# JGit: Retrieve tag associated with a git commit

Tags: jgit

I want to use JGit API to retrieve the tags associated with a specific commit hash (if there is any)?

Please provide code snippet for the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Git object model](http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html) describes tag as an object containing information about specific   object ie. commit (among other things) thus it's impossible in pure git to get information you want (commit object don't have information about related tags). This should be done "backwards", take tag object and then refer to specific commit.

So if you want get information about tags specified for particular commit you should iterate over them (tags) and choose appropriate.

```java
List<RevTag> list = git.tagList().call();
ObjectId commitId = ObjectId.fromString("hash");
Collection<ObjectId> commits = new LinkedList<ObjectId>();
for (RevTag tag : list) {
    RevObject object = tag.getObject();
    if (object.getId().equals(commitId)) {;
        commits.add(object.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: More info to the question can be found [in this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jgit-dev/msg01706.html) from the JGit Mailing list.

Comment: Shouldn't you collect the tags instead of the commits?

Comment: And org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git.tagList().call() returns List<Ref>.

Answer (score 7):

If you know that there is exactly one tag for your commit, you could use [describe](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html), in more recent versions of JGit ([~ November 2013](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339246)).

```
Git.wrap(repository).describe().setTarget(ObjectId.fromString("hash")).call()
```

You could parse the result, to see if a tag exists, but if there can be multiple tags, you should go with Marcins solution.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7503390/294317) uses `tagList()`.  After looking through the code in `ListTagCommand`, I came up with this simplified solution.

```
List<Ref> tags;
ObjectId commit;

commit = ObjectId.fromString("hash");

tags = m_git.
   getRepository().
   getRefDatabase().
   getRefsByPrefix(Constants.R_TAGS).
   stream().
   filter(ref -> ref.getObjectId().equals(commit)).
   collect(Collections.toList());
```