# How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?

Tags: git, sha1

Recently a team of researchers generated two files with the same SHA-1 hash (https://shattered.it/).

Since Git uses this hash for its internal storage, how far does this kind of attack influence Git?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hash collision in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434326/hash-collision-in-git)

Comment: Just for completenes: Linus answered some question regarding this topic [here](https://public-inbox.org/git/Pine.LNX.4.58.0504291221250.18901@ppc970.osdl.org/) and [here](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=148787047422954)

Comment: A few wonderful answers can be found here: [How would Git handle a SHA-1 collision on a blob?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392365/how-would-git-handle-a-sha-1-collision-on-a-blob)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen (and upvoter): I'd argue that this is not a duplicate as it's specifically about *the* (single) deliberate SHA-1 collision found recently, rather a theoretical discussion of the general idea. Of course a good theoretical discussion should subsume the question, but that requires that it be answered *ex post facto*, and existing questions obviously could not, in the past. :-)

Comment: Isn't this question off-topic here on stackoverflow? The topic it self seems to be interesting but not suitable for stackoverflow isn't it? Review system said that this is not off-topic but I think that's not correct.

Answer (score 43):

Edit, late December 2017: [Git version 2.16 is gradually acquiring internal interfaces to allow for different hashes](https://github.com/git/git/commit/721cc4314cb593e799213ad5f926a1e9fc5779b0).  There is a long way to go yet.

---

The short (but unsatisfying) answer is that the example files are not a problem for Git—but two *other* (carefully calculated) files *could* be.

I downloaded both of these files, `shattered-1.pdf` and `shattered-2.pdf`, and put them into a new empty repository:

```
macbook$ shasum shattered-*
38762cf7f55934b34d179ae6a4c80cadccbb7f0a  shattered-1.pdf
38762cf7f55934b34d179ae6a4c80cadccbb7f0a  shattered-2.pdf
macbook$ cmp shattered-*
shattered-1.pdf shattered-2.pdf differ: char 193, line 8
macbook$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .../tmp/.git/
macbook$ git add shattered-1.pdf 
macbook$ git add shattered-2.pdf 
macbook$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   shattered-1.pdf
    new file:   shattered-2.pdf
```

Even though the two files have the same SHA-1 checksum (and display mostly the same, although one has a red background and the other has a blue background), they *get different Git hashes:*

```
macbook$ git ls-files --stage
100644 ba9aaa145ccd24ef760cf31c74d8f7ca1a2e47b0 0   shattered-1.pdf
100644 b621eeccd5c7edac9b7dcba35a8d5afd075e24f2 0   shattered-2.pdf
```

Those are the two SHA-1 checksums for the files *as stored in Git*: one is `ba9aa...` and the other is `b621e...`.  Neither is `38762c...`.  But—*why?*

The answer is that Git stores files, not as themselves, but rather as the string literal `blob`, a blank, the size of the file decimalized, and an ASCII NUL byte, and *then* the file data.  Both files are exactly the same size:

```
macbook$ ls -l shattered-?.pdf
...  422435 Feb 24 00:55 shattered-1.pdf
...  422435 Feb 24 00:55 shattered-2.pdf
```

so both are prefixed with the literal text `blob 422435\0` (where `\0` represents a single byte, a la C or Python octal escapes in strings).

Perhaps surprisingly—or not, if you know anything of how SHA-1 is calculated—adding the *same prefix* to two different files that nonetheless produced the *same checksum before*, causes them to now produce *different* checksums.

The reason this should become unsurprising is that if the final checksum result were *not* exquisitely sensitive to the *position*, as well as the value, of each input bit, it would be easy to produce collisions on demand by taking a known input file and merely re-arranging some of its bits.  These two input files produce the same sum despite having a different byte at `char 193, line 8`, but this result was achieved, according to the researchers, by trying over 9 quintillion ([short scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers)) inputs.  To *get* that result, they put in carefully chosen blocks of raw data, at a position they controlled, that would affect the sums, until they found pairs of inputs that resulted in a collision.

By adding the `blob` header, Git *moved the position*, destroying the 110-GPU-years of computation in a single more or less accidental burp.

Now, knowing that Git will do this, they could *repeat* their 110-GPU-years of computation with inputs that begin with `blob 422435\0` (provided their sacrificial blocks don't get pushed around too much; and the actual number of GPU-years of computation needed would probably vary, as the process is a bit [stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic)).  They would then come up with two *different* files that could have the `blob` header stripped off.  These two files would now have different SHA-1 checksums from each other, but when `git add`-ed, both would produce the *same* SHA-1 checksum.

In that particular case, the first file added would "win" the slot.  (Let's assume it's named `shattered-3.pdf`.)  A good-enough Git—I'm not at all sure that the current Git is this good; see [Ruben's experiment-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34599081/1256452) to [How would Git handle a SHA-1 collision on a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9392365/1256452)—would notice that `git add shattered-4.pdf`, attempting to add the second file, collided with the first-but-different `shattered-3.pdf` and would warn you and fail the `git add` step.  In any case you would be unable to add both of these files to a single repository.

But first, someone has to spend a lot more time and money to compute the new hash collision.

Comment: but just to point out, while adding a _new_ file is not a security concern, replacing an existing blob in an important, compromised repository _is_. this would allow the insertion of a backdoor at an arbitrary point in history, even if every commit/tag is signed, without compromising the referential or cryptographic integrity of the repository.

Comment: that being said, see also Linus' response below.

Comment: Sure: if there is a bad blob in an existing repository, you want to replace it with a good one. If the good one has the same hash, you have a problem ... *unless* there are a near infinite number of new "good ones" with *other* hashes, which is likely the case.

Comment: what? I can't parse your sentence. I'm talking about a malicious actor replacing a legitimate blob with a malicious one and nobody noticing; I'm not sure what you're trying to say about "infinite number of new 'good ones'"?

Comment: What I'm saying here is that if you have an existing repository with a good blob, you literally *can't* replace it with a bad one, at least not using Git commands (including fetch and push). I think maybe what you are thinking of is: "I, Evil Bob, clone Good Bob's repository G. Then I manufacture bad blob X with same hash as good blob Y, and construct an all-new repository B that uses the same hashes as G. Then I somehow convince you, the victim, to clone my B instead of Good Bob's G." That's pretty tricky, in multiple senses: why would I take yours instead of Good Bob's?

Comment: Meanwhile, what I *thought* you were saying was: "I, Evil Bob, planned years in advance by sneaking a back door into massively-cloned repository E (for Evil). Now Good Bob can't fix it because he can't replace my historical bad blob!" Which is true: he can't replace the file with one with the same hash, but he doesn't *have* to. There is no need to assume evil as there are plenty of zero-day exploits in so much software. :-)

Comment: ah, yeah. I was assuming the canonical repository had been compromised in some other way like e.g. through a GitHub vulnerability.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe Linus' response might shed some light:

> > IIRC someone has been working on parameterizing git's SHA1 assumptions
> >     so a repository could eventually use a more secure hash. How far has
> >     that gotten? There are still many "40" constants in git.git HEAD.
>
> I don't think you'd necessarily want to change the size of the hash.
>   You can use a different hash and just use the same 160 bits from it.
>
> > Since we now have collisions in valid PDF files, collisions in valid git
> >     commit and tree objects are probably able to be constructed.
>
> I haven't seen the attack yet, but git doesn't actually just hash the
>   data, it does prepend a type/length field to it. That usually tends to
>   make collision attacks much harder, because you either have to make
>   the resulting size the same too, or you have to be able to also edit
>   the size field in the header.
>
> pdf's don't have that issue, they have a fixed header and you can
>   fairly arbitrarily add silent data to the middle that just doesn't get
>   shown.
>
> So pdf's make for a much better attack vector, exactly because they
>   are a fairly opaque data format. Git has opaque data in some places
>   (we hide things in commit objects intentionally, for example, but by
>   definition that opaque data is fairly secondary.
>
> Put another way: I doubt the sky is falling for git as a source
>   control management tool. Do we want to migrate to another hash? Yes.
>   Is it "game over" for SHA1 like people want to say? Probably not.
>
> I haven't seen the attack details, but I bet
>
> (a) the fact that we have a separate size encoding makes it much
>   harder to do on git objects in the first place
>
> (b) we can probably easily add some extra sanity checks to the opaque
>   data we do have, to make it much harder to do the hiding of random
>   data that these attacks pretty much always depend on.
>
> Linus

Source: https://marc.info/?l=git&m=148787047422954