# Can you remove Git commits from a branch that exist in another branch like an "intersection" of commits?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

The simple situation I find myself in at times, where I am working on some changes and I create a branch. As I move along in my changes I start finding some things that need cleanup or some other partially related thing to change that I want to start getting into. So, I want to keep the branches specific, so I quickly spin off another branch to start working on this other set of changes that may not have the same dependencies as the previous branch. In the end, I end up with 2 branches where I tried to isolate the changes, however, this 2nd branch originated from the first branch, which in term came from 'master'.

I can (and have) updated each branch individually by merging 'master' into each of them, and want to position this 2nd branch ready to be merged into 'master' because it has less drastic dependencies than the 1st branch created. However, this branch also contains changes done in the 1st branch since it was spun off of it.

So I'm wondering, is there a way to tell Git something like:
"Remove all the commits that exist in this other branch"
So that I'm left with my 2nd branch without all the changes done in the 1st branch, allowing me to merge this 2nd branch into 'master', and let me go back to work on the 1st branch I created.

It's possible that I'm just not finding the right terminology in Git to see how it can already do that. But also, maybe it can't. It would seem like it should be very doable though, seeing how Git is great at showing me only the appropriate diffs between branch 1 and 2 even after I individually update both branches from 'master'.

And "removing" from the branch isn't necessary..  even if the idea is creating yet another branch but that is still somehow excluding the changes that were done in that 1st branch that also are in the 2nd branch would be sufficient.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, you can do this.  In some cases it's even ridiculously easy, as it's just done automatically by `git rebase`.  In some cases it's ridiculously hard.  Let's take a look at the cases.

First, it's crucial, as it almost always is in Git, to *draw the commit graph*.  To get there, let's start with reviewing Git basics.  (This is a good idea since a lot of Git tutorials skip right over the basics, as the basics are boring and confusing. :-) )  First, let's look at what a commit *is* and does for you.

#### What a commit is and does for you

A *commit*, in Git, is a totally concrete thing.  We can look at any actual commit—most of them are pretty small—not with `git show`, which fancies them up a lot, but with `git cat-file -p`, which shows the immediate, raw contents (well, `tree` objects require minor tweaking, so sometimes "mostly raw") of an actual Git object:

```
$ git cat-file -p 3bc53220cb2dcf709f7a027a3f526befd021d858
tree 5654dad720d5b0a8177537390575cd6171c5fc50
parent 3e5c63943d35be1804d302c0393affc4916c3dc3
author Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1488233064 -0800
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1488233064 -0800

First batch after 2.12

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```

That's one whole commit right there.  Its name—the one name that identifies *that* commit, from now until forever—is `3bc5322...` (some big ugly hash ID that humans never want to deal with if they can avoid it).  It stores several more big ugly hash IDs.  One is for a *tree*, and some number—usually just one, again—are for *parents*.  It has an author (name, email address, and time-stamp) and committer, who are usually the same; and it has a log message, which is whatever you want to write.

The *tree* attached to a commit is a source-tree snapshot.  It's the *whole thing*, not a set of changes.  (Underneath, Git *does* get clever with compression, but the hash ID of the tree gets you hash IDs of files, and those files are the complete files, not some weird compressed thing.)  Have Git extract that tree, and you get all the files.

Because each commit stores a parent hash ID, we can start with a recent commit and work backwards.  That's Git for you: backwards.  We start with the hash ID of the *most recent* commit, which we have Git save for us in a branch name.  We say that this branch name *points to* the commit:

```
<--C   <--master
```

The name `master` points to commit `C`.  (I'm using one letter names instead of big ugly hash IDs, which limits me to 26 commits but is a lot more convenient.)  Commit `C` has another hash ID in it though, so `C` points to *another* commit.  That's `C`'s parent, `B`.  `B` of course also points to another commit, but let's say our repository only has three commits total, so that `B` points back to `A` but `A` was the first commit.

Since `A` *was* the first, it cannot have a parent.  So it doesn't: it does not point back any further.  We call `A` a *root* commit.  Every repository has at least one (and usually only one) root commit.<sup>1</sup>  That's where the action has to stop: we (or Git) can't go back any further.

In any case, commits, once made, are permanent and unchanging.<sup>2</sup>  This is because their hash ID is made by computing a cryptographic hash of *all of the bits* inside the commit (all the stuff you see with `git cat-file -p`).  If you change anything, you get a new and different hash ID.  Each hash ID is always unique.<sup>3</sup>

So, let's draw this out, but not bother with the internal arrows; let's just keep the one for the branch name itself.

```
A--B--C  <-- master
```

**Each commit on its own, then, saves a snapshot for you.  It's when you assemble them all together with their backwards arrows that you get the *commit graph*.**

---

<sup>1</sup>Except, that is, a completely empty repository, which obviously has *no* commits.  That's how you get root commits in the first place, by making a commit with no parent.

<sup>2</sup>Commits can, however, be *garbage collected* once you have no use for them.  Git normally does this invisibly; we'll see how that comes about soon.

<sup>3</sup>Pay no attention to [that web site behind the curtain!](https://shattered.it/)  Seriously, though, the recent breakage of SHA-1 hashing [is not an immediate problem for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452), but it does help push Git to switch to SHA-256.

---

#### Adding a new commit

Now that we see how the graph looks with three commits, let's add a new commit to `master`, to see how that works.  First we will `git checkout master` as usual.  That fills in the *index* and the *work-tree*.  Then we'll work, `git add` stuff, and `git commit`.

(Reminder: the *work-tree* is, well, where you do your work.  When Git saves files, it lists them under unpronounceable hash-ID names, and stores them compressed, and thus keeps them in a form useful only to Git itself.  To *use* those files, you need them in their normal form, and that's the work-tree.  Meanwhile the *index* is where you and Git build the *next* commit.  You work on files in the work-tree, then you run `git add` to copy them from the work-tree, into the index.  You can `git add` at any time: that just updates the index from the work-tree again.  The index starts out matching the *current* commit, and then you modify it until you are ready to make a new commit.)

When you run `git commit`, Git collects up your log message, then:

1. Writes out the index as a new `tree`: this is your saved snapshot, based on what you replaced in the index from the work-tree.  The new tree gets its own hash ID.
2. Writes a new `commit` object, with this new tree ID, the *current* commit's ID as its `parent`, you as the author and committer (and now as the time stamps), and your log message.

Step 2 gets Git a new hash ID for our new commit; let's call it `D`.  Since the new commit has `C`'s hash ID in it, `D` points back to `C`:

```
A--B--C     <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D
```

The last thing Git does, though, is to write *`D`*'s ID into the current *branch name*.  If the current branch is `master`, this makes `master` point to `D`:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- master (HEAD)
```

If we `git checkout -b` some *new* branch *first*, though—just before we make the new commit, that is—then look at our new starting setup:

```
A--B--C     <-- branch (HEAD), master
```

Both names, `branch` and `master`, point to `C`, but `HEAD` says that we are on branch `branch`, not on `master`.  So when we make `D` and Git updates the current branch, we get this:

```
A--B--C     <-- master
       \
        D   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

**This is how branches grow.**  A branch *name* just points to the *tip commit* of a branch; it's the commits themselves that form the graph.

It's worth stopping at this point and thinking about commits `A-B-C`.  They're on `master`, for sure.  But they are *also* on branch `branch`.  **A commit, in Git, may be on many branches at the same time.**  What we need to do, quite often, is *limit* how far back we let Git go when we tell it: "Get me all the commits starting from this branch-tip and working backwards."

## Now for the exciting part!

Well, maybe exciting. :-)  You have made several branches with a bunch of new commits, so let's draw that:

```
...--E--F--G                <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L     <-- feature1
                    \
                     P--Q   <-- feature2
```

Here, `master` ends at `G`, i.e., commit `G` is the tip of master.  `feature1` ends at `L`, and `feature2` ends at `Q`.  Commits `E-F-G` are on *all three* branches.  Commits `P-Q` are *only* on `feature2`.  Commits `I-J-K` are on both `feature1` and `feature2`.  Commit `L` is only on `feature1`.

Remember, again, these letters stand in for big ugly hash IDs, where the actual hash ID encodes *everything* in the commit: the saved tree *and* the `parent` IDs.  So `L` *requires* `K`'s hash ID, for instance.  This kind of thing matters because we intend to *copy* some commits.

What you described wanting to do is to somehow transplant commits `P` and `Q` so that they sit atop `master`.  What if there were a way to copy commits?  It turns out that there is: it's called `git cherry-pick`.

#### Cherry-picking

Remember that we noted earlier that a commit *is* a snapshot.  It's not a set of changes.  But right now we wish that a commit *were* a set of changes, because commit `P` is a lot *like* its parent commit `K`, but with some changes made.  After all, you made `P` by having `K` checked out, then editing files and `git add`ing the new versions into the index and then `git commit`ting.

Fortunately, there's an easy<sup>4</sup> way to turn a snapshot into a changeset, by *comparing it* (`git diff`) against its parent commit.  The output from `git diff` is a minimal<sup>5</sup> set of instructions: "Remove this line from this file, add these other lines to that file, etc."  Applying those instructions to the tree in `K` will turn it into the tree in `P`.

**But what happens if we apply those instructions to some *other* tree?**  As it turns out, this often "just works".  We can `git checkout` commit `G`—the tip commit of branch `master`, but let's use a different branch name:

```
...--E--F--G                <-- master, temp (HEAD)
            \
             I--J--K--L     <-- feature1
                    \
                     P--Q   <-- feature2
```

and then apply the diff to the work-tree.  We'll assume that goes well, automatically `git add` the result to the index, and `git commit` while *copying* the log message from commit `P`.  We'll call the new commit `P'` to say "like `P`, but with a different hash ID" (because it has a different tree, and a different parent):

```
             P'             <-- temp (HEAD)
            /
...--E--F--G                <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L     <-- feature1
                    \
                     P--Q   <-- feature2
```

Now let's repeat this with `Q`.  We run `git diff P Q` to turn `Q` into changes, apply those changes to `P'`, and commit the result as new `Q'`:

```
             P'-Q'          <-- temp (HEAD)
            /
...--E--F--G                <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L     <-- feature1
                    \
                     P--Q   <-- feature2
```

This is just the two `git cherry-pick` steps, plus of course creating the temporary branch.  But look what happens now if we erase the old name `feature2` and change `temp` to `feature2`:

```
             P'-Q'          <-- feature2 (HEAD)
            /
...--E--F--G                <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L     <-- feature1
                    \
                     P--Q   [abandoned]
```

It now looks like we made `feature2` by doing `git checkout -b feature2 master`, then writing `P'` and `Q'` from scratch!  That's just what you wanted.

---

<sup>4</sup>Easy, that is, after any number of master's and/or PhD theses on [string-to-string edit problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-to-string_correction_problem).

<sup>5</sup>"Minimal" in some sense, and somewhat tweak-able through different diff algorithms.  Minimizing the edit distance is important for *compression* but not actually for *correctness*.  However, when we go to apply the edit instructions to some *other* tree, the minimal-ness, and the exact instructions, really start to matter.

---

#### Git's `rebase` is automated cherry-pick plus the branch label moving

We can do all of the above at once using:

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase --onto master feature1
```

What we are doing here is using `feature1` as a way to tell Git what to *stop* copying.  Look back at the original graph, before the abandonment of the original commits.  If we tell Git to start at `feature1` and work backwards, that identifies commits `L`, `K`, `J`, `I`, `G`, `F`, and so on.  Those are the commits we explicitly say *not* to copy: commits that are on branch `feature1`.

Meanwhile, the commits we *do* want to copy are those on `feature2`: `Q`, `P`, `K`, `J`, and so on.  But we stop as soon as we hit any of the forbidden ones, so we'll copy *only* the `P-Q` commits.

The place we tell `git rebase` to copy *to* is—or is "just after"—the tip of `master`, i.e., copy commits so that they come after `G`.

**Git rebase does it all for us, which is ridiculously easy.  But there could be a hitch—or maybe several.**

#### Solving hitches

Let's say that we start out with this as before:

```
...--E--F--G                <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I--J--K--L     <-- feature1
                    \
                     P--Q   <-- feature2
```

We'd *like* to rebase `feature2` onto `master`, skipping most of `feature1`, but it turns out we need what we changed in commit `J` too.

We don't need `I`, or `K`, or `L`, just `J` (plus of course `P` and `Q`).

We can't do this with *just* `git rebase`.  We may need an explicit `git cherry-pick`, to copy `J`.  But this is Git, so there are lots of ways to do this.

First, let's look at the explicit-cherry-pick method.  We'll go ahead and make a new branch and cherry-pick `J`:

```
git checkout -b temp
git cherry-pick <hash-ID-of-J>
```

Now we have:

```
             J'             <-- temp (HEAD)
            /
...--E--F--G                <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L     <-- feature1
                    \
                     P--Q   <-- feature2
```

Now we can transplant `P-Q` as before.  We just change the `--onto` directive:

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase --onto temp feature1
```

The result is:

```
               P'-Q'        <-- feature2 (HEAD)
              /
             J'             <-- temp
            /
...--E--F--G                <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L     <-- feature1
                    \
                     P--Q   [abandoned]
```

We don't need `temp` any more at all, so we can just `git branch -d temp` and straighten out our drawing:

```
             J'-P'-Q'       <-- feature2 (HEAD)
            /
...--E--F--G                <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L     <-- feature1
                    \
                     P--Q   [abandoned]
```

#### Another way to get the same result

Suppose that, instead of copying just `P-Q`, we let `git rebase` copy `I-J-K-P-Q`.  This might actually be easier:

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase master
```

This time we don't need `--onto`: `master` tells Git *both* which commits to leave out *and* where to put the copies.  We leave out commit `G` and earlier, and we copy after `G`.  The result is:

```
             I'-J'-K'-P'-Q'  <-- feature2
            /
...--E--F--G                 <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L      <-- feature1
                    \
                     P--Q    [abandoned]
```

Now we have *too many* commits copied, but now we run:

```
git rebase -i master
```

which gives us a bunch of "pick" lines for each commit `I'`, `J'`, `K'`, `P'`, and `Q'`.  We *delete* the ones for `I'` and `K'`.  Git now copies *again*, giving:

```
             J''-P''-Q''    <-- feature2
            /
...--E--F--G                <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L     <-- feature1
                    \
                     P--Q   [abandoned]
```

which is what we want (the original copies are still in there, abandoned like the original-original `P-Q`, but they were there for so little time, who cares anyway? :-) ).  And of course, we can make that first `git rebase` use `-i` and remove the `pick` lines, and just have the `J'-P'-Q'` copies, all in one step.

#### Eliminating redundant commits

That's fine as far as it goes, but now there is both a `J` and a `J'`.  Actually there's nothing *wrong* with this—you can leave this situation in place, and even merge with it like this, with no real harm done.  But you might *want* to make `J'` part of `master` first and then *share* it.

Again, there is more than one way to do this.  I want to illustrate one *particular* way, though, because `git rebase` has some magic in it.

Let's say that we have done the `feature2` rebasing so that we have this now.  We'll drop the abandoned commits entirely, just like Git does when it eventually gets around to garbage-collecting them (note: you get at least 30 days by default before this happens, giving you about a month to change your mind):

```
             J'-P'-Q'     <-- feature2
            /
...--E--F--G              <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L   <-- feature1
```

You can now *fast-forward* `master` to include `J'`:

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only <hash-id-of-J'>
```

This moves the *labels*, without changing the *commit graph*.  To make it easy to draw in ASCII text, though, I'll move `J'` down one row:

```
                P'-Q'     <-- feature2
               /
...--E--F--G--J'          <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L   <-- feature1
```

(We could also get here by explicitly `git cherry-pick`ing `J` into `master` originally, then rebasing `feature2` without any fancy footwork.)  So *now* we'd like to copy `feature1`'s commits, adding them after `J'`, and *removing* `J`.

We *could* do this with another `git rebase -i`, which lets us explicitly delete the original commit `J`.  But we don't *have to*.  Well, we don't have to, *most of the time*.  Instead, we just run:

```
git checkout feature1
git rebase master
```

This tells Git that it should consider `I-J-K-L` as the candidates for the copy, and put the copies after `J'` (where `master` now points).  But—here's the magic—`git rebase` *looks closely* at all<sup>6</sup> of the commits that are on `master` that are not on `feature1` (these are called the *upstream* commits, in at least a few bits of documentation).  In this case, that's `J'` itself.  For each such commit, Git diffs the commit against its parent (a la `git cherry-pick`) and turns the result into a *patch ID*.  It does the same with *each candidate commit*.  If one of the candidates (`J`) has the *same* patch ID as one of the upstream commits, Git *eliminates* the candidate from the list!

Hence, as long as both `J` and `J'` have the same patch ID, Git *automatically* drops `J`, so that the final result is:

```
                P'-Q'     <-- feature2
               /
...--E--F--G--J'          <-- master
               \
                I'-K'-L'  <-- feature1
```

which is just what we wanted.

---

<sup>6</sup>All, that is, except merges.  Rebase literally *can't* copy merges—a new merge has a different parent-set than the original, and cherry picking "undoes" a merge in the first place—so by default it skips them entirely.  Merges don't get a patch ID assigned, and don't get plucked out of the set because they were never *in* the set.  It's usually a bad idea to rebase a graph-fragment that contains a merge.

Git does have a mode that tries to do it.  This mode *re-performs* the merges (as it has to: I leave working out the details as an exercise).  But there are a bunch of dangers here, so it's usually best not to do this at all.  I have said before that probably `git rebase` should default to "preserving" merges, but by erroring-out if there *are* merges, requiring either a "yes, go ahead and try to re-create merges" flag, or a "flatten away and remove merges" flag to proceed.

It doesn't, though, so it's up to you to draw the graph and make sure your rebases make sense.

---

#### When rebase goes wrong: merge conflicts

Any time you `git rebase` some commits, you run the risk of merge conflicts.  This is particularly true if you are plucking a segment of commits out of a long chain:

```
        o--...--B--1--2--3--4--...--o   <-- topic
       /
...o--*--o--o--o--T                     <-- develop
```

If we want to "move" (copy, then remove) commits 1-4 into `develop`, there's a good chance some or all parts of some of those four commits depend, in some way, on the other top-row commits that come before them (`B` and earlier).  When that happens, we tend to get merge conflicts, sometimes many.  Git winds up viewing the copy of commit `1` as a three-way merge operation, merging the changes from `B` to `1` with the changes from `B` to `T`.  The changes "from" `B` to `T` may looks quite complex, and may not appear sensible out of context, because we have to "go backwards" through the commits before `B` down to `*` and then "forwards" up to `T`.

It is up to you to figure out how, or even whether it is wise, to do this.

#### When rebase goes wrong: others are still using the originals

Because rebase is fundamentally a *copy* operation, you must consider who might still have the *original* commits.  Since commits can be on *many* branches, it may be the case that *you* have the originals.  This is what we saw when we had both `J` and `J'`, for instance.

Sometimes—even somewhat often—this may not be a big deal.  Sometimes it is.  *If all the extra copies are **only** in your own repository*, you can resolve all this on your own.  But what happens if you have *published* (pushed, or let others fetch from you) some of your commits?  In particular, what if some other repository has those original commits, with their original hash IDs?  If you *have* published the original commits, you must tell everyone else who has them: "Hey, I'm abandoning the originals, I have shiny new copies elsewhere."  You must get them to do the same thing, or else put up with the extra commit copies.

Extra commits are sometimes harmless.  This is particularly true of merges, since `git merge` works hard to take only *one copy* of any given change (although Git cannot always get this quite right on its own, since each change—each `git diff` output—depends on context and other changes, and the minimal-edit-distance algorithms sometimes go wrong themselves, picking the wrong "minimum changes").  Even if they do not break the *tree*, though, they do clutter up the commit history.  Whether and when this might be a problem is hard to predict.

## Summary

For your goals, `git rebase` is a powerful tool.  It needs a bit of care when using it, and the most important thing to remember is that it *copies* commits, then abandons—or tries to abandon—the originals.  This can go wrong in several ways, but the worst ones tend to occur when *other people* already have copies of your original commits, which generally means "when you have published (pushed) them".

Drawing graphs can help.  Everyone should make a habit of drawing their graphs, and/or using `git log --graph` (get help from "a dog": `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`, **A**ll **D**ecorate **O**neline **G**raph) and/or graphical browsers like `gitk` (although I personally hate GUIs in general :-) ).  Unfortunately, "real" graphs rapidly get very messy.  Git's built-in `log --graph` does a poor job separating rats-nest graphs.  There are a lot of ad-hoc tools to deal with this, some built in to Git, but it definitely helps to have a lot of practice reading the graphs.

Comment: Thank you for the lecture. :) I haven't responded yet because I'm not done digesting this. :) But I will once I get it.

Comment: Sometimes you come across an answer which is like a book. It teaches you so much. But then .. you see how little appreciation it got. So here's another upvote! Well written, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If your history looks like:

```
...--E--F--G                <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L     <-- feature1
                    \
                     P--Q   <-- feature2
```

In the simple case to remove `feature1` then do:

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase --onto master feature1
```

---

This is an abbreviation of `@torek`'s answer which is phenominal, but hard to find the actual answer to the question. Read `@torek`'s answer for more details and what to do in the non-simple cases.