# How to change the Tagger name and email of a Git Tag

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-tag, visual-sourcesafe-2005

Long story short I'm writing a script to migrate a very large project from (gasp) Microsoft SourceSafe to Git and I'm trying to retain the authors of the SourceSafe project's labels(which are essentially tags in Git). I know you can modify the author and committer name/date of a Git Commit but can you do the same to a Git Tag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Re-create the tags with the new desired data.  But if anyone else had them before, they may not accept your new ones.  Or they may!  It's up to *them*, though.

#### Description

> I know you can modify the author and committer name/date of a Git Commit

Actually, you *can't*, and the fact that you can't (and what you can do instead) plays an important part in the rest of the answer.

All Git objects have a hash ID as their "true name".  The hash is formed by computing a cryptographic checksum of the object's contents.  This means you can never change any Git object at all.<sup>1</sup>  What you *can* do is construct a *new* object, then convince everyone who had the old object to stop using it, and use instead the new object.

This is what `git commit --amend` does (and what various interactive rebase options like `edit` and `reword` can do as well).  First we extract the original Git object into ordinary data, where we can manipulate it; then we do the manipulation and ask Git to construct a new object; and finally we stop using the old object and start using the new one instead.

For a commit that is the *tip commit* (see [the definition of *head* in the gitglossary](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_head)), this all goes pretty easily and smoothly, as long as we haven't pushed that commit yet.  There are no additional commits referring back to this tip commit, so we make a new commit that is "just as good", re-direct the branch name (the *head*) to the new commit, and forget about the original we just replaced.  It *looks like* we changed a commit, but we got a new hash ID instead.

#### How this applies to tags

Git has two kinds of tags, a [*lightweight tag*](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_tag) and an *annotated tag*.  The difference between these is that an annotated tag consists of a lightweight tag pointing to a [*tag object*](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_tag_object).  It's the tag object that has the tagger information.  (A lightweight tag has no such information of its own, it just points directly to the commit object.)

Hence, to "change" a tag object, we must do the same thing we do to "change" a commit object: copy it to a *new* tag object.

There is no built in command to do this, but it is easy to build one out of `git cat-file -p`—this lets you extract the original tag into ordinary data—and `git mktag`, which lets you turn ordinary data into a new tag object.  For instance, the `v2.2.1` tag in the Git repository for Git begins with:

```
$ git cat-file -p v2.2.1
object 9b7cbb315923e61bb0c4297c701089f30e116750
type commit
tag v2.2.1
tagger Junio C Hamano <...
```

The `object` line is the commit to which the tag points:

```
$ git cat-file -t 9b7cbb315923e61bb0c4297c701089f30e116750
commit
```

so we can copy this tag to a new one with a different `tagger`:

```
$ new_hash_id=$(git cat-file -p v2.2.1 | sed -e .... | git mktag)
$ git update-ref refs/tags/$name $new_hash_id
```

where the `sed` does whatever is necessary (see below) and `$name` is the name of the tag.  Then we would make the lightweight tag `v2.2.1` point to this new tag object in `$new_hash_id`.  But there are two problems (only one of which is likely to apply to your case).

#### Tags may be PGP-signed

The above tag goes on to say:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1
```

and then has a PGP signature in it.  This signature covers all the data except for the signature itself.  If you copy-and-modify this tag, you should discard the original signature entirely (it will be invalid and will fail any testing applied); whether you can and should replace it with a new signature, and if so, whose, is up to you.

#### Tags are not supposed to change their target objects

The existing lightweight tag `v2.2.1` currently points to the existing tag object:

```
$ git rev-parse v2.2.1
7c56b20857837de401f79db236651a1bd886fbbb
```

This is the data we have been viewing up to this point.

The *new* tag object will have some other, different hash ID.  When we amended an unpublished commit, that was no big deal, because *no one else* had any idea that some branch name mapped to some particular hash ID.

Tags, however, are pretty commonly "well known".  In fact, the point of tags—particularly PGP-signed annotated tags, where the PGP signature lets you verify that no one has monkeyed with the tag data—is to *guarantee* that you can be sure that this tag is the *right* tag, and that the commit object to which it points is the original commit and not some Trojan Horse.  If you *change* an existing tag, you're subverting this intent.  Moreover, some people who know the previous tag's value will simply refuse to take a new value: you won't be *able* to get them to update an existing tag.  As long as you're doing this *before* anyone else has the tag, though, they will never know, and you will be fine.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or rather, you cannot change a Git object's contents unless you can [break the hash](https://shattered.it/).  See also [How does the newly found sha1 collision affect git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)

Answer (score 6):

unlike commits you can easily delete tags from remote, recreate them with the author name you want

```
git tag -d <tag-name> 
git push origin :refs/tags/<tag-name>
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
git tag <tag-name> [commit]
git push origin <tag-name>
```

Comment: This may work, but the date is not preserved in the case you want the original date, and a new date is saved

Answer (score 2):

One additional detail: When creating annotated/signed tags, `git tag` will use `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` (*not* `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`/`GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`) for the
"`Tagger`" field.

To create a tag with a different name/email **without changing the global Git config**:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="name" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="email" git tag -am"1.0.0" v1.0.0 <commit>
```

Note1: To create a signed tag (`-s`), a private key for the specified identity is required (that's the point of signing).

Note2: It is also possible to recreate older tags with a specific **timestamp**. For example: `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Wed Dec 16 22:33:44 UTC 2020" ...`