# Updating Git tagger emails

Tags: git

I used the wonderful `git filter-branch` script to rewrite all author and committer emails. I even used `--tag-name-filter cat` to rewrite the tags:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --env-filter '
    if test "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "foo@example.com"
    then
        GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=bar@example.com
    fi
    if test "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "foo@example.com"
    then
        GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=bar@example.com
    fi
' -- --all
```

Everything seemed to work OK, except that the rewritten tags still have a "tagger" property with the email set to `foo@example.com`. I read the [`filter-branch` documentation][1], yet I can't find anything similar to `TAGGER_EMAIL`.

How can I change the tagger email when updating the Git history?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610288/how-to-change-the-tagger-name-and-email-of-a-git-tag

Comment: You can't do this with `git filter-branch` as it has no tag *body* filter. (If you added a tag body filter, you could do it with `git filter-branch`, and perhaps you could get the Git community to take back this change.  `--env-filter` applies only to commit objects, unfortunately.) Meanwhile see phd's link.