# How do I import a commit into a branch

Tags: git, tags

I have a git commit that happened in some branch, and now the master does not have it. How do I import a commit to master?

I would prefer using merge as I need to go through pull request.

Answer (score 4):

Git does not have pull requests.<sup>1</sup>  Git*Hub* has pull requests, as do other web-hosting providers that let you use Git as a service.  There are several underlying Git mechanisms that these services build a fancy, more-user-friendly interface for.

The one you have asked about specifically is `git merge`.  It is possible to use this command—and/or the fancy Web interfaces that GitHub and others provide—without understanding what's going on.  I don't think this is a good idea, myself.  However, to understand what really *is* going on, there are a few basic concepts that one needs to "get" first.

One of these has to do with the meaning of the term *branch* itself: see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  When someone says "a branch", sometimes they mean a branch *name*—or one of Git's various other names that aren't quite branch names—and sometimes they mean *a vaguely-defined series of commits*.

Again, none of this is required to use the pull request interface on GitHub.  To use that, you just click some web buttons.  But it's a good idea—I think, at least—to know what's going to happen with these buttons, and for that, you *do* need to understand how Git works.  So let's dive into the details.

---

<sup>1</sup>By this, I mean there is no `git pull-request` command.  There *is* a `git request-pull` command, and what it does is generate an email message.  That's the extent to which Git supports pull requests: it has a comand to generate an email message, asking someone else to do something.

---

#### Commits

A Git commit is a snapshot of all of your files as of the state they had when you made the snapshot, plus a bit of *metadata* describing the snapshot.  (Technically, the commit represents the snapshot indirectly, as the snapshot is stored separately as a *tree* object, but in most cases you don't need to know this: there's a one-way link from commit to snapshot, so that given the commit Git can always find the snapshot.  The linkage means that multiple *different* commits can represent the *same* snapshot without taking the space twice, though, which is useful for several purposes.)

Each commit is identified by a hash ID like `b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a`.  These things are big and ugly and impossible for humans to deal with, but they are how Git *finds* the commits, so they are crucial for Git's operation.  The hash ID for any one particular commit is always unique: that hash ID is *that* commit and no other, ever; every other commit has a *different* hash ID.  Moreover, *all Gits everywhere in the universe agree on these hash ID computations.*  Given two different Git repositories, if they both have some commit ID *H*—that is, they both have a commit object whose hash is *H*—the *contents* of that object must necessarily be the same.<sup>2</sup>

The metadata in the commit includes your name (or the name of the person who made the commit) and email address, and a time-stamp of when the commit was made.  It includes your log message, telling everyone *why* you made this commit.  But it also includes the hash ID of the commit that comes immediately *before* this one.  We call that the commit's *parent*.  The result is a backwards-looking chain.  If we have a tiny repository with just three commits, we can draw it like this:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Here, `C` is the *last* commit.  It has some unique, big ugly hash ID.  It also stores the unique hash ID of commit `B`, so once we find `C`, we can use it to find `B`.  Meanwhile `B` has the hash ID of `A`, so we can use `B` to find `A`.  Since `A` is the very first commit, it has no parent at all—technically it's a *root* commit—and that lets us stop going backwards.

The other thing to know about commits—and all Git objects that have hash IDs—is that you cannot *change* any of them, ever.  The reason is that the hash ID is a cryptographic checksum of the contents of the object.  If you were to take a commit object and change even one bit—such as fixing the spelling of a word in your log message—you'd end up with a *new and different commit*, with a different hash ID.  So, once a commit is made, it's forever: that *hash ID* is taken now.<sup>3</sup>

What this means for us is that we don't need to draw the arrows coming out of a commit *as* arrows.  Once the commit exists, it's permanent, and its linkages to its parents are permanent too.  We just need to remember that they only *go* one way: backwards.  New links can appear *to* this commit, but they can't appear going *from* this commit to anywhere new.

---

<sup>2</sup>Note that the requirement that identical hash IDs represent the same underlying object content is only maintained across two Gits that meet and exchange objects.  Two repositories that are never connected *can* have such doppelänger commits, as long as they never try to talk to each other.

<sup>3</sup>You can *delete* a commit entirely, if a bit painfully, by just having nothing refer to it any more.  Eventually the underlying Git object goes away, effectively releasing the hash ID.  Since there are 160 bits in the current hash ID system, there are only 2<sup>160</sup> possible objects in any Git repository.  Fortunately, that's plenty.  Still, the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) combined with the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox) makes for some interesting theoretical issues, and [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452) has discussion about that.

---

#### Branch names

Given the above repository, we can find *all* the commits if we know the hash ID of commit `C`.  Where will we store that?  How about: *in a branch name?*  Let's pick a name like `master` and use that to scribble down the hash ID of `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

Now let's make a *new* commit, by checking out commit `C` and doing some work, in the usual way:

```
git checkout master
... do some work ...
git add ... various files ...
git commit
```

The new commit will package up a new snapshot, add whatever log message we provide, add our name and email address and the time-stamp, and, crucially, set the *parent* of our new commit to be commit `C`:

```
A--B--C--D
```

As the last step of committing, `git commit` will take the new commit's hash ID—whatever the actual checksum is, now that all the parts are cemented forever into place—and *write that checksum down in the name `master`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

So that's what a branch name is: it's a place to store the hash ID of the *last* commit.  Mere humans don't have to remember hash IDs, because we have Git remember them for us.  We remember only that `master` holds the hash ID of the *latest* commit, and have Git do the rest.

#### This is where your HEAD comes in

Of course, you can create multiple branch names.  Each one just points to one particular commit.  Let's make a new branch `dev` right now:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master, dev
```

Note that `master` and `dev` *both* point to commit `D`, and *all four commits are on both branches*.  But Git needs a way to know *which name to change* when we make a new commit.  This is where the special name `HEAD` comes in.  We have Git attach this name to one (and only one) branch name:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD), dev
```

or:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master, dev (HEAD)
```

We do this using `git checkout`, which not only checks out the commit, but also attaches `HEAD`.  If `HEAD` is attached to `master` and we make a new commit `E` it looks like this:

```
           E   <-- master (HEAD)
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- dev
```

If we now switch `HEAD` to `dev` (by doing `git checkout dev`) and make a new commit `F`, we get:

```
           E   <-- master
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           F   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

#### This is where merges come in

Let's say we have a repository with a bunch of commits where the last few look like this:

```
       I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
      /
...--H
      \
       K--L   <-- br2
```

Here, we have some series of commits ending in one whose hash is `H`, with `H` holding some snapshot.  Then someone—maybe us—made two more commits `I` and `J` on branch `br1`, that we're on now.  Someone—maybe us, maybe someone else—started from `H` and made two more commits `K` and `L`.  This is true *even if the someone else made `K` and `L` in a different repository.*  We both have `H`, and since all Gits everywhere agree on the hash ID computation, we both *started from the same commit*.

What the `git merge` command will do is to figure out *what we changed in our branch `br1`* and *what they changed in their branch `br2`*.  It will then *combine* these changes.  But we already noted that the word *branch* tends to be vague and ill-defined.  What Git will *really* do here is find the *common commit*, the one that we both started from.  We already saw that this is commit `H`.

Commit `H` is therefore the *merge base* of the merge operation.  The other two interesting commits are simply the one named by our current branch—commit `J` at the tip of `br1`—and the one named by the other branch, commit `L` at the tip of `br2`.  All three commits are *snapshots*, so Git needs to *compare* them:

- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-H hash-of-J` finds what we did in br1
- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-H hash-of-L` finds what they did in br2

Git can now *combine these two sets of changes*.  If we changed some file and they didn't, Git should take our new file.  If they changed some file and we didn't, Git should take their new file.  If we both changed the same file, Git should start with the copy of the file from the merge base commit `H` itself, *combine* the two different changes, and apply the *combined* changes to that file.

So that's what `git merge` does, in this case: it combines our changes and their changes, which produces a new merged snapshot.  This process of combining changes is what I like to call *merge as a verb*, or *to merge*.  It's important to remember that this can be done by other commands, because other Git commands do it!  This *to merge* or *merge as a verb* uses Git's *merge engine* to combine work.

In this case, though, `git merge` now goes on to make a *merge commit*.  This is almost just an ordinary commit: it has a snapshot, and a log message, and so on, just like any other commit.  What makes it special—a merge commit—is that it has *two* parent commits instead of just the usual one.  The *first* parent is the same as usual: it's the commit we have checked out when we run `git merge`.  The *second* parent is just the other commit—the one we picked out by using the name `br2`, or in this case, commit `L`.

So now `git merge` makes *a merge* (merge as a noun) or *a merge commit* (merge as an adjective), which looks like this:

```
       I--J
      /    \
...--H      M
      \    /
       K--L   <-- br2
```

What happens to our branch name?  The same thing as always, of course.  Git writes the new hash ID for this new merge commit `M` into the current branch name:

```
       I--J
      /    \
...--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
      \    /
       K--L   <-- br2
```

That's how we will merge someone's commits—the someone being whoever made `K` and `L` on `br2`, in this case.

(Note that, in general, we get the same *snapshot* if we `git checkout br2; git merge br1`.  The merge base is still `H` and the two tips are `L` and `J`, and combining work produces the same result.  What changes is that the first-parent of this other merge would be `L`, not `J`, so the parents get swapped, and the final name-update would update the name `br2` rather than `br1`.  If we start throwing in extra merge options, though, like `-X ours` or `-X theirs`, more things can be different.)

#### Not all `git merge` commands result in merges

It's worth noting an extra wrinkle or two here.  Suppose we have this graph:

```
...--A--B--C--D--E--H--I   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
            \      /
             F----G   <-- branch2
```

and we run `git merge branch2`.  We've already merged branch2 earlier at commit `H`, which has parents `E` and `G`.  The merge base is defined (loosely—technically it's the Lowest Common Ancestor in the DAG) as the nearest commit that's on both branches, and that's commit `G`, since from `I` we can walk backwards to `H` and then `G`, and of course from `G` we just stay right there at `G`.

In this case, `git merge branch2` will say *already up to date* and do nothing.  That's correct: their commit is `G`, and ours is `I` which already has `G` as an ancestor (a grandparent, in this case) so there is no new work to combine.

We can also have this related situation:

```
...--A--B--C--D--E--H--I   <-- branch1
            \      /
             F----G   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

where we run `git merge branch1`.  This time *our* commit is `G` and *theirs* is `I`.  The merge base is still commit `G` as before.  What Git does by default in this situation is to say to itself: *The result of diffing `G` against `G` is, by definition, empty.  The result of combining nothing with something is, by definition, the something.  So all I really have to do is `git checkout hash-of-I`.  So I'll do that, but at the same time, make the name `branch2` point to commit `I` too.*  The result is:

```
...--A--B--C--D--E--H--I   <-- branch1, branch2 (HEAD)
            \      /
             F----G
```

Git calls this a *fast-forward operation*.  Git sometimes calls it a *fast-forward merge*, which is not good terminology as there is no actual merging involved.

You can force Git to make a real merge—to diff `G` against itself, and combine nothing with something, and then make a real merge commit—giving:

```
...--A--B--C--D--E--H--I   <-- branch1
            \      /    \
             F----G------J   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

To force a real merge here, use `git merge --no-ff branch1`.

(Sometimes you want or need a real merge, and sometimes fast-forward-instead is OK.  For what it's worth, the clicky buttons on the GitHub web hosting interface *do not* permit or perform fast-forward merges, even if you want them to.  In effect, they always use `git merge --no-ff`.)

#### How all this relates to pull requests

Pull requests, or even Git's more-primitive `git request-pull` option, are only useful if there is *more than one Git repository involved in the process*.

In this case we might have, in Repository #1, a series of commits:

```
       I--J   <-- master
      /
...--H
```

Meanwhile, over in Repository #2, we have:

```
...--H
      \
       K--L   <-- master
```

Since these are two different repositories, they have their own private branch *names*.  One has *its* master holding hash ID `I`.  The other has *its* master holding hash ID `L`.  Commit `H` is in *both* repositories, while commits `I-J` are only in #1, and `K-L` are only in #2.

If we were to somehow *combine* the two repositories, while changing the names so that they don't collide, we'd be back in our regular merge situation:

```
       I--J   <-- master of Repository #1
      /
...--H
      \
       K--L   <-- master of Repository #2
```

This is *precisely what GitHub does* with its clicky web interface.  Whoever you are—#1 or #2; let's pick #2 for concreteness—you tell GitHub: *I'd like them to merge my master, i.e., commit L.*  GitHub then *copies* your commits—bit-for-bit so that their hash IDs remain the same—to their repository, putting the hash ID of commit `L` under a special name that's *not* `master` and not any other branch name.<sup>4</sup>  Then they, GitHub, run a `git merge`, using this same sort of special name that's not a branch name at all.  If that all works, *then* they tell whoever controls repository #1 that there's a pull request from you.

Whoever controls repository #1 can now click the "merge pull request" button.  That takes the merge that GitHub already did<sup>5</sup> and moves *their* `master`, or whatever branch name, in their GitHub repository, appropriately:

```
       I--J
      /    \
...--H      M   <-- master
      \    /
       K--L
```

Commits `K` and `L` now appear in their repository, reachable by following the second-parent backwards link from `master`.

What this means for you, as someone who wants to *make* a pull request, is that you have to arrange for your repository on GitHub to have a commit or chain of commits that GitHub will be able to test-merge for you.  GitHub will then present the request to the owner of that repository, and that owner will be able to just do one click to complete the merge by updating their branch's name to use the test merge GitHub has made.

The commits, and the test-merge result, are determined by what commits you put into your GitHub repository.  If you have your own separate repository on your own machine locally, you can put commits into *it* and use `git push` to send those commits *to* your GitHub repository.

This is, obviously, all a bit convoluted—but if you keep your local machine's repository and your own GitHub repository in sync, so that they always "look the same" as it were, you get to ignore the extra layer here.  The issue with ignoring this layer is that it is still there!  If you let your repository and your GitHub repository get out of sync, this shows right up again.

---

<sup>4</sup>When you make a pull request, GitHub allocates a unique number for it (unique to the destination repository).  Say this is Pull Request #123.  The name that GitHub uses for your commits, once they are copied into their GitHub repo, is `refs/pull/123/head`.  The name that GitHub uses for the test merge it makes is `refs/pull/123/merge`.  If the test merge fails with a conflict, GitHub doesn't make one after all and does not create the second name.

<sup>5</sup>If whoever controls the PR-target repository pushes *new* commits to *their* branch, the test merge that GitHub made becomes invalid (it's "out of date").  GitHub will make a new test merge if and when it's appropriate.  I'm not sure if they delete the `refs/pull/123/merge` name in between as I have never tested that.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) it:

```
$ git cherry-pick <commit hash>
```

Comment: It will work, but i would prefer to go through merge through a pull request. ( Just edited my question to reflect this; sorry)

Comment: @NoviceUser Then you can create a branch out of master & cherry-pick there and submit a PR for back to merge in master, Yes?

Comment: @VibrantVivek yes!

Answer (score 1):

**How to do this by Pull Request**
(but avoid merging into `master` any other commits from the feature branch, like a (feature-branch >> master) pull request would cause, you can do the following)

**1)** Create a new branch named `hotfix/master` (for example) from `master` directly on the remote (github? bitbucket? other? you didn't mention but feel free to comment and I'll adjust) then from your local, get the last refs from remote :

```
git fetch
```

**2)** Here, fetch output should contain your newly created branch, so let's create its local counterpart :

```
git checkout hotfix/master
```

**3)** Now we import the commit you want on it :

```
git cherry-pick <commitHash>
```

or alternatively, if the commit you want is the last on the feature branch, just :

```
git cherry-pick <branchName>
```

**4)** Resolve any conflict that may arise at this level, and push the branch to remote :

```
git push origin hotfix/master
```

**5)** Finally, back to the remote interface where you create your pull requests, and create one between `hotfix/master` and `master`.