# How could I let git share a same file between different branches?

Tags: git

I have two branches, one is `master` and the other one is `dev`. There is a file named `config` which I want it to be shared between branches.  That is to say, if I change it in `master` and then switch to `dev`, the changes are kept and I can see the changed file in `dev`. Besides, I would like it can be pushed to remote repositories, so I cannot add it to `.gitignore` file.

How can I do this ?

Comment: You cannot do this, but you can check out the file from the other branch using `git checkout master -- config`, and commit the changed file to `dev`

Comment: if you can use the 'config' file by reading it from the **stdin**, then `git show master:config` is your friend. This way you can change it in the 'master' branch and read in any branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this except when you are forced to do this.

This answer above makes no sense until you understand that Git isn't really about *branches* at all.  Git is all about *commits*.

Each commit has its own big ugly hash ID, such as `08da6496b61341ec45eac36afcc8f94242763468`.  This ID means *this* commit, and no other commit.  Try:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

in your own Git repository, to see the hash ID of your current commit.  That hash ID now means *that* commit, forever more, and never any other commit.<sup>1</sup>

But commit hash IDs are big and ugly and no mere human is going to remember them.  We (humans) need a device that will remember them for us.  Perhaps we can use our computers!  They're good at remembering long strings like that.  So what we do is have Git remember these hash IDs *for* us.

There are several different places that Git will remember hash IDs for us.  For instance, *tag* names hold one commit hash ID.<sup>2</sup>  But in fact, *branch* names, like `master`, *also* just hold one commit hash ID.

Fortunately, each *commit* holds hash IDs as well!  This is how what Git forms what we tend to think of as *branches*, although we (humans) also tend to think of our branch names, and sometimes some of our other names in our Git repositories, as "branches" as well.  For more on this, see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

Each commit stores a *full and complete snapshot* of all of our files.  A commit does not store changes!  It stores whole files, intact.<sup>3</sup>  So if commit `A` (where `A` stands in for some hash ID) stores the content of your file `foo/bar/file.txt`, commit `A` has a full and complete copy of the file—not differences, just a copy.  If some other commit `B` stores the content of your file `foo/bar/file.txt`, commit `B` also has a full and complete copy.

These full and complete copies are *automatically shared* **if they match exactly.**  Every commit, once made, is completely and totally read-only, frozen for all time.<sup>4</sup>  That includes the saved file contents as well.  So if commit `A` stores the *same* content—even just for one file—as commit `B`, the underlying file storage for that file is shared.  But you cannot *change* that copy of the file.  If you do change the file, you must make a new commit `C`, which gets its own new and unique hash ID.  This new commit `C` can have a file `foo/bar/file.txt` but, since we said you changed that file's content (to something that does not match any other existing commit), that file's content is new to commit `C`.  It can be shared again with later commits `D`, `E`, and `F` as long as `foo/bar/file.txt` continues to have the same content.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the hash ID is simply a cryptographic checksum of the entire contents of the commit object.  In theory, some different object could have the same checksum.  However, if you already have an object with hash *H*, your Git will not allow any new-but-different object with the same hash to enter your repository.  So once an object ID is "taken", it means *that* object from then on.

See also [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)

<sup>2</sup>A *lightweight tag* holds the hash ID directly, while an *annotated tag* holds it through an *annotated tag object*, which also holds additional data.  This tag object gets its own unique hash ID and the tag *name* then holds the tag object's ID.  Git will use the name to find the tag object, and then read the tag object to find the stored hash ID.

Tags can have as their tag-target *any* of Git's four internal object types.  If an annotated tag points to another annotated tag, Git will keep following the tag until it reaches some other object type, so ultimately, each tag points to some non-annotated-tag object, but possibly after many indirections.  If the ultimate object is a tree or blob object, the tag doesn't point to a commit after all.

<sup>3</sup>At the level of a commit, Git stores one *tree* object.  The tree object then refers to *blob* objects and more *tree* objects.  The tree objects hold file name components and references to blob hash IDs, and the blob objects hold the files' contents.

These objects are initially stored as *loose objects*, which are always whole and intact.  Later, Git eventually compresses the objects into *pack files*.  When stored in a pack file, an object can be [*delta compressed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) against other packed objects.  So, at some point, "files"—really, objects—do get stored via delta encoding, which is similar to storing diffs.  But that happens *later*, and is not visible from the level at which Git deals with files.  Note that the tree and commit objects themselves are, or at least can be, delta-compressed as well!

<sup>4</sup>This is necessary, as well as natural, *because* of the way Git stores objects.  Each object has its content, whatever that is, and then hash a hash ID that is computed by this same checksum process mentioned in footnote 1.  If you take an object out of the database, modify even a single bit, and write that back *to* the database, the new object has a new and different checksum.  If the new data are already *in* the database, the new object isn't new after all: Git just re-uses the existing object.  Otherwise Git writes that object into the database, and now that hash ID is taken.

There are procedures for releasing ("garbage collecting") unused objects, if and when they arise (which actually is relatively often in Git—many commands make temporary objects, then throw them away).  You don't have to do anything to have this happen: Git itself runs `git gc --auto` for you when it's appropriate.  But hash IDs have enough bits that an accidental collision never happens in practice; only deliberate, forced collisions can happen.  Again, see [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)

---

#### But the above is all about commits!  What about *branches*?

We just said that if commits `A` and `B` have the same file-content for `foo/bar/file.txt`, they actually *share* the underlying copy of the file.  In Git's terminology, they share the *blob* object.  But commit `C` introduced a new and different version of `foo/bar/file.txt`, so commit `C` has a new and different blob object.  Commits `D`, `E`, and `F`, then re-use that content for *their* `foo/bar/file.txt` files, because you made commits `D`, `E`, and `F` without changing the file.

Now, an interesting thing about commits is that besides storing *files*—a snapshot of *all* of your files—each commit also stores some *metadata*.  In the metadata, you will find your own name and email address, stored as "author" and "committer".  You will find two date-and-time-stamps, indicating when you *made* the commit.<sup>5</sup>  Git stores your *log message:* subject and body text for `git log`, to reminds yourself and others *why* you made this commit.  And, perhaps most important of all, you will find the hash ID of a *parent* commit, or sometimes some number of parent commits.  Usually there is just the one parent.

Remember, this parent is the *raw hash ID* of a commit—a big ugly string of letters and numbers.  That's Git remembering the hash ID *for* us, so that we don't have to.

Whenever something in Git is holding a big ugly hash ID, we say that that thing *points to* the corresponding object.  So if a commit holds the hash ID of its predecessor (parent) commit, the comimt *points to* its parent.  That means that commit `B` points back to commit `A`, and commit `C` points back to commit `B`, and so on:

```
A <-B <-C ... <-F
```

These backwards-pointing commit arrows, embedded within each commit, form a chain that links the commits together.  Since nothing about any commit can ever *change*, we can draw the chain like this:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F
```

But where do the branch names come in?  The answer is: right here.  The *last* commit in this chain is commit `F` (whatever its real, big and ugly, hash ID really is—we're just calling it `F` here).  To remember *this* hash ID, Git gives us a branch name.  Let's say this is branch `master`.  The *name* `master` will then hold the actual hash ID of commit `F`:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master
```

Now let's create a new branch `dev`.  Which hash ID does `dev` hold?  Well, let's have it hold `F` too!  So now we have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master, dev
```

We pick one of these two branches to be "on":

```
git checkout dev
```

and then we do some work and make a new commit, which gets its own new, unique, big and ugly hash ID.  We'll call this hash ID `G`.  Commit `G` will point back to existing commit `F`, since that's the commit we checked out in order to *make* `G`, and we get:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F
                \
                 G
```

Where do the branch names point?  Well, `master` still points to commit `F`—but because we just *made* new commit `G`, Git *automatically updates* the branch *name* to point to new commit `G`, giving:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master
                \
                 G   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

We draw the word `(HEAD)` next to the branch name that we used with `git checkout`, so that we—and Git—know which *branch name* gets updated as we make new commits.

If we make more new commits on `dev`, they point back to the existing commits on `dev`.  Existing commit `G` points back to commit `F`.  Which branch is commit `F` on?  Git's answer is unusual: commit `F` is on *both branches at the same time*.

But, what if we `git checkout master`, so that we have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master (HEAD)
                \
                 G   <-- dev
```

and then make a new commit `H`?  Well, that works just like last time.  The *parent* of new commit `H` is the commit we have checked out a moment earlier, which is commit `F`, and our *name* moves to point to the new commit:

```
                 H   <-- master (HEAD)
                /
A--B--C--D--E--F
                \
                 G   <-- dev
```

Commits `A` through `F` are on *both* branches.  Commit `H` is only on `master`, and commit `G` is only on `dev`.

---

<sup>5</sup>The reason for the two time stamps is that you can *copy* a commit, while (presumably) changing something about it.  The new commit gets a new *committer* line: you made the new commit right now.  But it retains its old *author* line: whoever wrote the original commit, whenever they wrote it, is captured in the *new* commit too.  So every commit has an *author:* the person who wrote the original commit, with name and email address and time stamp.  Every commit has a *committer* too: the person who made that particular commit, with name and email address and time stamp.  If the two match, this is the original copy of the original commit.

---

#### Now we can see why your original question is answered mostly "no" in Git

We start with a file named `config` that exists in snapshots `G` and `H` at this time:

```
                 H   <-- master (HEAD)
                /
A--B--C--D--E--F
                \
                 G   <-- dev
```

with the same content.  So this file *is* shared—stored just once—and both `H` and `G` use one shared blob object to store it.  But then you modify the work-tree copy of the file, `git add`, and `git commit` to make new commit `I`:

```
                 H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
                /
A--B--C--D--E--F
                \
                 G   <-- dev
```

Commit `I` has a new, different copy of `config`: a new blob.  You'd like for branch `dev` to *automatically* acquire a *new* commit:

```
                 H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
                /
A--B--C--D--E--F
                \
                 G--J   <-- dev
```

where commit `J` is the same as commit `G` except that the file `config` has been updated.

You can do that *manually*, by doing `git checkout dev` and then making a new commit `J` on `dev` that has, in its snapshot, the same updated copy of `config`.  But Git cannot do that automatically.