# Gitlab merge a merge request from command line not generating any commit(no fast forward)

Tags: git, gitlab, command-line-interface, git-merge

I am trying to Merge a Merge Request manually from **command line**.

In the merge window of Gitlab, there is already some codes are present to do that. Whenever I merge a request from the Gitlab website, it generates a merge commit, which is known as **--no-ff** commit. But when I am trying to do that manually, it is not generating any extra commit although I have specified the --no-ff option in command line. Any suggestions? I have already tried with the commit amend option as well.

```sh
    git fetch <Fork_Repo_URL> <Fork_Repo_Branch>
    git checkout -b <Branch_Name> FETCH_HEAD

    git fetch origin
    git checkout origin/master
    git merge --no-ff <Remote_Name>-<Branch_Name>

    git push origin master
```

After trying

```sh
git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph
```

I am getting

```
* dba92a6 (origin/falcondev, central/merge-requests/21, falcondev) check again with log
*   fdc761e (HEAD -> central/falcondev) Merge remote-tracking branch 'central/merge-requests/20' into central/falcondev
|\
| * f6c3a9b (central/merge-requests/20, central/falcondev) one more time
|/
* 1e5a6b0 trying with pull
*   d7a3fd9 Merge branch 'sourodeep.c/merge' into central/falcondev
|\
| * 67d1ee8 (central/merge-requests/19, sourodeep.c/merge) new no work
|/
*   078a128 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/falcondev' into central/falcondev
:...skipping...
* dba92a6 (origin/falcondev, central/merge-requests/21, falcondev) check again with log
*   fdc761e (HEAD -> central/falcondev) Merge remote-tracking branch 'central/merge-requests/20' into central/falcondev
|\
| * f6c3a9b (central/merge-requests/20, central/falcondev) one more time
|/
* 1e5a6b0 trying with pull
*   d7a3fd9 Merge branch 'sourodeep.c/merge' into central/falcondev
|\
| * 67d1ee8 (central/merge-requests/19, sourodeep.c/merge) new no work
|/
*   078a128 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/falcondev' into central/falcondev
|\
| * 7910f7e (central/merge-requests/18) from forked try
|/
*   e757ac2 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/merge-requests/17' into falcondev
|\
| * 0f09a9e (central/merge-requests/17) new approach
|/
* 2fa49fb check autonomous commit
*   226c1e9 Merge branch 'falcondev' into 'falcondev'
|\
| * f89bb8a (central/merge-requests/16) check online merge
|/
* 2d3def9 (central/merge-requests/15) no fail
* 8daf9c6 (central/merge-requests/14) success pls
* 64afe76 (central/merge-requests/13) Add one more commit
* 8d23993 (central/merge-requests/12) readme md merge
* 2053107 (central/merge-requests/11) check merge commit
* d6a2590 (central/merge-requests/10) check merge commit
* cb85533 (central/merge-requests/9, central/merge-requests/8, sourodeep.c/dummy_testing-falcondev) new change
* 8c27c2d (central/merge-requests/7) changes to merge
* bebf815 (central/merge-requests/6) Merge
* 33d4f61 (central/merge-requests/5, central/merge-requests/4, central/merge-requests/3) Again change
* 0d23cd4 (central/merge-requests/2) Update README.md
| * 3d8c3af (origin/master, origin/HEAD, central/merge-requests/1, master) Update README.md
```

Comment: I got my answer, please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58901217/9200233)

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

For an immediate fix, I recommend using this sequence of commands:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only origin/master  # make sure we are up to date

git fetch <fork_repo_url> <fork_branch>
git merge --no-ff FETCH_HEAD -m "<insert a GOOD merge message here>"

git push origin master
```

The good merge message is up to you to create.  The standard *low quality* merge message that Git provides is "merge branch <fork_branch> of <fork_repo_url>".  This describes the action taken, without giving a reason *why* the action was taken.  It's a bad (low quality) message because the presence of the merge itself *also* records the action taken, though not the specific URL and branch name.  The specific URL and branch name are typically not useful, so in effect, this merge message is "this commit is a merge commit", which is itself wholly redundant and therefore useless.

Ideally, you should add a *remote* to name the fork, after which you can shorten this slightly:

```
git fetch other-remote
git merge --no-ff other-remote/<fork-branch> -m "..."
```

(and after which, omitting the `-m` argument inserts Git's standard low-quality merge message, which is convenient if you're automating this and can't provide a better one.)

#### Long

Your immediate problem has nothing to do with making the merge commit (although there may be a problem here as well).  The issue with this series of commands:

> ```
> git fetch <Fork_Repo_URL> <Fork_Repo_Branch>
> git checkout -b <Branch_Name> FETCH_HEAD
>
> git fetch origin
> git checkout origin/master
> git merge --no-ff <Remote_Name>-<Branch_Name>
>
> git push origin master
> ```

lies in the middle of the *second* group of commands, *or* with the *final* command, depending on how you wish to treat this.  There's also a likely error with the `git merge` command, but we'll get to that later.

The command:

> ```
> git checkout origin/master
> ```

produces what Git calls a *detached HEAD*.  There is nothing fundamentally wrong with this state; you just need to understand what it does if you plan to use it.

The final command:

> git push origin master

has your Git call up the Git at `origin` and request that they set *their* name `master` to the commit hash ID your Git currently has stored under *your* name `master` (after handing them any new commits required to achieve this).  If your `master` and their `master` both hold the same commit hash, this step achieves nothing.  Your intermediate command *has* made a new merge commit, but has not put it on any branch, because you are operating with a detached HEAD.

You have multiple options for fixing this.  For instance, you could replace the second group of three Git commands with:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only origin/master  # make sure our master matches theirs
# do whatever is required here if this step fails
git merge --no-ff <Branch_Name>
```

(Note that I have changed the argument to `git merge -no-ff` here to use the name you created in the first pair of commands.  We'll see a better way to deal with that in a moment.)

This way, the result of the middle group of commands is to create a new merge commit—the `--no-ff` enforces a true merge even if a fast-forward is possible—with your (local) branch name `master` being updated to contain the new commit.  That is, the new merge we just made is now `on branch master`, as `git status` will tell you.  This feeds into the final command—`git push origin master`—so that the `git push` transfers to `origin` the new merge commit you just made, then requests that they set *their* `master` to point to this new merge commit.

Alternatively, we can work with the detached HEAD by changing the final `git push` command to read:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/master
```

This request uses a longer / more-detailed *refspec*, `HEAD:refs/heads/master`, in place of the simple refspec `master`.  These refspec arguments are the arguments we pass to `git push` and `git fetch` after the name-or-URL of the remote.  That is, the general form of the command is `git push remote refspec1 refspec2 ... refspecN`, with every argument after the *`remote`* being a *`refspec`*.

A refspec is, in this second-simplest form, just two identifiers separated by a colon `:`.  The identifier `HEAD` means that the *source* of the push—the commit(s) to be pushed from our (local) Git to the remote Git—should be read from `HEAD`.  The second identifier, `refs/heads/master`, is the full name of the `master` branch in *their* Git: this is the name we will have our Git ask their Git to update.

The reason for spelling the whole thing out, `refs/heads/master`, is that when we use the simpler `master` refspec—the one without a colon—Git intuits from this that we mean our `master` branch and therefore we must also mean *their* `master` branch.  But we're anticipating, in this case, that we are on *no* branch: that we have a detached HEAD.  Our Git will not be able to infer that we must therefore mean *their* `master` *branch* too.  Perhaps we mean their *tag* `master`.<sup>1</sup>  By spelling out `refs/heads/master` we remove all ambiguity: we definitely mean their `master` *branch*.

Let's also take a look into this peculiar bit of code you've shown:

> ```
> git fetch <Fork_Repo_URL> <Fork_Repo_Branch>
> git checkout -b <Branch_Name> FETCH_HEAD
> ```

You create a (local) branch named *`Branch_Name`*, but then never use it.  Why?

---

<sup>1</sup>It's a very bad idea to create a tag named `master`, and if no one ever does this, our careful use of `refs/heads/master` here is not actually required.  So we're really just being careful to avoid tripping over *someone else's* error here.

---

#### Git is about commits, and not so much about branches

First, Git is really all about *commits*.  Git is not about files—though files *do* get stored in commits, as snapshots—and mainly provides branch *names* for us dumb humans, who cannot deal with big ugly commit hash IDs.  The true name of any one commit is its big ugly hash ID, such as `08da6496b61341ec45eac36afcc8f94242763468`.  Without this hash ID, Git can do nothing at all.  But humans just can't deal with hash IDs (quick, was that 08da64something, or 08da46something? did you have to look back at it to find out? can you remember the whole thing from one minute to the next?).  Humans *can*, however, remember *names* like `master`.  So Git will let us use names to substitute for these hash IDs.

Every hash ID is guaranteed to be unique.  However, *every* Git in the universe is required to agree that two identical commits have the *same* hash ID, so that you can pass commits from one Git to another through `git clone`, `git fetch`, and `git push`.  If you can find *two different commits* that have the *same* hash ID, you've essentially found a way to "break" Git.  For much more detail about this, see [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)

Each commit, as we just said, stores a snapshot.  That is, it has a full and complete copy of *every* file.<sup>2</sup>  That's the data for the commit—but it also has important *metadata*, such as who made the commit, when, and *why:* the log message they supplied when they made the commit, to tell us what the *purpose* of this new commit was.  One of the most important pieces of metadata here is that each commit stores the raw hash ID of its immediate predecessor or *parent* commit(s).  Most commits have exactly one parent hash ID.  Merge commits are defined as any commit that stores two or more parent hash IDs (and most of *these* store exactly two).

These parent hash IDs are how Git finds a *previous* commit.  Since every commit stores its immediate parent, we can always start at the *last* commit and work backwards.  If we let single uppercase letters stand in for real commit hash IDs, the commit whose hash ID is `H` stores its parent's hash ID, which we can call `G`.  We say that commit `H` *points to* commit `G`:

```
G <-H
```

Meanwhile, commit `G` has a parent hash ID, so it points to its own parent `F`:

```
<-F <-G <-H
```

Like `G`, `F` points to *its* parent.  If the whole repository has exactly eight commits, they might look like this:

```
A <-B <-C <-D <-E <-F <-G <-H
```

Commit `A` is the very first commit we ever made, so it *can't* pointing to its parent.  It doesn't *have* a parent, so it just doesn't list any parent at all.  This rather special kind of commit is a *root commit* and every non-empty repository has at least one.<sup>3</sup>

Much of Git's job is simply following all of these pointers when necessary.  These commits, with their internal backwards-pointing arrows, *are* the history in the repository.  Each commit has its own individual snapshot of *all* of your files.  Git produces diff listings by *comparing* any two commits.  The *changes* in a commit are whatever is different from parent to child, and the *parent* commit is recorded by hash ID *in* the child.  It's really that simple.

Note, though, that real hash IDs are random-looking as well as big and ugly.  We can find `H` from the diagram above because `H` is the last letter, but that doesn't work with real hash IDs.  So Git has to have a way to store the hash ID of the *last* commit in some branch, as well as to give us mere humans a way to identify that commit.  This is where **branch names** come in.

---

<sup>2</sup>That is, it has a full and complete file of every file that it has, but that's kind of redundant.  The idea here is that if you make some commit that has, say, a `README` file, then make a *second* commit in which you have not *changed* the `README` file, this second commit *has a copy of the `README` file*.  Git can and does actually *share* the two identical files, which it stores as *blob objects*, which have hash IDs just like commits.  Hence, no matter how many times you commit one particular version of a file, the repository stores only one copy of it.  Because all internal Git objects are completely and totally read-only, it's easy to share them.  They cannot be changed, so re-using some existing object is just a matter of re-using its hash ID.

<sup>3</sup>Most repositories probably have only one root commit, though you can make additional root commits once you know how.  You can also acquire new root commits by connecting your Git to some unrelated Git—a Git that you never `git clone`ed from, nor cloned from a clone of it, etc.  That other Git has its own root commit, with its own unique hash ID.  You obtain their commits so that they are now copied into your repository, and now their root commit is another root commit in your own Git.

---

#### Branch names are pointers to commits

A branch name simply stores the hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch.  To see how this works, imagine our eight-commit repository has one branch name, `master`.  The *name* `master` will point to commit `H` by storing the raw hash ID of commit `H`, and we can draw it like this:

```
A--...--G--H   <-- master
```

If we now make a *new* commit, Git will set the *new* commit's parent hash ID to `H`, write out the new commit to discover its hash ID, and see that the new commit's hash ID is `I` (well, really, some big ugly hash ID):

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I
```

Now Git simply writes `I`'s hash ID—whatever it really is—into the *name* `master`, giving us:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master
```

The *name* now points to the *last* commit, as it always does.  From the last commit, we—or Git—will work backwards, following the backwards-pointing arrows embedded inside each commit.  (I drew them as lines here just because it's easier on StakcOverflow, especially when I had to draw commit `I` on a diagonal below `H`.  If you can draw good backwards-pointing arrows, that's not a bad idea, whenever you draw commits.  It's a reminder that Git always works *backwards*.)

#### `HEAD` is something we usually attach to a branch name

Every time we make a new commit, Git just writes the hash ID of the new commit into a branch name.  But—*which one?*  To make more-than-one branch name work, in a Git repository, Git needs to remember *which branch we're on*.

The way Git does this is by "attaching HEAD".  The special name `HEAD`, written in all-capital letters like this, is normally attached to *one* branch name.  Let's go back to our eight-commit state:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Now let's create a new name, `dev`, that also points to commit `H`.  We'll leave `HEAD` attached to `master`, because we will use `git branch dev` to create `dev`, so that we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), dev
```

Now let's create a new commit `I`, and then another one `J`.  Since `HEAD` is attached to `master`, that's the *name* that Git will update:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- dev
```

Now let's `git checkout dev`, which will refill our work areas from commit `H` instead of commit `J` and will attach `HEAD` to the name `dev`:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

Now we can make another two commits:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

This action, of creating new commits with the *current* branch name advancing as we go, is how we build up these branches.  The *names* just hold the hash ID of each branch's tip-most commit.  *Tip* is Git's technical term for this.

If we now `git checkout master` to select commit `J` and name `master`, and then run `git merge dev`, Git will build a true merge commit.  The mechanism for making this merge involves finding the *merge base* commit—the point where the two branches were last "seen together", as it were—which in this case is obviously commit `H`.  We won't go into detail here, but the result is this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- dev
```

The *name* `master` now points to *merge commit* `M`.  `M` has a snapshot as usual, but unusually, has *two* parents, `J` and `L`.  When Git works backwards from `M`, it goes to *both* commits (though one at a time).  The history starting from `M` and working backwards includes `I-J` *and* `K-L`, and working backwards from there, `H`, `G`, and so on.

Note that nothing else is different!  The branch *names* still each point to just one commit.  Each commit still has a snapshot.  Each commit still has some set of parents.  The only thing special about a merge commit is that it has *more than one* parent, and therefore, the history diverges at the merge (and in this case re-converges at the fork at `H`).

#### Detaching HEAD

Once you understand the above, a *detached* HEAD is really pretty simple.  Git just stores a raw hash ID directly in the name `HEAD`, rather than attaching `HEAD` to a branch name and getting the hash ID from the branch name.  So we can have:

```
...--E--F   <-- name
         \
          G   <-- HEAD
```

If we make another new commit in this state, only the name `HEAD` remembers it:

```
...--E--F   <-- name
         \
          G--H   <-- HEAD
```

If we now `git checkout name` to get back on a branch, the new commit's hash IDs become hard to find:

```
...--E--F   <-- name (HEAD)
         \
          G--H   ???
```

What are the actual hash IDs of `G` and `H`?  I have no idea, and neither do you.  Can you *find* them?  If so, maybe you can get those commits back, by using their raw hash IDs, or creating a new name pointing to them.  If not, maybe not.  For instance, if commit `H`'s hash ID is still visible in a window, you can cut-and-paste it into a `git branch` command:

```
git branch recover-it <some big ugly hash ID>
```

which gives us:

```
...--E--F   <-- name (HEAD)
         \
          G--H   <-- recover-it
```

#### Branch names move, and can be created and destroyed as you like

So the summary of the above is:

- Each commit has its own unique hash ID.
- The *last* (or *tip*) commit of a branch is the one stored in some name.
- You can make new names at any time.  The only constraint here is that you have to have the commit already—you must have some existing commit, whose hash ID you can find, or name by some other name.
- You can *delete* names at any time, though if this might lose your only way to *find* some commit hash IDs, be careful!  (Git will try to be careful for you, requiring the `--force` flag or `git branch -D`, in various cases.  This code is a little tricky and has evolved over time; different versions of Git have different rules about what's easy or hard to delete.)
- Branch names move *automatically* when you create commits.
- The special name `HEAD` is usually attached *to* a branch name, but in *detached HEAD* mode, *isn't*.

There's one other key thing to note, though: **Branch names are local to one particular Git repository.**

#### Remote-tracking names

Again, *branch names are local to one particular Git repository.*  If I've made a clone of your Git repository, I may have a `master` and/or a `dev`.  These are *my* `master` and *my* `dev`; they are not *your* `master`, nor your `dev`.  I can make new commits and change the hash IDs stored in my `master` and my `dev`, however I like.

But since I got all of my initial commits *from* your repository, all of my initial commit hash IDs *match* all of *your* Git's hash IDs.  I might like to remember that your `master` points to, say, `a123456...`.  That way I can see that since I cloned your repository, I've created two new `master` commits.

The way my Git remembers *your* Git's branch names is that my Git has *remote-tracking names*.<sup>4</sup>  My Git has an `origin/master` to remember for me where *your* Git had *your* `master`, the last time I talked to your Git:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- origin/master
```

Here I have made two new commits, that you don't have.

Of course, branch names move.  Your Git may have new commits.  They might be on your `master`.  So I can connect my Git to your Git by using `git fetch`:

```
git fetch origin
```

It turns out that you, too, made two new commits.  They have their own big ugly hash IDs but I'll just call them `K` and `L`.  My Git obtains these two commits, and sees that *your* `master` points to L`, so my Git now has this:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/master
```

Let's say I now run:

```
git merge origin/master
```

This creates a new merge commit `M`, using `H` as the merge base and `J` and `L` as the two branch tip commits:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- origin/master
```

Haven't we seen this before?

Scan up to the example where I merged `dev` into `master`.  Yes, we've seen this exact scenario earlier.  The only real difference was that I was using my own `dev`; this time I'm using my *remote-tracking* name `origin/master` instead of my *branch* name `dev`.

So a remote-tracking name like `origin/master` is just a name holding one commit hash ID.  In that sense, it's just like a branch name.  But there's already one big key difference.  **If I run `git checkout origin/master`, I get a detached HEAD:**

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- HEAD, origin/master
```

If I now run `git merge master` I'll get a commit `M` again, but like this:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- HEAD
         \    /
          K--L   <-- origin/master
```

There's a second important difference to this `M`, but I'll just footnote it.<sup>5</sup>

The last important thing to remember about remote-tracking names is that `git fetch origin` updates *all* of your `origin/*` names by default.  That is, your Git calls up their Git.  Their Git lists out *all* their branch names.  Your Git ends the `fetch` operation by updating your own memory of *all* of their branch names.

You *can* limit which remote-tracking names your Git updates.  The `git pull` command invokes `git fetch` in a way that often *does* limit them this way.  I recommend not using `git pull` at all, but that is also a matter of opinion; you *can* use `git pull` successfully, as long as you remember that it means *run `git fetch` with specific options, then run a second Git command with other options.*

---

<sup>4</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*.  I don't like the extra word *branch* in this phrase, so I leave it out, but you should know that the Git documentation keeps it in there.

<sup>5</sup>This merge commit has, as its *first* parent, commit `L`.  Commit `J` is its *second* parent.  The order of the parents is sometimes unimportant—Git will follow history by going back along *both* paths—but sometimes important, because Git has a `--first-parent` option to commands like `git log` to tell it *when you come to a merge, follow only the first parent*.  When and whether this first-parent property is useful to *you* depends on *how you use Git*, but it's worth noting that `git pull` tends to make these kinds of swapped linkages: the commit that many people believe *should* be the first parent is the second, and vice versa.  This is all a matter of opinion, but the opinion is strong enough to have Bitbucket provide an optional device to prevent what they call [Foxtrot Merges](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/stop-foxtrots-now/).

---

#### `git fetch` with a URL, vs using a remote

In all of the examples so far, we've used `git fetch origin` or just `git fetch` to obtain new commits from the Git that our Git gets when our Git calls up someone at the URL stored under the name `origin`.  But you're using:

```
git fetch <url> <branch-name>
```

This form of `git fetch` is much older, dating back to 2005 or earlier, before the invention of the *remote* names like `origin`.

When using this form of `git fetch`, **there are no remote-tracking names**.  Remote-tracking names like `origin/master` are built *by* taking the remote's name, `origin`, and their branch name `master`.  Without a remote name—with only a URL—there is no place to build a remote-tracking name.

In the bad old days before remote names, we had to do things this way.  By running:

```
git fetch <url> <branch-name>
```

we limited our `git fetch` to calling up the Git at the URL and asking *only about that one branch*.  Their Git would say, e.g., *OK, my `develop` is `a123456...`* and hand over commit `a123456...` and any earlier commits we needed to give our Git the ability to walk backwards from `a123456...` to a root commit.

So, we now would have:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   [a123456...]
```

We had to stash the actual hash ID of commit `L`, whatever it might be, somewhere.  The *somewhere* is the special name `FETCH_HEAD`.

Note that `FETCH_HEAD` is *overwritten* by each `git fetch` command.  The name `FETCH_HEAD` suffices to find commit `L` *right now*, after the one `git fetch` we just ran, but it won't last.  The next `git fetch` will overwrite `FETCH_HEAD` and if we don't save `L`'s hash ID somewhere quickly, we'll lose it and never be able to find it in the haystack of random-looking hash IDs inside a Git repository.

So that's why you have this second command:

```
git checkout -b <branch> FETCH_HEAD
```

The name `FETCH_HEAD` serves the same function as a remote-tracking name, but only until the next `git fetch`.  We use the poor substitute for a remote-tracking name to create a local *branch* name pointing to that very same commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- branch
```

That's *our* branch name, which we are now free to do with as we will.

This kind of clutters up our repository.  It's a much better idea to create a remote for the fork:

```
git remote add xyzzy <fork_repo_url>
```

(pick a better name than `xyzzy`, of course).  Now we can run:

```
git fetch xyzzy
```

and acquire or update our *remote-tracking names* `xyzzy/master`, `xyzzy/develop`, `xyzzy/feature/tall`, and so on.  We don't have to worry about dealing with the `FETCH_HEAD` file that gets overwritten on each new fetch—including a fetch to `origin`—that could mess with our memory of hash IDs from the fork-repo.

Comment: Sir, I will try to completely read your answer..but need some time 

Comment: Sorry sir, but the commands you have mentioned above are not creating any merge commit, it is just merging just like previous.

Comment: I'm not sure which commands you refer to by "commands ... mentioned above", but note that the short summary version has *two* `git merge` invocations, one with `--ff-only` and one with `--no-ff`. The `--no-ff` one should either make a merge, or produce messages about *why* it has not (yet) made a merge; you'll need to include those messages.

Comment: commands mentioned above means the commands I have mentioned in my question. Using those commands in the cloned upstream repository working perflectly, creates a merge commit as well. But from forked repository and configuring an upstream remote is not producing any merge commit

Comment: I'm not going to read any more about this. Work through the long section above and learn how Git makes commits, how branch names work, and how `git push` works.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout falcondev
git pull central/falcondev
git merge --no-ff origin/falcondev
```

Comment: Sorry sir, but I also tried with rebase, but it is not creating any extra merge commit.

Comment: rebasing is a technique to avoid creating an extra merge commit. So if I understand well, you want that commit?

Comment: Yes sir, I want that extra commit. But that commit is appearing only when I am merging the request from gitlab web interface. The commit looks like-

Merge branch master into master

See merge request ...

Comment: can you please give the simplified output (only the commit that you want to merge and his position in the point of view of the master branch) of this command `git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph` just before the `git merge` command

Comment: I have added the output in my question above...please see that

Comment: could you please tell which branches are concerned by this question: master? falcondev?

Comment: Right now, I am checkouted to a different branch, as I don't have permission to the master branch now

Comment: Organization created a different branch for me to do this kind of testing

Comment: ok, so right now which branches are you using for this kind of testing?

Comment: So for your testing, you are merging which branch into which branch please ? origin/falcondev, central/falcondev, falcondev, master, ... ?

Comment: Merging origin/falcondev to central/falcondev

Comment: Thank you so much sir, but it is just adding commits to my fork repository, not in that upstream(central) repository

Comment: OK, I changed the answer to add the merge commit to the upstream not to the fork repository

Comment: Sir, can you please go through the answer I have mentioned in my previous question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890831/gitlab-merge-request-from-forked-repository-remote-through-command-line-not-crea)

Comment: I'm glad you fixed your problem :)

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your help