# Gitlab merge request from forked repository remote through command line not creating any merge commits

Tags: git, powershell, merge, gitlab, command-line-interface

I am trying to merge a merge request (Gitlab) from command line.

After working on a dummy repository, I came to know that if **I have the permission** to merge a merge request, I can **merge them directly** through command line.

I started by **cloning the upstream repository** in my local system. After that, I made a change in my **forked repository** and created a merge request for the same.

While manually trying to merge the request from command line using this approach, I am getting an extra commit which is a **merge commit**(--no-ff).

```sh
git fetch <Fork_Repo_URL> <Fork_Repo_Branch>
git checkout -b <Branch_Name> FETCH_HEAD

git fetch origin
git checkout origin/master
git merge --no-ff <Remote_Name>-<Branch_Name>

git push origin master
```

Note: The above commands are used from the cloned upstream repository.

Now, I want to do the same without cloning the upstream repository and rather by **just adding an upstream** remote to my forked repository.

I followed all the steps mentioned in gitlab docs for merging the request manually, but to my surprise, I am unable to see any merge commit, although the merge request is merged after using those commands.

```sh
git remote add central <Central_Repo_URL>

git fetch origin master
git checkout -b my_master FETCH_HEAD

git fetch central
git checkout central/master
git merge --no-ff my_master-master

git push central master
```

So, is there any way to merge a merge request by configuring a remote in forked repository(I have permission), and generate a merge commit as well?

I tried this way as well.

```sh
git fetch central
git checkout central/master
git merge --no-ff origin/master

git push central master
```

I have also tried commit amend, rebase.

Comment: I am no sure, but I think that this is the same question as your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58889904/gitlab-merge-a-merge-request-from-command-line-not-generating-any-commitno-fast

Comment: Ya sorry but in the previous question, I told about origin in upstream repo. I also though to change the previous question, but it is little bit different

Comment: If I got my answer for this one, I will delete the previous one

Comment: there is no problem :) By the way, I am trying to help you in the other question/thread ;)

Comment: See my long answer to your previous question.

Comment: @torek actually by following all the steps I have written in my question working perfectly whenever I am setting up a clone of the Upstream Repository, without setting any remote as upstream or central inside of my forked repository. But inside of my forked remote(central), this commands not generating any merge commit. But in the previous case, it is perfectly creating an extra commit.

Comment: Note that any time you `git checkout` a *remote-tracking* name, Git will tell you that you have entered **detached HEAD** mode. All commits you make in this mode **are lost** when you *exit* this mode. **None** of them are pushed by `git push <remote> master`.

Comment: So then how can I get them, get that merge commit as well?

Comment: I think that's the problem you have spotted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution from torek's comment above. Actually by doing

```sh
git checkout central/master
```

I am going to a **detached HEAD**, all commits in this mode are lost when I exit the node.

So the best solution should be to create a local branch which can track that upstream remote named **central/master**.(Please ignore my branch name)

```sh
git checkout -b centralMaster central/master
```

Now after doing all the above steps, we can easily solve this issue, and a no fast forward merge commit as well.

```sh
git checkout -b centralMaster central/master
git fetch central
```

```sh
git fetch origin
git merge origin/falcondev --no-ff -m "<Message>"
git push central centralMaster:master
```

Now all the above problems can be easily solved.

Please comment if I had made any mistake on these steps.