# What happens when a blob is created in git?

Tags: git, binary, blob

Git stores files as blobs, and then uses a SHA-1 checksum as a key to find each specific blob amongst the others, similar to a filename identifying a file.

So how does this dark magic work? That is, How does one start with a text file and end up with a blob? Is a blob created by dereferencing the memory memory address of the file or something?

Comment: [Git Plumbing and Porcelain](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain), a must read if you really want to learn more about this.

Comment: "Blobs" in git are files. One starts with a text file and finishes with a binary file. No magic.

Comment: If you are using an operating system that doesn't distinguish between text files and binary files (like Unix), it's not even that complicated. You start with a file, Git hashes it, and uses the resulting hash to locate a copy of the file in the data base.

Comment: git-from-the-inside-out could answers very well to your question: https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/two/git-from-the-inside-out

Answer (score 5):

There's very little actual magic in Git.  The one bit that is pretty magic is (are?) the various [Secure Hash Algorithm (SHA) checksum designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms), Git's use of these checksums, and how they form a [Merkle Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree), but this is more "math magic" than anything else.

I *think* you're really asking "how does Git come up with the hash ID", and the answer to that one is simple:

- Find the size of the file, in bytes.  Print this in decimal, e.g., `123`.
- Put the printed size in decimal after the word `blob` and a space.  Append an ASCII NUL character, `b'\0'` in Python for instance.  Hash the prefix and the data, and the result is the blob's hash ID:

  ```
  $ python3
  ...
  >>> data = b"some file data\n"
  >>> prefix = "blob {}\0".format(len(data)).encode("utf-8")
  >>> import hashlib
  >>> h = hashlib.sha1()
  >>> h.update(prefix)
  >>> h.update(data)
  >>> h.hexdigest()
  'a831035a26dd2f75c2dd622c70ee22a10ee74a65'
  ```

We can check by using Git's object hasher:

```
$ echo 'some file data' | git hash-object -t blob --stdin
a831035a26dd2f75c2dd622c70ee22a10ee74a65
```

The hashes match, so this is the blob hash for any file that consists solely of the 15-byte line "some file data" as terminated by a newline.  Note that it is the *content* that determine the hash ID: the file's *name* here is irrelevant.  (This means the file's name must be, and is, stored elsewhere—in Git, in one or more *tree* objects.)

(Note that SHA-1 is no longer considered cryptographically secure.  Git is slowly being migrated to other hash algorithms, but there is no rush here.  See [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452))