# How to push a folder having HTML and js files remotely to a branch of a repository on someone's GitHub account by Terminal?

Tags: git, github, push, branch

I have the folder on Desktop on my mac. I really want to upload this to a particular branch of a repository of on my friend GitHub account. The lists below are what I do not know how to do however I search it on the internet.

1. How to access the friend account / the branch name
2. how to push my folder to the branch, not master? or origin?
3. I am opening Terminal which stages the folder which I want to upload to the branch on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Git is not a file transfer program.  Git is a version control system.<sup>1</sup>  You may or may not be able to accomplish your actual goal, but you'll have to change how you *think about* this goal.

To use Git, you'll need a version built for your computer.  You mentioned "mac" so we might assume you already have one.  You can run `git --version` in a Terminal window to see which version of Git is installed.

**Git operates on a *repository*, one repository at a time.**  A repository is primarily a collection of *commits*.  Commits *contain* files, but there are no *folders* involved.  The files simply have long names that include slashes, such as `README.md`, `lib/xyz.py`, and so on.  Your computer will demand that the *file* named `lib/xyz.py` be stored as a *folder* named `lib` that has a sub-file named `xyz.py` within it, and Git will do that, but as far as Git is concerned, what you have is a file named `lib/xyz.py`.  The upshot of this particular quirk is that you cannot store an *empty* folder: Git won't store a file named, say, `joey/`, so if you want Git to create the OS-level folder named `joey`, you *must* make a commit that has inside it a file named `joey/anything`.  A common trick is to create the file `joey/.gitignore`, which can be empty: if there is a commit that has this file in it, and someone does a `git checkout` of this commit, Git will create `joey/` if needed so that it can create `.gitignore` *inside* `joey/` so as to satisfy the requirement of creating a file named `joey/.gitignore`.

**Files inside a commit inside a Git repository are extracted relative to wherever the repository itself resides.**  You mentioned that the existing folder is in your `~/Desktop`.  For concreteness let's say these files are named `j/1` and `j/2` (i.e., `~/Desktop/j/1`, `~/Desktop/j/2`).  You could—note that this is inadvisable in general—create a Git repository in your own home directory, such that you can just `git add Desktop/j`.  But now suppose your friend copies this repository to *his* file system underneath, say, `~/src/github.com/joey`.  Extracting the commit will, on his system, create `~/src/github.com/joey/Desktop/j/1` and `~/src/github.com/joey/Desktop/j/2`.  In other words, **you control only a relative name**, not an absolute path.

**Every Git repository is independent of every other Git repository.**  When and whether you access your friend's repository on GitHub, you can use that access to transfer *commits*—there's that word again—from that Git repository to your Git repository, or from your Git repository to that Git repository.  Meanwhile, you friend will have a *third* Git repository on *his* computer.  He will use his Git to call up the Git on GitHub, and obtain commits from that Git, or send commits to that Git.  So the Git repository on GitHub is really a *rendezvous*, in this case.

**You may or may not have permission to access your friend's Git repository on GitHub**.  These permissions are controlled by whoever created the repository (presumably, him).  However, GitHub *is* built for sharing.  The *way* GitHub encourages sharing is to use what GitHub calls a *fork*.  A fork is very much like a *clone*, with some additional GitHub-provided glue.  (There are other Git providers, such as Bitbucket and GitLab, all of which have adopted this same idea.)  If you fork your friend's GitHub repository, this gives you a GitHub repository of your own—a *fourth* copy—that you can use for this rendezvous operation.  It's likely that you will have to do this.<sup>2</sup>

**Once you have access to GitHub** (for which there are many tutorials, including ones on GitHub help pages), **you will need to clone your friend's repository, or your fork of your friend's repository, so as to create a local repository on your laptop.**  This is where you really start getting in to using Git.  It simplifies the picture a lot here if there are just *two* repositories here: yours on GitHub, and the clone you are about to make.  So we will make this simplifying assumption: that you have in fact made a fork of your friend's repository, so that you are accessing *your* repository on GitHub.

---

<sup>1</sup>Some would argue that Git is merely a file system *pretending* to be a version control system, and there's a lot of merit to that argument, but let's stick with "distributed version control system" or DVCS, as the tag info in [git](/questions/tagged/git) suggests.

<sup>2</sup>Having done this, you may be able to dispense with the idea of using Git on your own laptop at all: GitHub offer several ways to manipulate commits in your fork without having to clone your own fork to your own computer.  If you plan to use Git a lot, though, it's far better to copy the entire repository onto your laptop, so that you can manipulate commits there easily.

---

#### A Git repository is mostly just a collection of commits

Early in the text above, we mentioned that a repository is primarily a collection of commits.  To use Git, you need to understand what a commit is, what it does for you, and how it does that.

Every commit, in Git, holds a complete snapshot of some set of files.  These are the files that are contained in that commit.  These files are read-only, frozen in time forever.  You cannot change them; even Git itself cannot change them.  They are just copies of files: they have a name, such as `README.md` or `lib/xyz.py`, and some content (the contents of the `README.md` and the `lib/xyz.py`), and one bit of *mode* information that tells Git: *this file should be executable* or *this file should be not-executable*.  For plain text files, rather than command you can run, the file should be not-executable.

A Git commit contains this snapshot as its *data*, but also contains some *metadata*.  The metadata includes two human names, their email addresses, two date-and-time stamps, and some more stuff we'll get into in a moment.  The two names are the *author* of the commit and the *committer* of the commit, and usually these are the same person.  The email addresses are those of the author and committer, and the two date-and-time stamps are for the author and committer.  You need to tell Git about yourself:

```
git config --global user.name '...'
git config --global user.email '...'
```

These are the strings that your Git will put into *new* commits, to hold the author and committer user names and email addresses.  You can use just about anything you like here—Git does not care who or what you call yourself—but if you want people to know about you, you should put real stuff here.

Every Git commit gets its own unique ID: a *hash ID*.  That hash ID is created at the time you create the commit.  Git uses a new hash ID, one that has never been used for any other commit anywhere, and will never use it ever again for any other commit.<sup>3</sup>  Moreover, *every Git in the universe* will now agree, from this point on, that *this* hash ID is for *this* commit, and only this commit.

This is also why you can't *change* **anything** in *any* commit, ever: the hash ID is constructed from all of the commit's contents, including your name and email address, and the two date-and-time stamps, along with all of the files saved in the snapshot, and so on.  This lets two Gits call each other up and merely exchange *hash IDs:* if their Git has hash `083378cc35c4dbcc607e4cdd24a5fca440163d17`, and your Git has hash `083378cc35c4dbcc607e4cdd24a5fca440163d17`, why, you both have that commit.  If one of you doesn't, the other one can give it to whichever one doesn't.

But hash IDs are big and ugly and *look* totally random.  Humans can't remember hash IDs.  So Git sets things up so that we don't even have to *try* to do that.  We have a computer, after all.  *It* can remember these big ugly hash IDs for us.  And here, there's something pretty magic.

**Every commit stores some set of hash IDs inside it.**  Usually there is exactly one of these.  This is part of the metadata, along with your name and email address and so on.  When you make a *new* commit, Git stores, in that new commit, the hash ID of the *current* commit.  So the new commit you just made *remembers* the unique hash ID of the commit that comes before it.

**This is also where branch names come in.**  A branch name, in Git, merely holds *one* hash ID.  The hash ID stored inside a branch name is the hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch.

Whenever something holds the hash ID of a commit, in Git, we say that this something *points to* the commit.  So the *latest* commit *points to* its earlier or *parent* commit, and that commit points to its parent—the grandparent of the latest commit—and so on.  Meanwhile, the *branch name* points to the latest commit.

---

<sup>3</sup>There's a theoretical possibility that the new hash ID for a commit *won't* be unique.  In practice, this is not a problem.  See [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452) for details.

---

#### Visualizing branches and the commit process

If we use single uppercase letters to stand in for the actual big ugly hash IDs, we can draw this kind of chain of commits like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

Here, we have one branch name—`master`—that points to the *last* commit, `H`, in the repository.  Commit `H` (whatever its real hash ID is) contains the raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`, so that `H` points to `G`.  Commit `G` in turn contains the raw hash ID of *its* earlier commit `F`, which contains another raw hash ID, and so on.

This whole process only ends when we get to the very first commit we—or whoever—made, in this repository.  That *first* commit doesn't point back to any earlier commit, because it can't: there wasn't any earlier commit.

If we get lazy and draw the internal backwards-pointing arrows as connecting lines, this lets us draw out the entire eight-commit repository like this:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master
```

This lets us see how branch names work in Git.  A branch name, as we already know, points to *one* commit—the *last* one on the branch.  Let's make a new branch name that *also* points to commit `H`:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master, feature
```

Now we need a way for us (and Git) to remember *which branch name we're using:* is it `master`, or is it `feature`?  Let's attach the special name `HEAD`, in all uppercase,<sup>4</sup> to *one* of these names, for this purpose:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), feature
```

If we run `git checkout feature`, this moves the attached `HEAD` to `feature`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, feature (HEAD)
```

Either way, we're still using *commit* `H`.  But we're *on* a different branch.  This matters because of what happens when we make a new commit.

To make a new commit, we need to understand how the index and work-tree work.  This answer is already very big, so I will just say: *look elsewhere for that*.  Assuming we know how to use them, though, we'll change some files and `git add` and then run `git commit`.  Git will:

- use the current commit `H` as the parent of the new commit;
- use our name and email address, and the current date-and-time from the computer, for the author and committer;
- collect from us a *log message* in which we remind everyone else, and our future selves, *why* we are making this new commit now; and
- actually make the new commit, saving a frozen snapshot of all of our files forever, or at least, for as long as this new commit continues to exist.

The *parent* of our new snapshot is `H`, so let's draw the new commit and call it `I` to stand in for whatever unique hash ID it gets:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, feature (HEAD)
            \
             I
```

Now comes the really tricky bit: having just made this new commit, Git *writes its hash ID into the branch name to which `HEAD` is attached*.  This changes the name `feature` so that `feature` now points to new commit `I`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

This is how branches grow, one commit at a time, as we work in Git.  Each *new* commit we make points back to the commit we *were* using, at the time, before we made the new one.  The *current branch name*—the one `HEAD` is attached to—*moves* to point to the newest commit, which just got a new and unique hash ID.

---

<sup>4</sup>On the Mac, you can often get away with typing in `head` in lowercase.  Try not to get into the habit of doing this!  It doesn't work right once you start using Git's `git worktree add` feature, and it does not work at all on most Linux systems.  If you don't like typing `HEAD` in all caps, consider using `@`, which Git treats as a synonym for `HEAD`.

---

#### Making a clone

Before we can get to this point, we have to start out with a *copy* of the repository that we forked on GitHub.  To make this copy, we must:

- tell our Git to make a new, empty repository;
- tell our Git to connect to the Git over on GitHub; and
- tell our Git that we'd like *every* commit from that Git repository, into this new empty repository.

To do that, we can use `git clone`.  The `git clone` command needs the URL by which our computer will call up some other computer over the Internet, and have that computer access a Git repository.  In the case of some GitHub repository, the URL will be `ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git` or `https://github.com/user/repo.git`.  (We'll need to set up an SSH key, or provide a password, or otherwise let the GitHub machines know that we are in fact ourselves: it's up to GitHub to tell us how to authenticate.  If we're using some other hosting provider, *they* will tell us how to authenticate.  Again, there are plenty of places to find help about this, including GitHub's own help pages.)

Hence we might run:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git
```

(but with `user` and `repo.git` adjusted as appropriate).

What our Git will do with this command is:

1. Create a new, empty directory in the *current* directory.  The name of this new empty directory is derived from `repo.git`.  If you want some other name, add it to the `git clone` command, e.g., `git clone url new-directory`.  (You can use the name of an existing empty directory, although there was a bug in Git for a long time that makes this slightly inadvisable.<sup>5</sup>)
2. Initialize this new empty directory *as* a Git repository.
3. Save the URL under a *remote* name `origin`.  Each Git repository can store any number of *remotes*, which are just short names for another Git repository.  It's just convention to use the name `origin` as the remote for the repository you cloned.  You can choose another name, but I will assume you don't, here.
4. Do any other special configuration we ask for.  (We didn't call for anything special, but if we had, this is the step where Git would do it.)
5. Run `git fetch origin`: this calls up *their* Git at that URL, and gets from it, most or all of its commits.<sup>6</sup>
6. Run `git checkout` to create a new local branch name, usually `master`, based on commits obtained in step 5.

At this point you will need to use your local computer's command—whatever that is; on the Mac, `cd` or `chdir`—to move into the Git repository that was created in step 2, in the previously-empty directory created in step 1.

You now have a clone of some other, existing Git repository.  This clone has *its own* branch names.  The branch names that were in the *other* repository exist in this clone as *remote-tracking names.*<sup>7</sup>  That is, if they had both `master` and `feature`, you now have the names `origin/master` and `origin/feature`.

**A remote-tracking name is just your Git's way of remembering their Git's branch names.**  Remember, a branch name holds the hash ID of *one* commit—the *last* commit on the branch, from which Git works backwards to find earlier commits.  It's very useful, at times, to know which commit hash IDs *their* Git has stored in *their* branch names.  But your `master` is *yours*, not theirs.  So your Git stores *their* `master` hash-ID pair in *your* name `origin/master`.

These remote-tracking names get updated when you run `git fetch`.  Other than `git fetch` and `git push`—which we'll get into in just a moment—*your* Git runs on *your* computer and never talks to the network.  *All the stuff you need is in your own Git repository*, because your Git got **every** commit from their Git.<sup>8</sup>

---

<sup>5</sup>If you interrupt the clone, or it fails, `git clone` will *remove* the partial, failed clone.  The bug was that if you gave `git clone` an empty directory name, and the clone failed, Git would remove the empty directory.  This is pretty harmless, but it's still surprising.  It's fixed now, but some systems have really old versions of Git installed, and there is little reason to tempt fate, or Murphy's Law, here.

<sup>6</sup>Technically, `git fetch` can only get the commits that the other Git *offers*.  But normally it offers all commits.  For GitHub repositories, they also offer *pull request* commits, and your Git normally *doesn't* get those.

<sup>7</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but I've decided that the word "branch" in this phrase is distracting and slightly harmful.  It's up to you to decide for yourself is you agree.  Be aware that people use the phrase "remote-tracking branch names" or even "remote branch", but you can't `git checkout` a remote-tracking name the way you can a real, local, branch name.  What you get is instead what Git calls a *detached HEAD*.

<sup>8</sup>Despite the fact that *every* commit holds a full snapshot of *every file*, commits are actually very space-efficient.  Git has several storage tricks here.  The first and most obvious one is that since every commit is frozen for all time, any time *any* file in *any* commit has the same *content* as some other file in *any other* commit, the two commits can just share the compressed, frozen, Git-only version of that file.  So if you have a million commits, but most of them keep re-using the same files every time, you don't have a million copies of the files.  Some files might only exist in two or three versions across all million commits.

---

#### Transferring commits to another Git

We saw just a moment ago how `git fetch` has your Git call up some other Git and get from it, any commits they have, that your Git wants, that your Git doesn't already have.  To do the same thing in the other direction—to have your Git call up their Git, but then *give* them commits—we use `git push`.

Besides the fact that `git push` *sends* commits *to* their Git, there is one other key difference here.  Remember that Git *finds* commits by starting from some name and working backwards.  Suppose your Git has this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

and *their* Git has this:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

When you `git fetch` from their Git, your Git finds that their Git has one commit they have—commit `I`—that you want.  So your Git *gets* that commit.  But your Git now changes *their* name, `master`, to your remote-tracking name `origin/master`, so that you end up with:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- origin/master
```

This doesn't work with `git push`.

Let's say we start with the above, then add a new commit `J` to our own `master`:

```
             J   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- origin/master
```

There's nothing *wrong* with this picture, really—it's normal enough in Git—but suppose we now have our Git call up their Git and send them commit `J`.  What *they* will have at this point is:

```
             J   [the commit we sent them]
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

How will they *find* commit `J`, when there is no *name* pointing to it?  If we had them set a name like `joey/master`, that would do the job.  But our `git push` is going to ask them to set *their* name `master` to point to commit `J`:

```
             J   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   ???
```

**If they obey this request, they will "lose" commit `I`.**  So they simply won't obey this request!  They will say: *No, I won't change my `master` the way you asked, because I'd lose track of some of my own commits.*

What we need to do at this point is come up with a better arrangement of commits.

In *our* Git repository, we can now:

- copy existing commit `J` to a new and improved `J'`, or
- *merge* existing commits `I` and `J` to a new merge commit `K`.

To do these, we would use either `git rebase` or `git merge`.  I'm going to skip all the details of how they work, and just show the final result.

If we use `git merge`, we get:

```
             J
            / \
...--F--G--H   K   <-- master
            \ /
             I   <-- origin/master
```

Commit `K` is slightly special.  Instead of pointing back to *one* parent, it points back to *two:* both `J` *and* `I`.  It still has a snapshot of all of our files as usual, but it remembers two previous commits for us.  So now we can have our Git call up their Git and send commit `K` to them, then politely request that they set *their* `master` to point to commit `K`, just like ours does.

This time, that *won't* lose access to commit `I`—from `K`, Git will go back to *both* `J` *and* `I`, and then from both of those to `H`—so they'll accept, and we will end up with:

```
             J
            / \
...--F--G--H   K   <-- master, origin/master
            \ /
             I
```

They accepted our polite request to move *their* master, so our Git moves *our* `origin/master` to remember that their `master` also selects commit `K`.  Our branches are now in sync.

Or, if we *rebase* our `J` by copying it to a new-and-improved commit `J'`, we get this:

```
             J   [abandoned]
            /
...--F--G--H   J'  <-- master
            \ /
             I   <-- origin/master
```

We totally give up on our old commit `J` and just have our `master` remember `J'` instead.  If we use `git log`, we never even *see* commit `J`.  It's as though it vanished entirely.  Our Git secretly keeps our original `J` for at least 30 days by default, in case we decide that this rebase was a bad idea, but it's not visible to most ordinary examination.

Since it's not visible, when we run `git push origin master`, our Git offers their Git commit `J'` only, and asks their Git to set *their* `master` to point to `J'`.  This time, they have no objection—they won't lose commit `I`—so they do it, and we get, in our repository, this picture, assuming we don't keep drawing the original `J`:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J'  <-- master, origin/master
```

So, this covers (very lightly) when and how to use either `git merge` or `git rebase` to adjust things so that you can `git push` your commits to your own GitHub fork.  We now need one last step, though.

#### Pull requests

Hosting providers like GitHub, GitLab, and Bitbucket all offer this idea of a *fork*, which is a kind of clone that adds another feature that they all call *pull requests*.  Each of them implement this slightly differently internally, in ways that may or may not be visible if you look hard enough, but they all use enough common stuff to make experience with one provider carry over.

In particular, once you have done a `git push` from your laptop to your GitHub repository, your GitHub repository now has commits in it that are not in the repository you forked.  You can now make a *pull request* to your friend.  Using the GitHub web interface, you click on various clicky buttons they provide.  They compare the commits in *your* fork to the commits in the other Git that you told them to fork earlier.

They do this comparing with the same graph-style operations we drew in the `git push` section above, but—in a misguided attempt to simplify it all away—they tend *not* to show you the actual graph.  Since the actual graph—the connections from commit to commit—are the key to when and whether this stuff works, I think this is a huge disservice.  Still, it mostly works—except when it doesn't, and then you have to add *their* GitHub repository to *your* laptop clone as a second remote.<sup>8</sup>

Anyway, with some luck, your pull request will turn out to be a simple case.  Your friend can then use *his* computer to sign in to *his* GitHub account, accept your pull request, and hence copy your commits—the ones you sent to *your* GitHub fork from *your* laptop—into *his* original GitHub repository.  Now he can download those commits into *his* Git, using `git fetch` on *his* laptop.  His `origin/master` or `origin/whatever` remote-tracking name will adjust to point to the new commit in his GitHub copy that has the same hash ID and *is* the same commit you sent to *your* GitHub copy from *your* laptop.

---

<sup>8</sup>You'd probably have to do this anyway, even if they did show you the actual graph, but at least you'd know right away—and they would be able to explain what's needed.  But they don't show this, and therefore cannot explain it either.

---

#### Conclusion: redundancy

This one commit you made, which stores the files you wanted to transfer, has now gone through *four* Git repositories: yours on your laptop, your fork of his GitHub repository, his GitHub repository, and his Git repository on your laptop.  All of you *share* this commit, which has as its parent(s) some other shared commit(s), which have more parents, and so on—but except on the GitHub computers, which are physically together and therefore can share the underlying copy of the actual commit,<sup>9</sup> there are actually many copies of this commit.

This distributed nature, in which *every* Git clone has a copy of *every* commit—well, every commit it has—which in turn has a copy of *every file* in that snapshot—is how Git provides redundancy and hence reliability.  Note that one lone Git repository on *one* computer is subject to data loss, if that one computer fails.  But with a repository that has dozens of clones, some on well-backed-up hosting providers, there's probably always *some* way to get most of your data back.

---

<sup>9</sup>Or, maybe they're not physically shared or adjacent.  How and when GitHub share the data across repositories is up to GitHub.

Comment: Hello Torek, thank you for sending me the detail. I try to read the whole paragraph and challenge it. I think I did not understand the role of git.  I will try to command from the top to the bottom sentence you sent. I really appreciate it!!! Thank you so much!!!