# Git local master is ahead despite making no changes

Tags: git

Apologies if this is obvious i'm no git expert.

This morning i went into my local repo and did the following:

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout master
```

And got a message that i've seen plenty of times before:

```
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 8 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

The problem is that i have never made any changes to this branch whatsoever. I tried git pull but it just responds with 'already up to date'.

'Git log origin/master..master' shows several commits to the branch from other authors which do not appear in the remote branch, so the message seems to make sense, but i don't understand how i can have commits from other authors in my local copy which are not in the remote repo

How do i get to the bottom of this?

Comment: `git log origin/master..master` will show you the commits you have that the upstream doesn’t.

Comment: Perhaps someone force pushed to the remote and removed those commits from it, after you got them into your local repository?

Comment: Sorry - that was actually what i tried when i mentioned git log. I've edited my question to make clearer. What perplexes me is that i haven't commited anything with this repo since i cloned it a week ago, though i have pulled updates several times. What i'm trying to understand is how i can, therefore, have commits in my local repo from another author which are not in the remote - surely this is impossible unless someone has delete them from the remote one?

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen - thanks, thats certainly the only reason i can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TL;DR is that [Lasse V. Karlsen's speculation in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61656035/git-local-master-is-ahead-despite-making-no-changes#comment109067091_61656035):

> Perhaps someone force pushed to the remote and removed those commits from it, after you got them into your local repository?

is probably the answer.  Run:

```
git reflog origin/master
```

and look for the string `forced-update` in the output; if you see this, that's what happened.

#### Long: what all this means

Git is, at its heart, really all about *commits*.  Commits are the unit of storage we work with.  Each commit has a sort of "true name", universally the same in *every* Git, which is its raw hash ID—a big ugly string of letters and digits, such as [`b34789c0b0d3b137f0bb516b417bd8d75e0cb306`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b34789c0b0d3b137f0bb516b417bd8d75e0cb306).  That hash ID means *that* commit, and if you have a clone of the Git repository for Git, you either have that commit (part of the upcoming Git 2.27 release) or you don't—well, not yet.

We do not, however, normally refer to commits by these hash IDs.  They are too big and ugly and impossible to remember or retype.  We like to use *names:* branch names like `master`, tag names like `v2.26.0`,<sup>1</sup> or *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master`.

To make tags work right in all cases, we have to promise never to *change* the hash ID to which some tag refers.  Some modern software—specifically Go modules and Go's version cache—[relies on this](https://golang.org/ref/mod#versions) for smooth functioning (though you can clamp down on it more for security if/as necessary).

The thing about branch names, though—as compared to tag names—is that the commit hash ID we obtain by looking up a branch name normally *changes*.  The branch name is in fact defined, in Git, as storing the hash ID of the *last* commit that is to be considered part of the branch.

Commits are immutable, because their true name hash ID is a cryptographic checksum of their content.<sup>2</sup>  Meanwhile each commit contains the hash ID of each of its immediate predecessor or *parent* commits—usually just one, with merge commits usually having two.  These form commits into nodes within a directed acyclic graph, by making each commit act as both vertex, named by hash ID, and the connecting one-way edges or arcs, named as the parents.

This graph can be—and is—added to, just by *adding new commits* to the set-of-all-commits in the repository.  That is, we use `git checkout` or `git switch` to select some *branch name* as the *current branch* and select its last commit—the hash ID stored *in* the branch name—as the *current commit*.  Then we do our work as usual, and Git packages up a new snapshot and new set of metadata to make a new commit.  The new commit's parent is the current commit.<sup>3</sup>  Now that the new commit exists and is safely stored in the repository,<sup>4</sup> Git writes the new commit's new, unique hash ID into the current *branch name*, so that the branch automatically points to the (new) last commit.

This is how branches grow, one commit at a time, and it provides a "normal direction" for branch names to move:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

becomes:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I   <-- master
```

when we add new commit `I`, then becomes:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I <-J  <-- master
```

when we add commit `J`, and so on.

We cannot actually *remove* commits from this graph, but we *can* force any branch name to move *backwards*, as it were.  For instance, after adding commits `I` and `J`, we can "remove" them for most *practical* purposes by forcing the name `master` to hold the hash ID of commit `H` again:

```
             I--J   ???
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Since Git normally *finds* commits by using a name like `master` and then working backwards through the commit-to-commit parent links, which point backwards, Git can no longer *find* commit `J`, at least not by starting with the name `master`.  Eventually, our Git will toss commits `I-J` for real—not immediately, and there are hidden names by which we can find them, as we'll see, but *eventually*.

Your own Git's *remote-tracking* names, like `origin/master`, are your Git's memory of some other Git's branch names.  That is, when you first clone a repository, or use `git fetch` to update a clone, you have your Git call up some other Git, via a URL that Git saves under a name.  We call the name—in this case `origin`—a *remote* and we supply the name as shorthand for the URL:

```
git fetch origin
```

Our Git calls up their Git, gets from them a list of their branch names and last-commit-hash-IDs, and gets from them any commits they have, that we don't, that we need.  For instance, if we have, at this time:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

we can call up their Git and perhaps *their* `master` now points to new commit `J`:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master [in the Git at origin]
```

Our Git checks, notices we don't have a commit with hash ID `J`, and gets that commit from their Git.  That also brings in commit `I` because we always get everything we don't have,<sup>5</sup> and then updates our `origin/master`—our memory of *their* `master`.  So now we have, in our own local repository:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/master
```

At this point, their master is `2 ahead`—two commits ahead of—our `master`.  We can now take action to add these commits, `I-J`, to our own `master`.  We can have Git do that by sliding the *name* `master` "forward" to point to commit `J`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I--J   <-- master, origin/master
```

If we do this with `git merge`, Git calls this a *fast-forward merge*.  There is no actual merging involved: Git really just checks out commit `J` directly and updates the name `master` to point to commit `J`.  (There are other ways to fast-forward any branch name as well: if the commit *isn't* checked out, and that is *not* our current branch, the name simply "slides forward".)

But as we noted above, we can *force* a branch name to "move backwards" so as to "remove"—well, sort-of-remove—a commit.  Suppose someone does this on the *other Git*, after we've added `I-J` to our own `master`.  *Their* repository now has their `master` pointing to commit `H`.<sup>6</sup>  When we have our Git call up their Git—by running `git fetch origin`—we see that their `master` names commit `H`, not commit `J`.  They have no *new* commits for us, so our Git just updates our `origin/master` now, giving us this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- master
```

We are now `2 ahead` of them, as if *we* made commits `I-J`.

If we are allowed to `git push origin master` we can easily put these two commits back, just by running `git push origin master` now.  If their Git has truly discarded commits `I-J`, well, now they're back.  If not, they already have `I-J` and our `git push` just makes them fast-forward *their* name `master` to point to commit `J`.

Whoever "removed" commits `I-J` from the Git repository at `origin` had some reason they did it.  Was it intentional?  Was it a mistake?  We have no way to know—well, we have *one* way: **ask them!**  *They* know; we can only guess, so ask them.

We can, however, tell that this happened, *if* our Git had picked up `I-J` from them at some point and updated our own `origin/master` accordingly.  This is where those hidden names I mentioned come in.

---

<sup>1</sup>In the Git repository for Git, `v2.26.0` means commit `274b9cc25322d9ee79aa8e6d4e86f0ffe5ced925`, although the name actually resolves to a *tag object* hash ID, `adf6396efeb4e8c12fb07174b4074c4031b2c460`.  The whole point of the tag, though, is that we don't *need* to know any of this.  The simple, human-readable, comprehensible name `v2.26.0` suffices.

<sup>2</sup>This is true of all Git objects, actually—it's not specific to commit objects.  See also [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)

<sup>3</sup>If the new commit is a *merge* commit, its *first* parent is the current commit.  The remaining parents—which are what make it a merge commit; there is usually just one other commit here—can be the hash IDs of any existing commit, but each one *must* be the hash ID of *some* existing commit.

<sup>4</sup>Note that the work-tree is *not* in the repository—it's a separate entity that lives *next to* the repository, in a sense–and your files are *not* safe until committed.

<sup>5</sup>Except, that is, for what Git calls *shallow* clones.  Let's ignore them here.

<sup>6</sup>Their repository may or may not still actually hold commits `I-J`, depending on how quickly their Git gets around to discarding *unreachable* commits.  Reachability is a key concept here; for (much) more about this, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

---

#### Reflogs keep the previous values of names

Whenever our Git updates any of our names—`master` or `origin/master` or even a tag name—our Git will (optionally, but it is on by default for us) *save the old value of the name* in a log.  This log is the *reflog* for the given name.<sup>7</sup>  This means that our `origin/master`—our memory of where their `master` was, updated each time we run `git fetch`–keeps track of where their `master` *used to be* on a previous `git fetch`.

Suppose someone deliberately, or somehow accidentally, forces `origin`'s name `master` to move backwards—to go from commit `J` to commit `H` in the example above.  Suppose further that we ran a `git fetch` that captured that name pointing to commit `J` before, and now we run `git fetch` and the name points to `H`.  Our Git will forcibly update our `origin/master` in a non-fast-forward manner.<sup>8</sup>

We can now, after the fact, look that up in the reflog for `origin/master`:

```
$ git reflog origin/master
```

In my case, I can do that with my Git repository for Git, because the `pu` branch moves like this all the time:

```
$ git reflog origin/pu
dfeb8fbf42 (origin/pu) refs/remotes/origin/pu@{0}: fetch: forced-update
fc307aa377 refs/remotes/origin/pu@{1}: fetch: forced-update
5525884f08 refs/remotes/origin/pu@{2}: fetch: forced-update
...
```

The "forced update" part here means that they had some commits on their branch, which we were able to obtain and remember with our own remote-tracking name, but then they decided to shove those commits aside.  Our Git picked up their new `pu` name and updated our `origin/pu` accordingly.

---

<sup>7</sup>There is also a reflog for the special name `HEAD`, but it has no important function in this particular case because we cannot be "on" a remote-tracking name like `origin/master`.

<sup>8</sup>The `git fetch` command reports this in its output, though many people pay no attention to it.  You'll see three indicators in each line: a leading plus sign, three dots instead of two, and the words "forced update" appended:

```
   b34789c0b0..07d8ea56f2  master     -> origin/master
   232c24e857..5cccb0e1a8  next       -> origin/next
 + fc307aa377...dfeb8fbf42 pu         -> origin/pu  (forced update)
   139372b246..6b33381979  todo       -> origin/todo
```

Note how the `pu` branch has moved in a non-fast-forward manner, and `git fetch` has told us that three times.