# How to properly clone and switch to existing branch of fork

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I had been working on a branch of a fork associated with a merge request and I was stupid enough to accidentally delete my local git folder. Luckily, all code changes had already been pushed, but I can't figure out how to properly recreate the state of the folder at the time of deletion.

I had originally cloned a project using

```
git clone [origin_URL]
```

after which I made some local changes, created a fork on GitLab, added it using

```
git remote add fork [fork_URL]
```

then created a branch, pushed to my fork

```
git checkout -b new_feature
git add [files]
git commit -m [message]
git push fork new_feature
```

and created a merge request from `my_user_name/project:new_feature` into `other_user_name/project:master`. The merge request had seen some discussion and some more commits had been made and I was ready to implement the finishing touches before getting on with other work but that was before I realized I had accidentally deleted my local folder.

*“Not a big deal,”* I thought, *“it's all on GitLab anyway, I'll just have to get back to where I was”* but now I've spent the last 2 hours trying to figure out the proper way of cloning the repository and configuring the branches the right way, all to no avail. I have been reading through a couple of other Git questions on SO found on Google and the SO search, none of which seemed to provide an answer to this particular problem so I think this shouldn't be a duplicate but of course I can't be too sure with the sheer amount of Git questions on here.

I've tried a couple of variants of `git clone`, cloning the original repository first and using `git remote add fork`, cloning the fork, renaming it as such and adding the original repository as `origin`, cloning with `--branch`… I've tried getting back onto the branch I was working on before using `git checkout` but all attempts so far ended up with a “detached head” state I don't know how to get out of or Git forcing me to create a new branch when all I want to do is get back onto the branch I was working on. I tried using `git switch fork/my_feature` but got

```
fatal: a branch is expected, got remote branch 'fork/my_feature'
```

Since the request had been opened, there had been some (unrelated) activity on the master branch, so the source branch is some commits behind the target branch which means I'll need to rebase the source branch onto the target branch – I don't know enough about Git to know if this is relevant to the problem, so I thought I'd mention it. Any insight from someone experienced enough with Git to tell me why the previous approaches failed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You're on the right track.  You just need to use `git switch -c my_feature --track fork/my_feature`.  The reason why is at least a little bit messy, and there may be several other ways to deal with this, depending on your personal tastes, but the above should Just Work.

If you just want to *view* that commit, you can tell `git switch` that it is OK to use the detached-HEAD mode:

```
git switch --detach fork/my_feature
```

In general it's not a good idea to do *new work* like this though, as it's too easy to lose track of it.

#### Long

> *“Not a big deal,”* I thought, *“it's all on GitLab anyway, I'll just have to get back to where I was”*

This is right—that's the point of distributed development, after all: there's *more than one copy* of the repository.  The tricky part is getting back to where you were, though.  It's not *hard*, but it **is** *tricky*, with the difference being that people can use Git without understanding what's really going on.  That's because we (humans, rather than computers) like to think of Git as being about files and branches, and it's not.  Git is all about *commits*.

The problem is, commits are identified, in Git, by hash IDs: big ugly random-looking strings of letters and digits, such as [`d2ecc46c0981fb829fdfb204604ed0a2798cbe07`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2ecc46c0981fb829fdfb204604ed0a2798cbe07).  Every commit gets one of these, and no commit ever shares it with any other commit.<sup>1</sup>  What this means is that these hsah IDs *are* the commits, in a very real sense.  You just present the hash ID to your Git, and it fishes out the commit, if it has it; or if it does not have it, you know that you need to copy that commit from whichever Git or Gits *do* have it.

So even though these are what Git uses, these hash IDs are no good for humans and are not how *we* interact with Git.  They are also quite useless for doing any *new* work: their only purpose is to locate and extract *existing* work.  Remember that every commit represents a snapshot, frozen in time.  That is, each commit stores *all* of your files.  Every commit has a complete copy of every file.  These copies are de-duplicated, which is a good thing.  They are then stored in a frozen, compressed form that only Git itself can read and use.  Overall, this is good because it means that each repository is (normally) relatively small: the repository does not grow immensely fat as we make more commits, because each commit really just keeps re-using the previous files.

But this does mean that we literally *cannot* work on a commit.  We have to have Git *extract* that commit.  That copies the committed files to a form we *can* use.  This is what `git switch`, and to a lesser extent, `git restore`, are about.  Note that in Git versions predating 2.23, these are combined into one big `git checkout` command.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is generally even true across entirely-independent repositories.  The commit hash ID quoted above is in the Git repository for Git itself, so that if you have a clone of that repository and it is reasonably up to date, you will have that commit in your clone of that repository.  That hash ID won't be in your GitLab repository, though.  So these hash IDs are universally unique.

They don't have to be—they just have to be unique within the set of repositories that you'll connect to each other via `git remote add` and the like—but in general, they are.  The chance of any two individual hash IDs colliding accidentally is just one in 2<sup>160</sup>.  However, the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) means that the chance rises very fast as the number of commits increases, to the point where it's statistically significant if you have more than a few trillion commits or so.  It's also possible for a malicious actor to craft a collision on purpose, though [Git is accidentally immune to some known collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452).  In any case, SHA-1 is no longer considered cryptographically secure, so Git may eventually move to a 256-bit SHA.

---

#### Names

While Git is all about *commits*, we humans like to think in terms of *branches*.  There is a big problem with this word *branch:* we humans use it ambiguously.  Sometimes, when we say *branch B*, we mean *one commit, found by our name B*.  Sometimes, when we say *branch B*, we mean *every commit up to and including the **last** commit on a series of commits whose last commit is found using our name B*.  Sometimes we mean *the name B itself*, and sometimes we mean *a specific subset of the general names that Git provides*.

(See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

Git has multiple different kinds of names.  These include *branch names* like `master` or `feature/tall`, *tag names* like `v1.0` and `v2.17.2`; and *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master` or `fork/my_feature`.  All of these names are treated pretty similarly, and wind up being handled as a general form that Git calls *refs* or *references*.

To keep track of each reference and what kind of name it is, Git's refs are stored in [*name spaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).  The `refs/heads/` namespace holds all of our branch names, so `master` is actually just a short way to spell `refs/heads/master`.  Tag names are in `refs/tags`: `v1.0` is just short for `refs/tags/v1.0`.

Remote-tracking names are the most complicated of these, but follow exactly the same pattern `origin/master` is `refs/remotes/origin/master` and `work/my_feature` is `refs/remotes/work/my_feature`.  The slightly tricky part is that `refs/remotes/` itself is split into `refs/remotes/origin/*` and `refs/remotes/work/*`.  This comes about because of the *remote names* `origin` and `work`.  We'll get back to this later.

Each of these names just stores one hash ID.  That's all it has to do, so that is all that Git does with it:<sup>2</sup> the name `master` means some commit hash ID, and the name `work/my_feature` also means some commit hash ID—probably a different one, but two different names *can* mean the same hash ID.  *Branch* names, however, have one very special feature.

When we use `git switch` to get "on a branch" like `master` or `develop`, that branch name becomes the *current branch*.  Git extracts the right commit for us: Git looks up the hash ID, in Git's name-to-hash-ID table, and copies out the commit's frozen files, into a work area with ordinary files.  This allows us to view and edit the files.  At the same time, though, Git *stores* the *name* into the special Git ref `HEAD`, so that `git status`, for instance, will now say `on branch master` or `on branch develop`.

Being "on a branch" gives us a happy property.  Describing this property correctly requires that we take a second look at the anatomy of a commit.

---

<sup>2</sup>Branch names have other functions as well, but they're handled by storing the branch name and its other data in your `.git/config` file, not by the name-to-hash-ID mapping part that is part of every Git reference.

---

#### Commits store data and metadata, and contain hash IDs

We said above that each commit stores a full snapshot of all files, and that's still true.  That's the main bulk of the data of a commit: a saved file-tree, in which all of the files are in the special, read-only, Git-only, frozen and compressed format.  We also said that each commit has a unique hash ID, and that is also true.  What we left out is that each commit contains some *metadata:* some information about the commit itself.

We see some or most of this metadata when we run `git log`, e.g.:

```
$ git log --format=fuller -1 | sed 's/@/ /'
commit d2ecc46c0981fb829fdfb204604ed0a2798cbe07
Author:     Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
AuthorDate: Sun May 24 18:13:53 2020 -0700
Commit:     Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
CommitDate: Sun May 24 19:39:40 2020 -0700

    Hopefully final batch before 2.27-rc2

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

(I used `--format=fuller` here to show more than we usually see).  In fact, this is just a cleaned-up version of the raw data that's inside the commit, which we can view directly:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | sed 's/@/ /'
tree e83aacc68752967a710fc32e3cf49356959545eb
parent ea7aa4f612ef33ecfb7fd6d488d949da3a51a377
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1590369233 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1590374380 -0700

Hopefully final batch before 2.27-rc2

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

The `tree` line represents the saved snapshot.  The `author` and `committer` lines give the name of the person who made the commit: the author is whoever wrote it, and the committer is the person who added it to the Git repository.<sup>3</sup>  The `parent` line gives the raw hash ID of the commit that comes *before* this commit.

Every commit has some of these `parent` lines.  In fact, if we look at the commit that comes before the `HEAD` one:

```
$ git cat-file -p ea7aa4f612ef33ecfb7fd6d488d949da3a51a377 | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 0342252fde5f2b5721299d321d57ce12542b2957
parent d55a4ae71d515e788e5afb355a20c4b262049cac
parent 1eb73712360744b552f30a6961c03d05bc44bef2
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1590374380 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1590374380 -0700

Merge branch 'dd/t5703-grep-a-fix'

Update an unconditional use of "grep -a" with a perl script in a test.

* dd/t5703-grep-a-fix:
  t5703: replace "grep -a" usage by perl
```

we see that it has *two* `parent` lines.  That marks this commit as a *merge commit*, combining two different series of commits—two lines of work.

---

<sup>3</sup>This specific split allows for emailed patches, which were much more important in the 2005ish time frame, when Linus Torvalds first wrote Git: see [commit `e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290).

---

#### These interconnections form backwards-looking chains

When a name like `master` contains a hash ID like `d2ecc46c...`, or a commit like `d2ecc46c...` or `ea7aa4f6...` contains the hash ID of some earlier commit, we say that that name, or that commit, *points to* the target.  So the name `master` *points to* `d2ecc46c...`, which in turn points to `ea7aa4f6...`.  We can draw this:

```
... <-ea7aa4f6 <-d2ecc46c   <--master
```

In fact `ea7aa4f6` points back to two different commits:

```
...--d55a4ae7--ea7aa4f6--d2ecc46c   <-- master
              /
 ...--1eb73712
```

In general, if we let round dots `o` or uppercase letters stand in for the random-looking and utterly forgettable hash IDs, we get more useful pictures:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master
```

or:

```
  ...--D--G--H   <-- master
         /
...--E--F
```

which is a more digestable, and hence easier-for-humans, way to think about branches and branch names.  **The key takeaways here are that the branch name points to the *last* commit in the branch, and that commit points back to the earlier commits that are also contained in the branch.**  So given the drawing above, all commits up through `H` are on `master`.  At some point there was a name, `dd/t5703-grep-a-fix`, pointing to commit `F`:

```
  ...--D--G--H   <-- master
         /
...--E--F   <-- dd/t5703-grep-a-fix
```

That name is not needed any more because Git *finds* commits by starting with some name—such as `master`—and finding the *last* commit, then using that to work backwards.  From commit `H`, Git works back to `G`; from `G`, Git works back to both `D` *and* `F`; so Git can find `F` without a separate name for it.

**For these purposes, any name is as good as any other.**  A branch name like `master`, or a tag name like `v2.17.2`, or a remote-tracking name like `dd/t5703-grep-a-fix` (I'm guessing that this was a remote-tracking name), all just serve to locate one specific commit, and that's all we need *for these purposes*.

#### The special feature of a branch name

What makes a *branch* name special is that we can get "on" the branch, using `git switch` or, in Git predating 2.23, `git checkout`.  We cannot get "on" a tag or remote-tracking name: instead, we get a *detached HEAD* (`git checkout`) or a complaint (`git switch`):<sup>4</sup>

> ```
> fatal: a branch is expected, got remote branch 'fork/my_feature'
> ```

But we *can* get on a branch:

```
git checkout master
```

after which we can draw our graph like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

If we now do some work and make a *new* commit, here's what happens:

1. *do some work:* we modify files in our work-tree, then run `git add` to copy the updated files back into Git's index.
2. `git commit`: Git creates a new commit, which gets a new and unique hash ID.  We'll call this commit `I`, using the next letter after `H`.

   - Git collects the appropriate metadata: user name, email, log message, current date-and-time, and so forth.  Included in that metadata is the raw hash ID of commit `H`, which is the *current commit* because `master` is the current *branch name* because `HEAD` is attached to `master`.  So the parent for new commit `I` will be `H`.
   - Git freezes, for all time, all the files that are in its index (aka the *staging area*).  We won't go into details here, but note that the index started out matching commit `H`.
   - Git writes out the new commit, which acquires its hash ID at this time.  The hash ID is based on both the data and all the metadata, including the exact second at which you ran `git commit`.  It *looks* random, but it's simply a checksum of all of this data.
   - Last, Git does the special trick.  Before I describe it, let's look at the graph.

Since new commit `I`'s parent is existing commit `H`, commit `I` points back to `H`:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

But what about the *name* `master`, which used to contain `H`'s hash ID?  Well, because `HEAD` is attached to `master`, Git writes `I`'s hash ID into the *name* `master`.  So now `master` points to `I`, not `H`:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

No *existing commit* has changed at all.  It's physically impossible to change any part of any existing commit, because the actual hash ID for `H` is the checksum of all the bytes *in* commit `H`.  Those are not allowed to change!  If we take `H` out of the repository, fiddle with some bytes, and put the result back, that's just a *different commit* `H'` with a different hash ID.  Commit `H` will still be there.  Commit `I` will point to commit `H`, because now that commit `I` exists, no part of *it* can be changed either.

So, the special feature of being "on a branch" is that as we *make new commits*, Git *automatically updates the branch name*.  The name that gets updated is the name we have `HEAD` attached-to.  We can make extra names:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, develop
```

We pick one of these names and attach `HEAD` to it:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), develop
```

Then we make a new commit and get:

```
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop
```

If we make another commit, that continues to extend the branch:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop
```

No *existing commit* changes, and no other *branch name* moves.  Only the branch name we're "on"—as in `git status` says `on branch master`—moves.

If we now switch to `develop`, we get commit `H` back out in our work area (and in Git's index / staging-area):

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

and now, if we make two new commits, they make the *name* `develop` move accordingly:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

and now we have our familiar branch-y structures.  Note that commits up through and including `H` are on *both branches*.  Commits `I-J` are currently only on `master`, and `K-L` are currently only on `develop`.  The name `HEAD` is attached to the name `develop`, telling us that the current *branch name* is `develop` and the current *commit* is commit `L`.

---

<sup>4</sup>You can see here that Git called this a *remote branch* rather than my preferred term, *remote-tracking name*.  Given how badly overloaded the word *branch* is in Git, I think *remote-tracking name* is a better phrase to describe the name `fork/my_feature`.  Both mean the same thing here though.

---

#### remotes, `git fetch`, and remote-tracking names

When we have two or more repositories that are supposed to hold the same commits, we need to have them *talk to each other*.  In general, to achieve this, we give each "other Git" a name.  This name is a *remote*.

Most of the time, we get our first and only remote automatically.  We make our own local Git repository, not by running `git init`, but by running `git clone`:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/project/repo.git
```

for instance.  The `git clone` command is actually just a fancy wrapper that runs six commands for us:

1. `mkdir`, to create a new empty directory, plus an internal `chdir` into the new directory for each of the subsequent commands;
2. `git init`, to create a repository within this empty directory;
3. `git remote add origin url`, to create the remote name `origin` and use that to store the *`url`*;
4. `git config` if / as needed (mostly if we specify particular configuration items with our `git clone` command);
5. `git fetch origin`; and finally
6. `git switch -c master --track origin/master`, or something very similar (see below).

When this all finishes, we are left with a non-bare repository—a repository that has an associated work-tree, where we can do our work—that has the `master` branch checked out into its work-tree,<sup>5</sup> which is at the top level of the new directory.  The repository proper is the `.git` sub-directory and all of its files.<sup>6</sup>

The fact that we have a *remote* named `origin` is where our `origin/*` *remote-tracking names* come from.  Step 5 above is for our Git to run `git fetch origin`.  This has our Git call up their Git, using the URL saved in step 3.  Their Git then lists out, for our Git, all of their branch and other names, and the corresponding commit hash IDs.  Our Git mostly throws away the non-branch names, except for tags, which are handled in a complicated way that we won't cover properly here.  Our Git takes the branch names and *renames* them.  Their `master` becomes our `origin/master`, for instance.<sup>7</sup>

The full name of each of these renamed branch-names is a remote-tracking name, i.e., is in that remote-tracking name-space we mentioned earlier: their `refs/heads/master`—a branch name—becomes our `refs/remotes/origin/master`: a remote-tracking names.  For every one of their `refs/heads/*` names, we get a `refs/remotes/origin/*` name.

The hash IDs their branch names hold become the hash IDs that our remote-tracking names hold.  For our remote-tracking names to hold these hash IDs, though, we *must first obtain the commits*.  So before we actually use these renamed names, our Git tells their Git: *Please send over those commits, and also all their ancestors.*

The result is that we get every commit that they have, except perhaps for some *unreachable* commits, or commits that are only reachable from a non-branch name.<sup>8</sup>  So after our:

```
git clone <url>
```

we have a new repository that has every commit they have—or almost every commit—*and* has changed their *branch* names into our *remote-tracking names*.  The last step, step 6 above, has created in *our* Git repository, *our* one and only branch, named `master`.

We can at any later time run:

```
git fetch origin
```

and our Git will call up their Git and have them list out all their names, just as before.  Just as before, we'll find any commits from these names that we want, but do not yet have, and get those commits from their Git.  Then we'll adjust our *remote-tracking names*, `origin/*`, to match their *branch* names.  **The end result of this is that `git fetch origin` obtains `origin`'s new commits and updates our memory of their branch names.  It does not touch any of *our* branch names at all.**

We can use:

```
git remote add fork <url>
```

to add a *new* remote named `fork` that stores the given URL.  Having done that, we then run:

```
git fetch fork
```

to have our Git call up their Git, have them list out their *branch* (and other) names, and have our Git rename those names to our remote-tracking `fork/*` names.  We will get from them any commits that they have, that we don't, that we need to update our `fork/*` names, and then update our `fork/*` names to remember their branch names.

---

<sup>5</sup>We still have to do our own `cd` into the directory because of the way current-working-directory works in Linux.  In theory, on some OSes, `git clone` could adjust the shell's working directory, but given that people don't expect it to do that, it doesn't do that—it just runs each of its other five commands in the new directory.

<sup>6</sup>You can, if you really want, later move the repository proper somewhere else.  If you do your own commands instead of having `git clone` do them for you, you can set this up initially.  Nobody really works this way, as far as I know, and the feature that allows it is not particularly useful for ordinary work—it's meant for internal use, to handle submodules in the modern Git way, as opposed to the old Git 1.7 style.

<sup>7</sup>You can change all of this.  For instance, using `git clone --mirror` makes a *bare* clone—one with no work-tree, which means you can't do any work in it—in which our Git slavishly copies all of their names.  The underlying mechanism here is very flexible, but in practice, it's mostly used to handle three particularly interesting special cases.  The only one we're covering here is the normal everyday full-clone-with-work-tree case.

<sup>8</sup>An *unreachable commit* is one that cannot be found by starting with a name and working backwards through the parent links.  A commit that is reachable by some funky GitHub-specific name, such as `refs/pull/123/head`, might also not come over.  We can, by configuring the fancy mechanisms mentioned in footnote 7, arrange to bring over pull-request commits too, though.

---

#### Their branch names are not our branch names

While this is already covered above, it's worth emphasizing it again.  Now that we have two remotes, `origin` and `fork`, we have two sets of remote-tracking names.  We have an `origin/master` and a `fork/master`, provided that both `origin` and `fork` have branches named `master`.

Their `master`s may have different final commits—and different earlier commits too—than our `master`.  Of course, if we just now ran `git clone origin`, it is likely that our `master` matches their `origin/master`: that both point to commit `H`, for instance.  It's `fork/master` that is more likely to be different from these two.

In any case, though, if we want to have other branch names in *our* Git repository, we can now create them.  Our branch names are *ours*.  We can do whatever we like with them, creating and deleting them whenever we want.  The only constraint on our branch names is that each branch name must point to some actual, existing, valid commit hash ID in *our* repository.  At the moment, we have the commits we got from the other two repositories, so we can make any branch name we like, pointing to any of these commits.

#### "Do What I Mean" mode

The `git switch` command takes a branch name:

```
git switch master
```

Given that the name `master` already exists, this means *select the name `master` and the commit to which the name `master` points*.  Git will try to attach `HEAD` to that name, and extract that commit's frozen snapshot into our work-tree.

But you can give `git switch` the name of a branch that does not exist yet!

Suppose that `origin/develop` exists, and suppose further that `fork/develop` *does not* exist, or that we have not done `git remote add fork ...`.  That is, we have something like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
      \
       I   <-- origin/develop
```

Then:

```
git switch develop
```

*would* fail, because we don't have a `develop`—but before it fails, Git first checks: *Do I have exactly one remote-tracking name that indicates that the other Git has a `develop`?*  In this case, because there is an `origin/develop` and no `fork/develop`, that's the case: there is exactly one other `develop`.

Our Git then says: *Aha, you mean you want me to **create** `develop` using the commit identified by `origin/develop`.*  So our Git does that—it creates the name `develop`, pointing to commit `I`, and switches to it:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
      \
       I   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

This "do what I mean" mode is optional, and also has some fancier features, but it defaults to "on" and behaves as described above.  It basically turns the `git switch` you gave—`git switch develop`—into:

```
git switch -c develop origin/develop
```

which is an explicit request: *check out the commit identified by the name `origin/develop`* (in this case commit `I`) *and at the same time, create a new branch name `develop` pointing to this commit*.

In your case, you have something more complicated.  For instance, maybe you have:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
      \
       I   <-- origin/my_feature, fork/my_feature
```

If you now run:

```
git switch my_feature
```

your Git will complain, because there are *two* names it could have used to create `my_feature`.

Note that in this case, either name would have worked fine—as far as what I'm showing, anyway.  But `git switch`, or the older `git checkout`, won't do what you want here, simply because there is more than one matching name.<sup>9</sup>  So an explicit `git checkout -c name --track remote-tracking-name` is usually the way to go.

---

<sup>9</sup>There is a configuration setting you can change to adjust this, but this answer is already very long, so I won't cover that here either.

---

#### Further reading

The verb *track* in Git is badly overloaded.  The remote-tracking names already use this verb, in that when you run `git fetch`, your Git updates them from their Git's branch names.  The `git switch -c name --track remote/name` uses the verb in another way, which we have not covered here.

Independent of both of these, files in your work-tree can be either *tracked* or *untracked*.  A *tracked file* is simply one that is in Git's index right now.  We have not covered Git's index properly either, but it's a very important construct and it's good to know about it.

You can extract any file, or an entire directory-tree, from any commit.  In Git 2.23 or later, use `git restore` to do this.  In older version of Git, this function is jammed into `git checkout` too.

#### Conclusions

The things to keep in mind here are:

- Git is distributed.  There are many copies of some repositories, holding commits.  The commits hold files, but the unit at which we interact with Git is whole commits: we either have them, or don't.
- These repository copies mostly contain the same commits.  The commits are literally shared, by copying, and are found by their hash IDs.  No commit can ever change, not one bit, once it's created, so it's safe to just use your copy, if you have a copy.  If you don't have a copy, you just get one, by its hash ID, from anyone who has one: they're all the same.  Not only that, but the cryptography aspect of the hash-ID-as-checksum tells you that you have the *right* commit content: that no one has messed with it.
- These repositories *do not* share their branch names.  At most, sometimes someone comes along and makes sure that repository copy C1's branch name B matches that in repository copy C2.  If people are diligent about this, the branch names *seem* to stay in sync, but that's just because people were diligent about synchronizing these independent names.
- Your Git will remember the URL for some other Git under a *remote:* a short name like `origin` or `fork` or `upstream` or whatever you like.
- Your own Git will remember another Git's branch names as your *remote-tracking* names.  Running `git fetch` to that other Git, by its remote name, will pick up new commits (but not re-obtain old ones, so it goes fast) and update your Git's memory of their Git's branch names.
- To do *new* work, you'll want to create or update your own branch names.
- Do remember that until you use `git push` to *send* new commits to other Git repositories, they won't have your own commits.  Only your own Git repository will have these.  If you ask those other Git repositories for those hash IDs, they'll just say: *I don't have that hash ID.*