# How do I keep a local version and commit changes on Git without pushing upstream?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone, git-history

I am a student so I am a newbie. I have cloned a repo from the place I am interning at and want to set up my own development branch to use as a sandbox for myself. I want to be able to commit changes and switch back and forth between them but I do not want to push my branch upstream.

I have created a new branch, committed my changes so far. But when I try to push' Git wants me to send it upstream. How do I keep all this for myself and NOT push it to a remote location? Do I have everything set locally already? If so then how I can see the history of commits and switch between them?

Comment: "But when I try to push' Git wants me to send it upstream" ...because this is what you asked git. What do you think "pushing" is achieving that you need to do, apart from sending it upstream?

Comment: I guess I want to know the difference? If I dont push do the commit save? And how can I switch back and forth between them?

Comment: They save on your machine, but you need to push if you want the place youʼre interning to ever be able to actually use your code.

Comment: @dgozen About your 3 questions : 1) difference between what and what? 2) Yes, the commit "saves" even if you don't push. 3) Switch back and forth between what? Branches?

Comment: @RomainValeri I mean to switch back and forth between different commits. That is why I was wondering if I needed to push to commits to save them. Can all this be done locally with out pushing?

Comment: @dgozen Yes. You can do everything you want offline in git, except for fetch and push.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you really need here is a good Git tutorial, but in place of that, let's try this:

- Git is all about commits.  Git newbies (and even people with some experience with it) often think it's about files, or branches, but it's really not: it's about *commits*.
- Each Git repository is a complete collection of commits.  That is, if you have the *last* commit, you have all the *earlier* commits too.<sup>1</sup>
- Commits are numbered, but the numbers aren't simple counting numbers: they don't go commit #1, #2, #3, and so on.  Instead, each commit has a big ugly *hash ID* number, expressed as, e.g., [`675a4aaf3b226c0089108221b96559e0baae5de9`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/675a4aaf3b226c0089108221b96559e0baae5de9).  This number is unique across *every* repository copy, so either you have a commit, or you don't; when you make a new commit, it gets a new, unique number that no other commit has ever had.<sup>2</sup>  In this way, it's possible to connect two Gits: they just hand each other commit numbers, rather than entire commits, and the other Git can easily check: *do I have this commit?* by just looking up the number.
- Each commit contains a complete snapshot of every file that Git knows about.  Commits don't contain changes, despite the fact that when you *show* a commit, Git *shows* changes.
- The way the above works is that each commit also contains some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit, a date-and-time-stamp, and so on; but it also includes the raw hash ID—the commit number—of the commit that comes *right before* this commit.  Git calls this the *parent* of the commit.
- Once Git makes a commit, nothing in it can ever be changed, and commits are (mostly) permanent.<sup>3</sup>

Since each commit holds the hash ID of the *previous* (parent) commit, we can, if we like, draw the commits in a tiny 3-commit repository like this:

```
 A <-B <-C
```

Here `A` stands in for the hash ID of the first commit, `B` for the second, and `C` for the third.  The *last* commit is commit `C` and is the one we'd normally use.  Since `C` holds the hash ID of earlier commit `B`, though, Git can easily read both commits, and compare the two snapshots.  Whatever is *different*, that's what Git will show you—along with, of course, the metadata showing who made commit `C` and so on.

This also means that, starting with the last commit, Git can work *backwards* all the way to the first commit.  That is, Git starts with the last commit as the commit to show.  Then Git shows it, then Git moves to its parent, and shows that, and so on.  What makes the first commit "first", in Git's eyes, is that it just doesn't have a parent: `A` has no parent, so Git can now stop walking backwards through this chain.

---

<sup>1</sup>A so-called *shallow clone* deliberately weakens this guarantee, but as long as you are not using `git clone --depth number` or similar, you won't have a shallow clone and won't need to worry about this.

<sup>2</sup>The [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) tells us that this scheme must eventually fail.  The reason commit hash IDs are so big is to make the "eventually" take long enough that it doesn't matter.  In practice, collisions don't occur, but someone could theoretically hand-craft one.  Also, two Git repositories that never actually meet each other could safely have hash collisions.  For more about this see [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)

<sup>3</sup>This "unchangeable" property is actually true of all of Git's internal objects, all of which get these hash IDs, as the hash ID is simply a cryptographic checksum of the internal object contents.  If you take one of these objects out of Git's database, make some changes to it, and put it back, the altered object gets a *new hash ID*.  The old object is still there, with its old content.  So even Git can't *change* an object: if we want to replace a commit, e.g., with `git commit --amend`, what we get is not really a *changed* commit, but rather a *new* one.  The old one is still in the repository!

The "mostly" part in "mostly permanent" is because a commit or other internal object that *can't* be found by *any* name—which `git fsck` calls *dangling* or *unreachable*—will eventually be cleaned up by Git's *garbage collector*, `git gc`.  We won't get into any detail here for length reasons, but `git commit --amend` typically results in the old (bad and now replaced) commit being garbage collected later.

---

#### Branches

What's missing here is an easy way for Git to *find* the raw hash ID of that last commit.  This is where branch names come in.  A branch name like `master` simply holds that last-commit hash ID:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

Note that I've replaced the internal arrows between the commits with connecting lines: since commits can't change, that's OK to do, as long as we remember that Git can't go *forwards* easily, but only backwards.  That is, `A` has no idea what the hash ID for `B` is, even though `B` has hardwired in it `A`'s hash ID.  But we'll keep the arrows coming out of branch names, for a good reason: these names (or arrows) *move*.

If we now make a new branch name such as `develop`, the default is to have this new branch name *also* point to the current commit `C`, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, master
```

Now we need one more thing: a way to remember *which name we are using*.  This is where the special name `HEAD` comes in.  The name `HEAD` is normally *attached to* one of the branch names:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, master (HEAD)
```

This indicates that even though there are two names for commit `C`—and all three commits are on both branches—the name we're *using* is `master`.

The `git checkout` or (since Git 2.23) `git switch` command is how you change which name `HEAD` is attached to.  So if we `git checkout develop` or `git switch develop`, we get this:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop (HEAD), master
```

We're still *using* commit `C`; we've just changed the way we have Git find commit `C`.  Instead of using the name `master` to find it, Git uses the name `develop` to find it.

Suppose we now make a new commit `D`.  Without getting into *how*, we'll just assume we've done it.  Git has assigned this new commit a new unique hash ID, and new commit `D` points back to existing commit `C` as its parent—because we were "on" `C` when we made `D`.  So let's draw that part:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D
```

The last step of `git commit` is just a little tricky: Git writes the new commit's hash ID into *whichever branch name `HEAD` is attached to*.  So the diagram is now:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

#### `git log` normally starts with `HEAD` and works backwards

Suppose we run `git log` now.  Git will:

- show commit `D` (and with `-p`, show what's *different* in `D` as compared to its parent `C`); then
- move one step back to `C` and show that; then
- move one step back to `B` and show that

and so on.  Git started with commit `D` because the name `HEAD` is attached to the name `develop` and the branch name `develop` locates commit `D`.

Suppose we run `git checkout master` or `git switch master`, to get this:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

and run `git log` again.  This time `HEAD` is attached to `master`, and `master` points to commit `C`, so `git log` will show `C`, then move back one step to `B` and show that, and so on.  Commit `D` seems to have disappeared!  But it hasn't: it's right there, findable using the name `develop`.

Hence, this is what branch names do for us: each branch name finds the *last* commit that is "on" that branch.  Earlier commits are also on that branch, even if they're on some other branch or branches.  Many commits are on many branches, and in a typical repository, the very first commit is on *every* branch.<sup>4</sup>

You can even have commits that aren't on any branch at all.<sup>5</sup>  Git has something called *detached HEAD* mode in which you make such commits, but normally you wouldn't do any real work in this mode.  You will be in this detached HEAD mode during a `git rebase` that requires resolving conflicts, but we won't cover that here either.

---

<sup>4</sup>You can make more than one "first commit" in a repository.  Git calls these parentless commits *root commits*, and if you have more than one, you can have chains of commits that are independent of each other.  This isn't particularly useful but it's straightforward and simple, so Git supports it.

<sup>5</sup>For instance, `git stash` makes such commits.  Git finds these commits using names that aren't *branch* names.  We won't go into any detail about those here though.

---

#### Git's index and your work-tree, or, things to know about making new commits

Earlier, I skipped right over the "how" part of making new commit `D`, but it's time to talk about this.  First, though, let's take a somewhat closer look at the snapshot in a commit.

We covered the fact that the committed files—the files in the snapshot that Git saves in each commit—are read-only.  They literally *cannot* be changed.  They are also stored in a compressed and de-duplicated format that only Git can read.<sup>6</sup>  The de-duplication takes care of the fact that most commits mostly just re-use files from some earlier commit.  If `README.md` is not changed, there's no need to store a *new* copy: each commit can just keep re-using the previous one.

What this means, though, is that the files inside a Git commit are *not* the files you will see and work on.  The files you will work on are in the computer's ordinary everyday format, and are writable as well as readable.  These files are contained in your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  When you check out some particular commit—by choosing a branch name, which points to the last commit that is on that branch—Git will populate your work-tree with the files from that commit.

This means that there are, in effect, two copies of each file from the *current commit:*

- There is one in the commit itself, which is read-only and Git-only, in a frozen, Git-ified form that I like to call *freeze-dried*.
- There is one in your work-tree, which you can see and work with/on.

Many version control systems use this same pattern, with just these two copies of each file, but Git actually goes further.  There is a *third* copy<sup>7</sup> of each file in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  This third copy is in the freeze-dried *format*, ready to go into the *next* commit, but unlike the committed copy, you can replace it any time, or even remove it entirely.

Hence, when you check out a commit, Git really fills both *its index* (with the freeze-dried files) and *your work-tree* (with usable copies).  When you go to make a new commit, Git doesn't actually look at your work-tree at all.  Git just makes the new commit by packaging up the already-freeze-dried *index* copies of each file.

This leads to a nice, simple description of Git's index: **The index holds your proposed *next* commit.**  This description is actually a little *too* simple, as the index has other roles.  In particular, it takes on an expanded role when resolving merge conflicts.  We won't get into that part here though.  The simple description works well enough to get started with Git.

What this means is that after you edit a work-tree file, you need to tell Git to copy that work-tree copy back into its index.  The `git add` command does exactly that: it tells Git *make the index copy of this file, or all of these files, match the work-tree copy*.  Git will compress and de-duplicate the work-tree copy at this time, well in advance of the next `git commit`.  That makes `git commit`'s job a lot easier: it doesn't have to look at your work-tree at all.<sup>8</sup>

Anyway, the thing to keep in mind here is that there are, at all times, *three* copies of each "active" file, in Git:

- the frozen-forever committed `HEAD` copy;
- the frozen-*format* but replaceable *index / staging area* copy; and
- your work-tree copy.

Git builds new commits, not from your work-tree copy, but from the index copy of each file.  The index therefore holds all the files that Git knows about, at the time you run `git commit`, and the commit's snapshot is *whatever is in the index* at that time.

---

<sup>6</sup>There are multiple formats, called *loose objects* and *packed objects*, and loose objects are actually pretty easy to read directly.  It's the packed objects that are somewhat hard to read.  But in any case, Git reserves to itself the right to change formats any time in the future, so it's best to just let Git read them.

<sup>7</sup>Because this third copy is pre-de-duplicated, it's not really a *copy* at all.

<sup>8</sup>Note that `git commit` normally runs a quick `git status`, and `git status` *does* look at your work-tree, though.

---

#### What `git status` does

Before you run `git commit`, you should generally run `git status`:

- The status command starts by telling you the current branch name—that's the name that `git commit` will *change*, so that it points to the new commit—and often some other useful stuff that we'll skip over here.
- Next, `git status` tells you about files that are *staged for commit*.  What it's really done here, though, is to compare *all the files in `HEAD`* to *all the files in the index*.  When these two files are the same, `git status` says nothing at all.  When they're *different*, `git status` announces that this file is *staged for commit*.
- After the HEAD-vs-index comparison, `git status` tells you about files that are *not staged for commit*.  What it's really done here, though, is to compare *all the files in the index* to *all your files in your work-tree*.  When these are the same, `git status` says nothing at all.  When they're *different* `git status` announces that this file is *not staged for commit*.
- Last, `git status` will tell you about *untracked files*.  We'll leave this for another section.

The `git status` command is very useful.  Use it often!  It will show you what's in the index and what's in your work-tree, in a much more usable way than if you were to just look directly at them.  A *not-staged-for-commit* file can be `git add`-ed, so that the index copy matches the work-tree copy.  A *staged-for-commit* file is going to be different in the new commit than it is in the current commit.

#### Untracked files and `.gitignore`

Because your work-tree is *yours*, you can create files here that Git knows nothing about.  That is, a new file in your work-tree isn't *in* Git's index yet, as the index was filled, earlier, from the commit you selected.

Git calls such a file *untracked*.  That is, an untracked file is simple a file that exists in your work-tree, but is not in Git's index.  The `git status` command whines about these files, to remind you to `git add` them.  The `git add` command has an en-masse "add all files" mode, e.g., `git add .`, which will add all these untracked files by copying them into Git's index, so that they *will* be in the next commit.

Sometimes, though, there are work-tree files that you know should never be committed at all.  To make `git status` stop whining about them, and make `git add` *not* automatically *add* them, you can list the file's names or patterns in a `.gitignore` file.

*Listing a file here has no effect if the file is already in Git's index.*  That is, these files aren't really *ignored*.  Instead of `.gitignore`, this file might be better named `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-files-and-do-not-automatically-add-them-with-any-en-masse-git-add-command`, or something like that.  But that file name is ridiculous, so `.gitignore` it is.

If a file has gotten into Git's index, and it should not be there—should not be in new commits—you can remove the file from Git's index.  **Be careful** because the command to do this defaults to removing the file from *both* Git's index *and* your work-tree!  This command is `git rm` and you might, e.g., use `git rm database.db` to remove the accidentally-added database of important stuff ... but if you do that, Git removes *both copies*.

To remove only the index copy, either:

- move or copy the work-tree file so that Git can't get its grubby paws on it, or
- use `git rm --cached`, which tells Git *remove only the index copy*.

But be aware that if you put the file in some earlier commit, and remove it from future commits, Git will now have a different problem.  Every time you check out the *old* commit, Git will need to put the file into Git's index and your work-tree ... and every time you switch from that old commit to a newer commit that *doesn't* have the file, Git will need to remove the file from both Git's index and your work-tree.

It's best to never accidentally commit these files in the first place, so that you don't hit the above problem.  If you do hit it, remember that there's a copy of the file—maybe out of date, but a copy nonetheless—*in* that old commit; you can get *that* copy back any time, because committed files are read-only, and as permanent as the commits themselves.

#### What's left

We have not covered `git push` and `git fetch` at all.  We have not touched on `git merge`, except to mention that Git's index takes on an expanded role during merges.  We have not mentioned `git pull`, but I will say that `git pull` is really a convenience command: it means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command, usually `git merge`*.  I recommend learning the two commands separately and then running them separately, at least at first.  We have not covered `git rebase` either.  But this answer is plenty long enough already!

There is a lot to know about Git, but the above should get you started.  The most important points are:

- Each Git repository is complete (except for shallow clones).  You can do all your work in your local Git.  You only need to fetch and push when you want your Git to exchange commits with some other Git.
- Each Git repository has *its own* branch names.  The *names* just locate the *last* commit.  That's important (because how else will you find the last commit?), but the commits themselves are the real keys.
- Each commit holds a complete snapshot of "freeze-dried" (compressed and de-duplicated) files, as built from Git's index at the time you, or whoever, ran `git commit`.  Each commit also holds the hash ID of its *parent* commit (or, for merges—which we didn't cover here—parents, plural).
- You work on files that aren't actually *in* Git, in your work-tree.  Both your work-tree and Git's index are *temporary;* it's only the commits themselves that are (mostly) permanent, and it's only the commits themselves that get transferred from one Git to another.

So, perhaps too late , the short answer to:

> How do I keep all this for myself and NOT push it to a remote location? Do I have everything set locally already?

is: yes, everything is set already.  To view commits, use `git log`.  It defaults to starting from your *current* commit and working backwards, but with:

```
git log --branches
```

it will start from *all branch names* and work backwards.  This adds a bunch of complexity: `git log` can only show *one commit at a time* and there may now be more than one commit to show at a time.  It's also worth experimenting with:

```
git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

The `--all` flag tells Git to use *all references* (all branch names, tag names, and other names that we haven't covered here).  The `--decorate` option makes Git show which names point to which commits.  The `--oneline` option makes Git show each commit in a one-line compact form, and the `--graph` option makes Git draw the same kind of connection-graph I've been drawing above, except that Git puts the newer commits towards the *top* of the graph, instead of towards the right.