# Resolving individual git file conflict in rebase/merge take theirs / take ours?

Tags: git

While using git, suppose there is a local commit on `main` and a new remote commit on `origin/main` and I enter:

```
$ git pull --rebase
```

git will then rewind my local commit, apply the remote commit, and then try to merge my local commit.

Now suppose the merge fails, and there is a conflict in one binary file `foo`:

```
You are currently rebasing branch 'main'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")

Changes to be committed:
  a
  b
  c

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
    both modified:   foo
```

and I want to either:

1. Take the remote version of the file foo, completely overwriting my local changes to foo

or

2. Take the local version of the file foo, completely overwriting the remote changes to foo

What command do I run for (1) ?

```
$ git take-remote-version-??? foo
$ git rebase --continue
```

What command do I run for (2) ?

```
$ git take-local-version-??? foo
$ git rebase --continue
```

Comment: does this work ,specifically for 1st case : `git rebase -Xours <remote-branch>` ? this should take remote version changes and discard local changes completely , but it will do it for all files.

Comment: @Dev-vruper: No I specifically want to take just one file (ours or theirs).

Answer (score 3):

[eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66442114/1256452) shows one way to pick out the `--ours` and `--theirs` versions, using the numeric conventions to specify a particular index copy of some file.  I've tried that while writing this up and they are not working; I could have sworn they did work at some point, but now `--ours` and `--theirs` seem to be required.  You can (still?) use `git show`, though: `git show :1:path`, `git show :2:path`, and `git show :3:path`.  Combine this with shell style redirection to replace the working tree copy, e.g., `git show :3:path > path`.

There are several things to know before you proceed, though.  The first and most important is that during a `git rebase`, the `--ours` and `--theirs` checkout options are *very misleading*.  **The `--ours` flag can mean *their version* and the `--theirs` flag always means *our version*.**  (That's one reason to use the `:2:` and `:3:` spellings instead: at least they aren't misnamed!)

The reason this is the case is that Git is allowing the *implementation behind rebase* to show through.  Many people call these ["leaky abstractions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction), and there is [an MIT CSAIL lecture on Git and version control](https://missing.csail.mit.edu/2020/version-control/) that notes this as well.  As [Joel Spolsky notes](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/), *all* abstractions tend to leak.  Git, however, embraces the leaks, shouting them from rooftops, as it were.

This means that you need to know the following things:

1. `git rebase` is, in effect (and sometimes in reality), mostly a series of `git cherry-pick` commands.
2. `git cherry-pick` uses Git's merge engine.
3. Git's merge engine uses three input *commits*.  These three commits are called the *merge base*, the "ours" commit, and the "theirs" commit.
4. A lot of stuff about commits, Git's *index* [a.k.a.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/aka) *staging area*, and your working tree.

I'm going to omit most of what you need to know about part 4 here because it's long (but see, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64604022/1256452)).  Also, you need to know most of this just to use Git at all.  People try to skip over it because it's messy and complicated, and that's what leads to [xkcd #1597](https://xkcd.com/1597/).  Let's instead jump straight to a description of Git's merge engine.

Suppose we have a series of commits that we might draw like this, with newer commits towards the right:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Here we have two branches—more precisely, two branch *names*—`branch1` and `branch2`, which select commits `J` and `L` respectively.  We have run `git switch branch1` (or `git checkout branch1` in older Git versions), so that our index and working tree are filled in from commit `J`.  We now run `git merge branch2`, directing Git to look at commit `L`.

The three commits that are inputs to this particular merge are:

- Commit `H`: this is the one Git calls the *merge base*.  It is the *best shared commit that is on both branches*.  We can see, visually, from the drawing, *how* it's on both branches: it's where they diverge.  Why it's the *best* is mostly because it's the newest.  Internally in Git, it's because it is the Lowest Common Ancestor of the Directed Acyclic Graph, but it's obvious by eyeball that it's "newer" than commit `G`.
- Commit `J`: that's the one we have checked out right now.  That's *our* commit.  Or, in `git merge` terms, it's `--ours`.
- Commit `L`: that's the one we told `git merge` to merge.  That's *their* commit: `--theirs`.

Git's merge engine now goes on to run two `git diff`s, to compare the snapshot in commit `H` to the ones in `J` and `L`.  This produces two sets of operations: *make these changes to this file* and so on.  The merge engine *combines* these two sets of changes, applying the *combined* changes to the snapshot in commit `H`.  That way, we keep **our** changes—the changes that we made to get from `H` to `J`—and *add* **their** changes from `H`-vs-`L`.

If something goes wrong in the combining process, Git halts in the middle of the merge, leaving us with a mess.  This mess is in both Git's index, and our working tree.  Our job is to *clean up* the visible mess in our working tree, and then run `git add` to clean up Git's index too.  Git itself really only cares about the stuff that goes into its index, but we use our working trees to *make* that stuff.  So *we* care about fixing up the working tree files.

Anyway, having fixed up the working tree and run `git add`, we run `git merge --continue` or `git commit` to get Git to *finish* the merge.  Git then makes the new *merge commit* `M`, which we can draw like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Like every commit, merge commit `M` has a snapshot.  The snapshot *in* `M` is the one we proposed when we cleaned up the mess and ran `git add`.  Like every commit, merge commit `M` has some parent commits.  The thing that makes `M` a *merge commit* is that it has *two* parents: `J`, where we were when we ran `git merge` in the first place, and `L`, from the argument we gave *to* `git merge`.

So, when we're doing the "clean up the mess" part, the `--ours` and `--theirs` flags make perfect sense.  They refer to the version of some file that came out of commit `J`—"ours"—or `L`.

#### But rebase isn't merge

When we use `git rebase`, we don't have a simple fork into two branches that we need to merge.  Instead, we typically have a situation more like this:

```
          I--J   <-- our-branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- main
```

Our *goal* is to take the two existing commits `I-J` and *copy* them to new and improved commits, which we'll call `I'` and `J'` to keep track of what they got copied *from*.  What makes them new is that we're about to make them now.  What makes them **improved** is that we'll have a different source base ("rebase") on which we make some change(s), and that the parent of `I'` will be `L`, with the parent of `J'` being `I'`, so that we get this:

```
          I--J   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- main
               \
                I'-J'  <-- our-branch (HEAD)
```

By making the *name* `our-branch` select commit `J'`, we abandon the original commits in favor of the new-and-improved ones.  But there's the [small matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming) of *making* these new-and-improved commits.  That's where `git rebase` does most of its work, but here, `git rebase` fobs that work off on `git cherry-pick`.

The rebase operation starts by listing the hash IDs of commits to copy, then doing a detached-HEAD switch / checkout of the place the copies are to go.  In this case, that's commit `L`, so that we have:

```
          I--J   <-- our-branch
         /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- main, HEAD
```

Then, rebase runs `git cherry-pick hash-of-I`, to copy commit `I` to the new commit `I'`.  The end result, if all goes well, will be this:

```
          I--J   <-- our-branch
         /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- main
               \
                I'  <-- HEAD
```

If things *don't* go so well ... er, let's come back to that in a moment.

Having successfully copied `I` to `I'`, `git rebase` repeats the cherry-pick for commit `J`:

```
          I--J   <-- our-branch
         /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- main
               \
                I'-J'  <-- HEAD
```

That's the last of the commits to copy, in this example.  If there were more commits to copy—say, ten commits, or a thousand, or whatever—`git rebase` would keep on going, one commit at a time, using `git cherry-pick` to copy the commits.  Eventually it copies the last one, and that's when it stops the cherry-picking and moves the branch name:

```
          I--J   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- main
               \
                I'-J'  <-- our-branch (HEAD)
```

and that's the result we wanted, so `git rebase` is now finished.

#### When cherry-pick goes wrong, we see the individual cherry-pick

Just as with `git merge`, the cherry-pick action can *fail*.  When it does, Git stops in the middle of whatever it was doing.  Cherry-picks can happen through use of the `git cherry-pick` command, or through use of `git rebase`.  Git saves what it was doing somewhere,<sup>1</sup> then ends the in-progress operation for now.  You're now back at your shell prompt.  It is now your job to resolve the mess, then tell Git to get back to work, with `git rebase --continue` or `git cherry-pick --continue`.

But—here's the important part for us here—a cherry-pick, no matter what caused it, actually uses Git's *merge engine*, just like `git merge`.  These repeated cherry-picks are actually mini-merges, that happen over and over again.  And—since we're merging—**there is an ours, theirs, and merge-base commit** and the `--ours`, `--theirs`, and numeric `git show :1:` style stuff refer to those.

But: **What are we merging?**  That's where a diagram comes in handy.  Let's go back to our first cherry-pick, that tries to copy `I` to `I'`:

```
          I--J   <-- our-branch
         /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- main, HEAD
```

Since `HEAD` points to commit `L`, the `--ours` *commit* is commit `L`.  We had `git rebase` run `git cherry-pick hash-of-I`, so `--theirs` is commit `I`.

But commit `L` is not *our* commit, in our own heads.  Commit `L` is *their* commit.  When we ran `git rebase`, commit `J` was the current commit, not commit `L`.  Git has just slapped us in the face with one of its leaky abstractions.  The fact is, we're in the middle of a rebase-initiated cherry-pick, and Git insists on proving it to us.  So if we want *our* version of some file from commit `I`, we need to run `git checkout --theirs -- filename`.  We want the one from commit `I`, not the one from commit `L`.  If we want *their* version of the file, from commit `L`, we must use `--ours`.

This *is* documented in [the `git checkout` documentation].  Let's look, though, at what happens if we get commit `I` copied, and commit `J` is the one that has an issue:

```
          I--J   <-- our-branch
         /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- main
               \
                I'  <-- HEAD
```

Now `--ours` means *commit `I'`*, as that's where `HEAD` points.  The `--theirs` option means *commit `J`*, so `--theirs` is ours.  But `--ours` is ... *also* ours?  Whose commit *is* commit `I'`?

**This is what makes the ours/theirs flags to `git checkout` and `git restore` confusing during a rebase.**  The idea that some commit is "ours" and some commit is "theirs" works fine for `git merge`.  It works, but is backwards, for the *first* cherry-pick of a rebase.  After that, the whole idea is just crazy.  The commits are *all* ours, at this point.  It makes more sense just to use the numbers.

---

<sup>1</sup>The *somewhere* has moved around, over the years.  Fancy prompts for bash and zsh and the like have, built into them, knowledge about how to find out about a suspended merge, rebase, or cherry-pick, and will set your shell prompt to tell you that you are in the middle of an unfinished operation, including which one it is.  The `git status` command also knows where to look, and will tell you this—at least, in modern Git.  Back in the Git 1.5 days, `git status` was not as nice as it is now.

---

#### One last thing to know: you still need to `git add`

When using `git checkout --ours` or `git checkout --theirs`, what you're doing is telling Git: *copy, from your index, one of the three versions of some file, to my working tree.*  These three versions are from the merge base commit, from the `HEAD` commit, and from the other commit: numbers 1, 2, and 3.  The `--ours` flag means to retrieve version #2, from `HEAD`; the `--theirs` flag means to retrieve version #3, from the other commit that's not the merge base.  (There is no flag for version #1.)

Your job, during one of these in-progress merges that has not yet finished, is to clean up Git's index for Git.  You'll do that with your working tree files, because the Git-ified files inside the index are unusable.  But when you run `git checkout --ours` or `git checkout --theirs`, that doesn't affect Git's index.

So, if you used `git checkout --ours somefile` and `git checkout --theirs anotherfile`, you've replaced the working tree copy of these two files.  But that's just for *you*.  You still need to run `git add somefile anotherfile`, to tell Git: *Copy the working tree version of these files back into Git's index.*  It's the copy-back-into-index step that *resolves* the files.  Git takes the expanded entries, that held *three* versions of some file, and collapses then down to one normal, un-expanded index entry.  The resolved file from your working tree goes into that normal slot, in Git's index.  That's how Git remembers that you told it that the file was ready to go into the next commit.

There are other constructs, such as `git checkout commit-hash -- path`, that cause Git to *overwrite* the entry in Git's index, as well as overwriting the normal everyday copy of the file named *`path`*.  These particular constructs have the side effect of marking the file resolved, because any time you write a new copy to Git's index, that *automatically erases any expanded-to-three-index-slots-for-one-file* versions.  Since the expanded state is *how* Git remembers that there was some problem merging some file, erasing the expanded state resolves the conflict.

Comment: This is a really nice answer. Thank you! During a rebase, what is the merge base (when using `diff3` a rebase/cherry-pick will still have a base commit)? Would it still be calculated as `H` since that is where `I - J` branched from `main`?

Comment: @dcow: rebase is, in essence, repeated cherry-pick. Each cherry-pick is a merge with a forced base: you're on commit O ("ours"), you cherry-pick commit T ("theirs" even though it's yours), and the merge base B is the parent of T, `T^` or `T~`. This is the case even though T and O may not even be related (if you're cherry-picking into an orphan branch for instance). Git just diffs T^-vs-T to find "their" changes and T^-vs-HEAD to find "our" changes.

Comment: To rebase a topic that consists of commits `T1-T2-T3` in that order, `git rebase` does three cherry-picks, of `T1`, then `T2`, then `T3`. The "merge base" for the first cherry-pick operation is therefore `T1^`, and the "merge bases" for the remaining two cherry-picks are T1 and T2! Meanwhile the "ours" commit for the first cherry-pick is really "their" commit for some "them" (since you're adding on to their branch), and the "ours" commit for the remaining two are hybrids that you just made with the previous cherry-pick. This really bends the heck out of "ours" and "theirs".

Answer (score 2):

in general, the way you want to solve it (say, forget about the changes from one branch) is not *really* correct (you should go through them to see what's going on). Having said that, the way you get a file as it is in one of the 2 branches that is being merged/rebased, is like this:

```
git show :2:path-to-file > path-to-file # get this file as it is on _my_ branch
git show :3:path-to-file2 > path-to-file2 # get this file as it is on _the other_ branch/revision
git add path-to-file path-to-file2
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: What does the `2` and `3` mean?  Where is this documented?

Comment: Oh searching for `2` and `3` in `man git checkout` shows options `--ours` and `--theirs`, so would `git checkout --ours foo` and `git checkout --theirs foo` also be an answer?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_to_resolve_conflicts

Comment: After a `git checkout --ours` or `git checkout --theirs`, or manual editing of the file to produce a correct merge, you will need to run `git add` on the file as well. That's because you need to mark the file resolved, and these kinds of `git checkout` do not do so (though other kinds can!).

Comment: ... one more reason to use the form with `2:` and `3:`?

Comment: That's what I say. :-) Note that this need to `git add` still applies though.

Comment: Hm, I'm writing up a long answer and have actually tested `git checkout 2:path` etc and they don't work. I am pretty sure they *did* work at one point, but `--ours` and `--theirs` are apparently required now (Git 2.27 on the machine I'm playing on).

Comment: You gotta be kidding me :-O Will check it out later

Comment: I checked checkout with git 2.20.4 and it didn't work.... so I am adjusting the answer to use `git show >` instead