# Git branch population 'Git Branch vs Git Repo'

Tags: git

When we do a get pull or git clone, how many local branches are populated with remote-tracking branch?
I have seen new branches listed after a pull. Does it mean that all the branches in Git repository are pulled down or just names are listed? The question is more on 'what affects repo and what affects branch?'

Comment: Git clone and git fetch, by default, synchronize _all_ the remote data down to your computer.

Comment: if you could add this as answer, it would be great

Comment: Do you mean git pull only affects one branch?

Comment: @BlueClouds, yes - `git pull` affects just one branch. `git fetch` will get information for all tracking branches but will not do merge; while `git pull` will get information for branch and will try to merge remote into local one.

Answer (score 2):

`git clone` and `git pull` are completely different commands.

`git clone` [does the following](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_description):

> Clones a repository into a newly created directory, creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository (visible using git branch --remotes), and creates and checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository’s currently active branch.

While `git pull` is executed without arguments, it will merge the remote tracking branch into the current local branch.

So yes, after `git clone` command all remote-tracking branches are created locally, so they could be checked-out. And, the default branch will be checked out.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking of branches as if they actually mean something.  This is misleading you.  Git is not about branches.  Git is all about *commits*.  Branch names do matter, but only to the extent that we need them to *find* commits—and it's possible, in some cases, to find all your commits with *no* branch names at all.

(There's a secondary issue here, which is that the word *branch* in Git is ambiguous.  See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

Now, as [kosist answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65139401/1256452), `git clone` and `git pull` are different, but to really see the difference properly, we should break each of those two commands into its constituent parts, because both of them are higher-level commands that work by running lower-level commands.

In fact, `git clone` runs *six* commands—well, *up to* six—of which five are Git commands.  Meanwhile `git pull` runs *two* commands, each of which is a Git command.  The *second* of the two commands that `git pull` runs is configurable, but it normally defaults to `git merge`; we'll come back to that in a bit.  Let's note here that the *first* of the two commands that `git pull` runs is `git fetch`.  Now let's look at the six commands that `git clone` runs:

1. `mkdir` (or some variant for your particular computer/OS): this makes a new, empty directory, after which the remaining five commands run in that new empty directory.
2. `git init`: this adds a new empty *repository* underneath the new directory.  The repository itself is the `.git` sub-directory in the new directory.
3. `git remote add`: this adds a *remote*, which stores a URL.  The stored URL is from your `git clone` command.
4. `git config` (if/as needed): this step is optional and is needed only if you've specified particular configuration values to set in the new clone.
5. `git fetch`: **aha! this is where we overlap with `git pull`.**
6. `git checkout` (or in Git 2.23 or later, `git switch`): this *creates* one branch name, and makes it the current commit and current branch.  There are some fiddly details here that we'll mostly ignore, but note that until step 6 runs, your new clone had *no* branches at all.

Again, the overlap is at step 5.  The `clone` command runs `git fetch` and the `pull` command runs `git fetch`.  It is the `git fetch` command that obtains new *commits* from the other Git repository.

#### A Git repository is a collection of commits

It's time to step back a bit and make a note of what a Git repository really is, at both a high level and at the low level of individual commits.

At a high level, a repository consists mainly of two databases.  These two databases are simple [key-value stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database).  The main and usually bigger one has, as its keys, *object IDs* or *hash IDs* (Git used to call them SHA-1 IDs, but Git is moving to SHA-256, and eventually, perhaps, pluggable hashes).  Commits are one of four kinds of objects, and the one kind that you normally deal with sort-of-directly; all four kinds exist in this database, but two of the other four are there to support commits, and the last one is there to help with *annotated tags*, which help you (and Git) *find* commits, so in the end, we're mostly interested in the commits.

The second, usually smaller, database holds names: branch names, tag names, and all of Git's other kinds of names.  Each name holds one *hash ID*.  If the name is a *branch* name, it is *required* to hold a *commit* hash ID; other names can use one of those other internal object types, if that's helpful (but we won't look at when it is helpful here as we are concentrating on branch names).

So this is how and why Git is all about commits: everything we do is in the service of finding some commit hash ID, and that hash ID allows Git to look up the commit in the main database.  From there, Git can get at what's inside the commit.

#### What is inside a commit

Once we *find* a commit by its hash ID, Git gets two things out of it:

- Each commit has a full source snapshot.  That is, it has, saved for all time (or as long as the commit exists anyway), copies of all the files that Git knew about, at the time you, or whoever, *made* the commit.  That's the data part of a commit: the source snapshot.
- Each commit also has some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit, and a date-and-time stamp showing *when* they made the commit.  It includes other things like a log message.  Crucially for Git itself, each commit is also allowed to store the hash ID of some number of earlier, already-existing commits.  Most commits store exactly one such hash ID.

No part of any commit (or any Git object, really) can ever be changed, so these hash IDs are good forever.  The fact that a commit stores the hash ID of some *earlier* commit, which Git calls the *parent* of the commit, means that if we have a series of commits in a row, they form a nice simple linear chain, where each commit points *backwards*, like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the actual hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  As long as we somehow know what this commit's ID is, we can have Git find it.  Inside `H` we'll find the source code snapshot, and also the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.

We can thus have Git use `H` to find `G`.  Inside `G`, we have a snapshot and an earlier commit ID, so from `G` we can find `F`.

Inside `F` ... well, you should have the idea by now.  By starting from the end, Git can work backwards, through each commit, all the way to the beginning.  The commits in the repository therefore *are* the history in the repository.  All we need to know is the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain, and we're good, because Git is all about commits.

#### Branch names let us find commits

The tricky part is knowing the hash ID.  What's the hash ID of the last commit you made?  How about some other commit?  Do you remember any of them?  (I don't remember mine!)  We could write them all down or something, but that's silly: we have a *computer*.  Let's have the *computer* save them.

This is what a branch name does for us: it saves a hash ID.  Well, so does any other name in Git: we'll see what's extra-special about a *branch name* in a moment.  For now, let's just say that we have the name `main` or `master` holding hash ID `H`.  Then we can draw this as:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

The *name* lets us have Git find `H`, from which we find all earlier commits.

Once we start making new branches, well, let's first make one new name, `br1`, that also points to `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, main
```

We now need to know which *name* we'd like to use.  At the moment it doesn't matter too much: both mean *commit `H`*.  But that is about to change.  So, let's attach the special name `HEAD`, written in all uppercase like this, to one branch name:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), main
```

Now, we'll make a new commit, in the way that we do that in Git (which we won't cover at all here).  The new commit, being new, gets a new, unique hash ID, different from every other commit hash ID in the universe,<sup>1</sup> which we'll just call `I` here:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

We need to have the name `br1` find commit `I`.  Git makes this happen by writing the new hash ID *into* the name to which `HEAD` is attached:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
```

Nothing happens to `HEAD`, but now the *name* `br1` selects commit `I`.  When we use the name `main`, that selects commit `H`: `H` is the last commit on `main`.  When we use the name `br1`, that selects commit `I`: `I` is the last commit on `br1`.

If we go back to `main` and make a new commit (and draw `br1` above instead of below for no apparent reason), we get this:

```
          I   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J   <-- main (HEAD)
```

and now we can easily see how commits up through `H` are on *both* branches.  (If we drew this differently, we might think commits up through `H` are only on `main`, or only on `br1`, but in Git, they really are on *both branches*.  Other non-Git systems are more rigid about branches; there, branches are much real-er than they are in Git.  In Git, the names are just there to find "last" commits, and as we saw, there can be commits after the "last" ones: these last ones are just the last ones *on the given branch*.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It only has to be unique *within all clones of this repository*, but in general, it's universally unique.  But SHA-1 is now too small to guarantee this: see also [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)

---

#### Remote-tracking names

When we did that first `git clone`, or run the `git fetch` step of a `git pull`, we have `git fetch` run.  When `git fetch` runs, it:

- calls up some other Git;
- has that Git list out its branch names and other such names; and
- uses the hash IDs from this list to figure out which commits are new, and to get them from the other Git.

Remember, those hash IDs are universal: they're the same in *every* Git.  So our Git can just see whether or not we have the hash IDs that their Git lists out.  If we don't have the hash ID, we must need the commit.  We ask their Git to send over that commit.  Their Git tells us what parent(s) that commit has, and if we don't have them, we get those too—so that in the end, we get all the commits *they* have that *we don't*.

Let's say that since an earlier clone, where we got:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (in their Git)
```

we get, this time:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

(again these names are in *their* Git repository, as *their* branch names).  So the new commits are `I-J` and `K-L`.  The parent of `J` is `I`; the parent of `I` is `H`; we already have `H` in our repository.  The parent of `L` is `K` and the parent of `K` is `H`.  So we ask for them to package up and send over the four new commits.

Once they do, we have, in our repository:

```
          I--J   ???
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   ???
```

We have `main` because *our* Git made it when it ran step 6 of the checkout.  We made our `main` from their `main`.  How will we have our Git remember that they had their `br1` pointing to `J`, and their `br2` pointing to `L`?

The answer is that our Git takes their *branch names* and *renames* them.  They become our *remote-tracking names*.  We change their `br1` to `origin/br1`,<sup>2</sup> change their `br2` to `origin/br2`, and change their `main` to `origin/main`.  In fact, we did that last change earlier—so we already had `origin/main` to select commit `H`, along with our `main`.  If we draw all the `origin/` names in, we get this:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/br2
```

So now we have an easy way to find all the commits, using these remote-tracking names.  We can find any commits we have that they don't—right now, there are none, but if we make some, we'll have some—using our *branch* names.

---

<sup>2</sup>These names actually go into a separate [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), under `refs/remotes/` rather than `refs/heads/`.

---

#### So `git fetch` obtains *commits* and updates *remote-tracking names*

What this means is that what `git clone` and `git pull` have in common is that they run `git fetch`, and this gets the *commits* and updates *remote-tracking names*.  You can run `git fetch` in its unlimited mode, as:

```
git fetch origin
```

and it will download *all* new commits and update *all* remote-tracking names, or you can run it in a more limited way:

```
git fetch origin br1
```

and it will only download new commits for their `br1`, and update our `origin/br1` from their `br1`.  The `git pull` command may use this more limited form of fetch.<sup>3</sup>

Note: I tend to avoid `git pull` entirely myself: I run my own `git fetch`, then run a second command of my choice if and when I want to, rather than letting `git pull` run `git fetch` and then immediately running a second Git command that I have to pick in advance.  But this is a matter of taste—you certainly *can* use `git pull`, if you like it.

---

<sup>3</sup>Back in the old days, when `git pull` was a shell script, it was easier to see what it did: if you ran `git pull` with no arguments, it ran `git fetch` with no arguments; if you ran `git pull origin br1`, it ran `git fetch origin br1`; so it was easy to tell how it was going to run `git fetch`.  It's now a C program and it is harder to see what it does, but the `fetch` output tell you what it did.

---

#### That second Git command

The second command that `git pull` runs is (usually) `git merge` or `git rebase`.  You pick which one you want: `git pull --rebase` makes it use the second one (usually).<sup>4</sup>  Otherwise it uses the one you configured; if you didn't configure one, it uses `git merge`.<sup>5</sup>  **Both commands operate on the current branch only,** so `git pull` *only affects the current branch*, even if the `git fetch` it ran picked up many commits and updated many remote-tracking names.

---

<sup>4</sup>This "usually" is because there's a special case: if you run `git pull` when on an orphan branch / in a new empty repository, it just runs `git checkout` or `git switch` as its second command.  There are also some cases where it does nothing at all, to avoid wrecking uncommitted work; in the bad old days, `git pull` could accidentally wreck such work.  That's another reason I still don't use it, having been burned by this rather nasty bug.  It's been fixed for more than a decade, I think, but that was a bad burn.

<sup>5</sup>You can configure it to use `git merge --ff-only`, and I for one think this is actually a good idea.  A future version of Git may eventually default to this behavior, which is probably the right default.  You can also specify more command line options, though many of them are relatively new.  Since I don't use `git pull` regularly (and have not done so for probably a decade) I'm not sure how new "relatively new" is.

---

#### Note that you cannot be "on" a remote-tracking name

The reason to use a *branch* name is that whole notion of being "on a branch", where when you make a *new* commit, Git drags the branch name forward to include the new commit.

To get "on a branch", you simply run `git checkout` with the name:

```
git checkout main
```

or:

```
git checkout br1
```

for instance.  If the branch name exists now, `git checkout` chooses it as the *current name*, finds the *commit* that goes with it, and checks out that commit if possible.  (If you have uncommitted work, this request might get rejected, if that work would be destroyed in the process.)

If the branch name *does not* exist, Git has a trick: it will check to see if exactly one *remote-tracking name* looks a lot like that branch name.  If so, Git will *create* the branch name, using the remote-tracking name as the starting commit.  It will then check out that branch name.  So `git checkout` actually *creates new branch names*.

This is basically free: branch names in Git have almost no cost.  *Commits* have some cost (often still pretty small), but *branch names* just *point to* the commits, so they're super-cheap.  Moreover, *your* branch names are *yours*.  They are not anyone else's.  Your own repository holds your branch names.  When your Git sees someone else's branch names, your Git turns them into your *remote-tracking* names instead.

The new (since Git 2.23) `git switch` command works the same way here, but has a few new safety features, so if you have this later version of Git, you might want to train yourself to run `git switch` instead of `git checkout`.

Once you do have a remote-tracking name, though, you might want to try out something like:

```
git checkout origin/br2
```

This *does work*, but it *does not put you on a branch*.  In fact, it takes you *off* a branch, and puts you into what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode.  You can view a commit this way, and you can even do new work this way, but the doing-new-work part is usually a bad idea.  For this reason, `git switch` *requires* that you add `--detach` if you are going to use a remote-tracking name:

```
git switch --detach origin/br2
```

does the same thing that `git checkout` does.  The checkout command omits the safety check of requiring `--detach`; the switch command keeps it.

We won't go into the details of operating in detached-HEAD mode, but since you're no longer on a branch, the *second* part of `git pull` becomes messy.

#### Conclusion

- `git clone` runs `git fetch`, which obtains new commits and updates remote-tracking names.  But that's one of six steps.
- `git pull` runs `git fetch`, which obtains new commits and updates remote-tracking names.  But that's one of two steps.
- The big difference between these is in the remaining steps.
- Because the *second* command from `git pull` works on the *current branch* (only), if you have more than one local branch you want to update, you'll need more than one Git command to update it.
- For efficiency, you can run one `git fetch` (on your own), followed by multiple `git checkout` and other Git commands:

  ```
   git fetch origin
   git checkout br1 && git merge
   git checkout br2 && git merge
  ```

  for instance.  This is roughly equivalent to:

  ```
   git checkout br1 && git pull
   git checkout br2 && git pull
  ```

  except that it's more efficient with CPU and network time.  (But which is more expensive: the computer's time, or your time?  Maybe the shorter command line is cheaper in the end.)
- If all you want to do with a commit is *look* at it, consider using the "detached HEAD" mode.  You do not need your own branch name for this!  You can work in Git without branches.  Just remember not to make *new commits* in this mode.  (If you do make new commits by mistake, it's easy to recover, though.  Nothing committed is lost, at least for 30 days by default, because commits are completely read-only and mostly permanent.  The 30 days has to do with commits that you can't *find* any more: if there is no way to find a commit and it's more than 30 days old, Git will tend to feel free to clean it out.)

Answer (score 0):

- Git clone affects all branches in the repo.
- Git pull affects partially:
  It will fetch all the branches from the repo but update to latest(merge) if branch exits on the local system for current branch only(default checked-out branch). This is why you
  saw the name of all the branches listed.