# submit code on the main branch but create a master branch

Tags: git, github

I tried to upload my code to a repository on GitHub.

These are the commands I used:

```
git add . 
git commit -m "text"
git push
```

However, instead of uploading the code to the `main` branch on GitHub, it created a `master` branch on my repository.
It looks like this now, with "main" shown first, then "master":

[image: main branch]

[image: master branch]

May I ask how can I merge these two branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is effectively a duplicate of [How to merge main and master branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65369949/1256452)  My answer there, however, is much longer and more general: it covers your specific case, but your specific case is quite simple as you have nothing interesting on your GitHub `main`.  You can just replace your existing GitHub `main` with what you currently call `master`, using:

```
git branch -m main
git push --force origin main
```

from your computer (your laptop).  *Normally*, `git push --force` (or even `git push --force-with-lease`) is something to use carefully at best.  Here, you're using it carefully—though you may not yet know it.

I recommend you read through the more complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65371141/1256452), but given the two images you show in your original question, the "overwrite main" method shown above should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge these two branches with:

```
git switch <branch you want to merge to>
git merge <branch you want to merge onto the current branch>
git branch -d <branch name> //Optional, will delete the branch
```

To avoid this issue with future repositories, you can run this command:

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

It tells git to name the default branch 'main' instead of 'master' when using  'git init'.

For further information on branches take a look at this: [Github - Manage branches](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository)

Comment: He'd need to use `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories` here.

Comment: By the way, you can also do the reverse - set default branch on your GitHub project to `master` and delete `main` altogether.