# what's the best way to create a feature branch from remote in git?

Tags: git

Sounds like a dumb question, right?

```sh
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout -b myBranchName
```

Except I always forget the git pull step... when this is such a common use-case I imagine there *must* be some chrome to make this automatic, right?  Some way to skip the local "master"?

Because I did it again today.  I switched to `master`, created my feature branch, a bunch of work got done and then I found out when I pushed I discovered my feature branch was way behind `master` in a horribly conflict-y way.

I always forget the `git pull` step.  So I'm getting the worst kind of silent failure where everything *looks* fine until way later when you find out you're screwed.

Is there a way to avoid this?  A way to say "don't trust my local `master` branch, instead go back to the remote to create my local untracked branch?  Or am I just trading a "oops you forgot to `git pull`" for "ooops you forgot to `git fetch`" if I do that?

Comment: Enter `git rebase master` in your feature branch?

Comment: @dan1st of course, fixing the mistake afterwards is easy normally but this time there were bad conflicts so I'm trying to figure out what I should be doing instead of "git checkout master; git checkout -b myBranchName" where I forget the "git pull" for the future.

Comment: Make a script that does the pull and checkout at once?

Comment: You can configure an alias in git  eg :`git config --global alias.oops '!git checkout master && git pull origin master'` . this should checkout your local master , pull the latest changes inside the master automatically .  Run it as `git oops`.
You can rename the alias as you wish . ;)

Comment: I guess the merging and other fixes don't hurt bad enough if you still keep forgetting :)

Comment: This post reminds me of the late night infomercials selling products for people forgetting or being clumsy.

Comment: @Pxtl any luck in trying to set the alias and solving your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure an alias in git eg :`git config --global alias.oops '!git checkout master && git pull origin master'` . this should checkout your local master , pull the latest changes inside the master automatically .

Run it as `git oops`. You can rename the alias as you wish . ;)

PS : Also it can be tweaked to checkout a new branch from your master branch.

`git config --global alias.oops '!git checkout master && git pull origin master && git checkout'`

you can run it as `git oops -b <feature-branchname>`

Answer (score 1):

I create branches from remote directly:

```
git checkout -b my-feature origin/main
```

then the branch is set to track that remote branch.... which allows for not having to update a local branch in order to pull updates on the base branch.

Comment: But that means if I push I'm pushing straight to master.  I have a branch policy to prevent that, but that means I then have to create a remote tracking branch and switch to track that.

I assume I can script around that but it seems like in the end it's a multi-step operation so at that point all roads come back to "make a git config alias".

Comment: If you tried pushing, I _think_ it would complain because the branch is not named the same.

Comment: @eftshift0: you're right *as long as* `push.default` is set to `simple`. That's the default for `push.default`, if you haven't set it, as long as your Git version is at least 2.0. In 1.7 and 1.8, the default is different (though it still won't overwrite origin's main/master).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the *rest* of your work-flow, you might benefit from simply *deleting your `master` branch name entirely*.  Once you do that, you can't be *on* that branch, because you don't *have* that branch.

That aside, if you created a new branch name from your local `master` but forgot to update your local `master` first, there are multiple cures.  To understand them—and to understand when and **why** *deleting* your local `master` works—it helps to realize that in Git, *branch names are almost irrelevant*.  They do one important thing for us (and for Git): they help us *find* commits.  But it's not the branch names that matter!  It is the *commits* that matter.

It's this one fact—that the names let us find commits—that makes the names important.  So the names become *un*-important whenever there is some *other* way to find those commits.

To make sense out of *this*, take note of `git log` output.  Here's a sample of a fragment of `git log --oneline` output from a clone of the Git repository for Git:

```
$ git log --oneline
328c109303 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) The eighth batch
8b25dee615 Merge branch 'tb/precompose-prefix-too'
006c5f79be Merge branch 'jk/complete-branch-force-delete'
60f8121940 Merge branch 'jv/upload-pack-filter-spec-quotefix'
```

Note the funky numbers ([hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) numbers) on the left.  These are the actual commit IDs, shortened somewhat because the full number is very long.  (The Git repository for Git is fairly big at this point so the numbers are now shortened to 10 characters instead of 7; smaller repositories use shorter shortenings.)

The numbers appear random, but aren't.  They are in fact the result of running a cryptographic hash function over the contents of each commit.  In this way, every Git in the universe will agree that the top commit in the list here gets the number [`328c10930387d301560f7cbcd3351cc485a13381`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/328c10930387d301560f7cbcd3351cc485a13381).  No other commit, anywhere or any time, can use this number.<sup>1</sup>

What a branch name, like `master` as seen in the output above, does is hold the hash ID of the *last* commit that's on that branch.  But another name might also hold that hash ID.  In this case, another name *does* hold it: the name `origin/master` holds the same hash ID.  The special thing about `origin/master` is that it's not a *branch* name: `git switch` won't switch to it, for instance.

Anyway, once you've internalized the idea that it's the *numbers* that matter, and that *names* like `master` are just convenient ways to *find* the numbers, we're ready to move on to the next section.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, some other Git repository *could* re-use this number, but only if that other Git repository never comes in contact with a clone of the Git repositories for Git.  They won't explode in a Star-Trek-Matter-Antimatter-End-Of-The-Universe fashion, but if another Git repository somehow re-uses the hash ID for something else, it's, well, Not Good.  See also [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)

These are SHA-1 numbers.  The Git folks are gradually moving to SHA-256.  Exactly how we'll get there is still a bit of an open question.  Currently (Git 2.30), you can make a SHA-256 repository and use it, or a SHA-1 repository and use it; but you can't ever have a SHA-256-speaking Git talk to a SHA-1-speaking Git.  You can't even upgrade an old database to a new one, nor downgrade a new one to an old one.  That's not a very acceptable situation.

---

#### Branches, in several senses

Each commit is numbered: OK.  Git actually *finds* the commits—and its other internal objects—by these hash-ID numbers.  OK.  But: so what?

Well, there's several more things to know about commits.  Without going deep into them, let's just say here that they're made up of two parts: a *snapshot of all files*, and some *metadata*.  The snapshot is what `git checkout` checks out.  The metadata is stuff about the commit itself, such as who made it, when, and why.  We see this metadata in `git log` output:

```
$ git log
commit 328c10930387d301560f7cbcd3351cc485a13381
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 12 14:13:40 2021 -0800

    The eighth batch
    
    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
...
```

Here we have the commit's author, the date-and-time (last Friday—I haven't updated all week!), and Junio's log message (which is rather terse since the real information is in all the merges).  What you *don't* see here is that the commit's metadata *also* stores something just for Git, which Git calls the *parent* of this commit.  The parent of `328c10930387d301560f7cbcd3351cc485a13381` is [`8b25dee6155fd3816f62649da196a4f42cf5584e`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b25dee6155fd3816f62649da196a4f42cf5584e), where Git picked up a fix for a Mac-specific bug having to do with Unicode file names.<sup>2</sup>  (This parent-of-`328c109303` commit is itself a *merge commit*, because it has not just one but *two* parent commits, but in most Git repositories, most commits are not merges.  Below, I'm not drawing any merge commits.)

This trick of storing the *previous* commit's hash ID means that in Git, a commit "points backwards" to the previous commit, which then points backwards again, one more step.  This repeats over and over again, stringing the commits into one long backwards-looking chain.  If we draw such a chain, replacing the real commit hash IDs with symbols such as uppercase letters (so as to retain sanity in our feeble human brains), we get a picture that looks like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the *last* commit in this chain.  Commit `H` points back to earlier commit `G`, which points back to `F`, and so on.  This repeats until we reach the very first commit ever (presumably `A`): that one doesn't point backwards because it *can't*.  So that's where `git log` stops, if we don't cut it off sooner.

Git, as always, finds each of these commits by their hash IDs.  But where will Git find the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain, commit `H`?  We could write it down on paper, or on a whiteboard, perhaps.  But that would be silly: we have a computer.  What if we save it in a file?  Better yet, what if we have *Git* save it, *automatically*, in some file or database somewhere?

That's what a *branch name* is.  A branch name, such as `master`, just holds *one* hash ID.  This hash ID is automatically the *last* commit in the chain.  So if we have this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

then what we mean is that the *name* `master` is holding the hash ID of commit `H`, which is the last in that chain.  That's true even if there are commits *after* `H`, like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- feature
```

Here, the *name* `feature` holds the hash ID of commit `J`, so that `feature` points to `J`.  `J` in turn points backwards to `I`, which points backwards to `H`, which points backwards to `G`, and so on.

Commit `H` is simultaneously the *last in the chain that ends at `master` = `H`* **and** *somewhere in the middle of the chain that ends at `feature` = `J`*.  Commits up through `H` are on *both branches*.  Commits `I` and `J` are only on `feature`.

The word *branch* in Git is ambiguous: it means both a *branch name*, and *a set of commits ended by one I care about at the moment*.  The chain of commits leading up to `H` is "a branch", and is "branch master", but the branch *name* `master` really just *picks out* commit `H`, from which Git can work backwards.  The chain of commits leading up to `J` is also "a branch", while branch *name* `feature` picks out commit `J`.

The special feature of *branch names* like `master` and `feature`, though, is that they *move*.  Let's see how this works.

---

<sup>2</sup>This involves the way macOS takes two different files, e.g., named `schön` vs `schön`, and collapses them into one single file, because it's impossible to *see* the difference between the two file names, or in fact to post it here.  One is S C H O COMBINING-DIAERESIS N using Unicode code-point U+0308, and the other is S C H LATIN-SMALL-LETTER-O-WITH-DIAERESIS N using Unicode code point U+00F6.  On a Linux box, you can make two different files using these two different byte sequences.  Upon transferring this commit to a Mac box, an attempt to extract this commit will fail because the local file system will just create one file.  Command line arguments must be turned into the correct form; the current Git releases get this slightly wrong.

---

#### How branch names move as branches grow

Let's start with this again, though for no obvious reason I'll draw `feature` on top instead of below, this time.  It doesn't matter how you draw these, as long as you remember that commits point *backwards*.  Git draws these so that newer commits are on top and connections go down the page.  People sometimes draw newer commits towards the bottom.  The internal arrows, from commit to commit, always go *backwards:* Git has a hard time going forwards, and an easy time going backwards, so Git generally works backwards.  That's why `git log` goes backwards, for instance.  Not only do *we* want to see the newest commit first, so does Git.

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

We will pick out one branch and "check it out", with `git checkout`, or, if our Git is 2.23 or later, `git switch`.  Both commands do the same thing here.  Let's say we run `git switch master` (or `git checkout master`).  This will make `master` our *current branch name*, and get out, into our work area, all the *files* from commit `H`.  Let's draw this by attaching the special name `HEAD` to the name `master`:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Now let's make a *new* branch name, `feature2`, with `git checkout -b feature2` or `git switch -c feature2` or even `git branch feature2; git checkout feature2` or whatever.  They all do the same thing: make the new branch name `feature2` point to commit `H`, and attach `HEAD` there, like this:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- feature2 (HEAD), master
```

Now let's make a new commit, in the usual way.  It gets an all-new hash ID, but we'll just call it `K` for short.  `K`'s parent will be `H`, because we used `H` to *make* `K`.  So the result looks like this:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             K   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

Note how Git has *moved* the name `feature2`.  It does this by writing `K`'s hash ID into the *name* `feature2`, just after making commit `K`.<sup>3</sup>

If we make another new commit `L` we get:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             K--L   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

Note how the *name* `feature2`, to which our `HEAD` is attached, gets updated each time.  The other names don't change, and no existing commit changes—none can, in any way, due to the hash ID scheme for numbering them—but as we add new commits, one by one, the *current branch name moves*.

If we make a bad commit and want to get rid of it, we can use `git reset`.  This command is quite complicated, but in the mode we'd use to get rid of the bad commit, what it does is easy to draw.  It sort of shoves the commit aside (without changing it) and makes our *current name* point to some other commit, like this:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             K   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
              \
               L   ???
```

Commit `L` still *exists* in the Git database.  But now, *there is no **name** by which to find it.*<sup>4</sup>  The commit *appears* to be gone.  If you saved its hash ID somewhere, though, you could use another `git reset` to get it back:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             K
              \
               L   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

The `reset` command can move the *current name* **anywhere** (to any existing commit) so it is quite powerful.

(Once we put `L` back as the *last* commit in the chain, there's no reason to draw the commit on a row by itself any more.  I kept the extra row it to make it clear that we're just moving the name around.)

---

<sup>3</sup>The hash ID for `K` incorporates all the metadata, including the exact time Git makes `K`, the hash ID of parent commit `H`, your log message, and so on.  This means nobody—not you, not Git, *nothing*—knows what the hash ID *will be* until the commit is actually made.

<sup>4</sup>To make sure you *can* find it again if you decide you want it back, Git keeps multiple *hidden* names.  These eventually expire, typically after 30 days or more; once they expire, and the commit is truly un-find-able, `git gc` will "garbage collect" it, throwing it away for real.

---

#### How all this relates to your original problem

Let's go back to your original problem now:

> ```
> git checkout master
> git pull
> git checkout -b myBranchName
> ```
>
> Except I always forget the `git pull` step...

I'm going to go very fast here: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command to do something with any commits I just fetched.*  The usual *second* thing takes those new commits and adds them on to `master`.  So the end result is that if you do what you had *intended* to do, you would start with:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

The `git pull` would run `git fetch`, which adds a new commit or two (or many) and updates the non-branch name, `origin/master`, to find the *last* one:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/master
```

The *second* command winds up moving the *name* `master` forward, almost like `git reset` (but much more safely: using `git reset` tells Git *wipe out unsaved work* while whatever second command you've configured carefully preserves unsaved work, or halts if it would destroy it).<sup>5</sup>  The result is:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

Now when you create a new name `myBranchName` or `feature2` or whatever,<sup>6</sup> this new name points to commit `J`:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- master, myBranchName (HEAD), origin/master
```

If you've forgotten the `pull` step, the newly created branch name points to commit `H` instead (and you don't even *have* commits `I-J` yet):

```
...--G--H   <-- master, myBranchName (HEAD), origin/master
```

Later, you'll run `git fetch`—perhaps as part of a `git pull`—and pick up the new commits.  By then, you might have made your own new commit `K`:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/master
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K   <-- myBranchName (HEAD)
```

If you now `git checkout master` and get Git to "slide the branch name forward" (as `git pull` will do), you have:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K   <-- myBranchName
```

Your existing commit `K` points back to *old* commit `H`.  **This is not an error in and of itself.**  There's nothing *wrong* with having your commit(s), and your branch(es), descend from older commits.  You can just keep working, then eventually use `git merge` to combine work.  Let's say you switch back to your branch and make one new commit `L`:

```
          I--J   <-- master, origin/master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- myBranchName (HEAD)
```

You can now switch back to `master` and `git merge` your work, to combine your changes in `K-L` (as seen from commit `H`) with their changes in `I-J` (as seen from commit `H`) and get a new *merge commit* `M`:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/master
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- myBranchName
```

If you look at various Git repositories, including the Git repository for Git, you'll see this kind of work-flow sometimes.  There's nothing wrong with it.  But some people *dislike* it, for whatever reason.  If you are one of those people, or work with them, you can simply take your two commits—`K` and `L`—and *copy* them to *new and improved* commits.

Without going into all the mechanism, `git rebase` will do this for you.  You don't even have to update your `master`.  Let's say you're in this position:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/master
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- myBranchName (HEAD)
```

You can now run:

```
git checkout myBranchName
git rebase origin/master
```

Git will copy commit `K` to a new-and-improved(?) commit, which we'll call `K'` to imply the copying action, that comes after `J`.  Then Git will copy commit `L` to a new-and-improved(?) commit `L'` that comes after `K'`.  Having made these two copies, Git will peel the name `myBranchName` off the old end of the old chain, and paste it onto the new end of the new chain, like this:

```
               K'-L'  <-- myBranchName (HEAD)
              /
          I--J   <-- origin/master
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   ???
```

Commits `K` and `L` seem to have vanished, but commits `K'` and `L'` look so much like original commits `K` and `L`—except for the big ugly hash numbers, but do you remember any of the ones from above? I don't—that it will *seem* as though Git magically changed the commits in place somehow.

You can simply *delete the name `master` entirely* now too, because `origin/master` is the one you care about: it finds the right commit after each `git fetch`.  If we do that, and drop the un-find-able commits and straighten out all the kinks we can, we get:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- origin/master
               \
                K'-L'   <-- myBranchName (HEAD)
```

which looks as though you didn't forget the `git pull` earlier.

Note that if you haven't made any commits at all yet, i.e., if you have:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, myBranchName (HEAD), origin/master
```

when you remember to run the `git fetch` you forgot about, you can now delete `master` entirely (optional) and run `git fetch` (mandatory) to get:

```
...--G--H   <-- myBranchName (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/master
```

If you now run `git rebase origin/master`, your Git will quietly copy *no* commits and then move the name `myBranchName`:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- myBranchName (HEAD), origin/master
```

so `git rebase` works for both these situations.  That's pretty convenient.

---

<sup>5</sup>In truly ancient Git versions, somewhere around 1.5 or so, `git pull` would sometimes accidentally destroy unsaved work.  I got burned this way more than once!  I *avoid* `git pull`, in part because of this, though also because I like to insert commands *between* the two that `git pull` will run.

<sup>6</sup>If you use Windows or macOS, I recommend avoiding mixedCaseNames.  *Git* thinks that case in branch names matters.  Your OS thinks that case in file names *doesn't* matter.  Git sometimes stores branch names in files, and sometimes stores them *as file names*, and this means that the case sometimes matters and sometimes doesn't.  The experience is confusing and miserable.  Avoid mixing case, and you avoid the misery.

Answer (score 0):

### "Is there a way to avoid this?"

> I think not! I think it's a matter of attention. But if that happens ...

```
// new branch feature from master
git checkout -b my_feature

// did you forget the pull at master?
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout my_feature
git merge master
```