# Switching branches in git tracking

Tags: git, github

```
What does the 'main' setup to track remote branch main from origin mean?
```

I understand Origin is the URL for my remote repository

```
> PC@DESKTOP-R8DI61V MINGW64 ~/Desktop/team6/ch (team1.1) $ git checkout
> main Switched to a new branch 'main' Branch 'main' set up to track
> remote branch 'main' from 'origin'.
```

Also when I change to a different branch say team1

And use git branch, the main branch does not show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'main' setup to track remote branch main from origin` means there is local branch whose name is also main which is configured or set up to track remote branch ( whose name is also main hosted somewhere for example in github)

whenever you make changes to your remote branch (main) your local main will track those changes

```
the main branch does not show
```

for branches I usually use this

```
git branch # to show all branch 
git branch -a # to show all branches low and remote 
git checkout branchname # to shift to another branch
```

Comment: OKay thanks, how can i check the branch structure. For example if Dev branch is a sub branch of main

Comment: `git log --graph --simplify-by-decoration --all` check git log documentation http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log
if it solved your purpose do upvote and accept it as your solution so that it may help others in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your secondary question:

> ... how can i check the branch structure. For example if Dev branch is a sub branch of main

Branches—or more precisely, branch *names*—are never super- or sub-branches of any other branch names.  They all live at the same "level", as it were:

- The first trick here is that in Git, the branch names don't *really* matter.  What *really* matters are the commits themselves.  Those commits exist regardless of which branches contain them.
- The second trick—which doesn't undo the first one!—is that the *branch names* are how we *find* the commits.  Since the commits matter, this makes the branch names matter ... but only to the extent that we need those branch names to find the commits.

As [Jatin Mehrotra commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66616177/switching-branches-in-git-tracking#comment117761588_66616311), you can use `git log --graph` (usually with additional flags) to ask Git to draw a *graph* of your commits.  For (much) more about this, see [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452).  For StackOverflow posting purposes, I like to draw my graphs horizontally, using either `o` characters for each commit, like this:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master
```

or single uppercase letters to stand in for the actual hash IDs of each commit.  You'll see the real hash IDs of commits when you run `git log`.  They are very big and ugly and impossible for mere humans to deal with—you need a computer to use the hash IDs—which is why, in my drawings, I use the letters instead:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

Here, we have a string of commits ending at commit `H` (`H` is short for Hash-ID).  Git *finds* the hash ID of commit `H` because the *branch name* `master` holds it.  That is, we can literally ask Git: *What hash ID does the name `master` represent?*

```
$ git rev-parse master
225365fb5195e804274ab569ac3cc4919451dc7f
```

So `H` here might stand in for `225365fb5195e804274ab569ac3cc4919451dc7f`.

Commit `H` itself is made up of two parts.  Both parts are completely read-only!  Nothing can ever change these, so commit `H` saves these two things forever:

- One part of the commit is a *snapshot of every file*.  The files inside a commit are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form.  They are, in effect, an *archive* of your files.  The de-duplication is there because most commits mostly *re-use* files from some other commit, and this means that the re-used files don't take any space.
- The other part of the commit is some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit, for instance.  It includes the date-and-time of *when* they made the commit.  It includes their *log message* in which they should explain *why* they made the commit.  And, for Git's own internal purposes, the metadata includes the actual hash ID of some *earlier* commit or commits.

The earlier commit—the one that comes *before* commit `H`—has some big ugly hash ID, such as `140045821aa78da3a80a7d7c8f707b955e1ab40d` (let's call that `G` for short).  This looks random,<sup>1</sup> so there's no easy way to associate one hash—or one commit—with the other, *except for the fact that commit `H` has commit `G`'s hash ID inside `H`*.  **We say that `H` *points to* `G`.**

Commit `G`, in turn, stores a snapshot—a full set of every file; comparing the snapshot in `G` to the one in `H` shows what files got *changed*—and metadata.  The metadata in `G` points to a still-earlier commit, `F`.  Commit `F`, like `G` and `H`, stores a snapshot and metadata, so from `F` Git can go backwards to an even-earlier commit, and so on down the line.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's actually a cryptographic checksum, similar in some ways to some of the tricks that power digital currencies.

---

#### Branch names

This stuff—the commits with their snapshots and metadata—is mostly what's really *in* a repository.  The snapshots hold files, which Git can extract for you to see and work on / with, and metadata, which Git can use to find earlier commits.  But to use the *latest* commit, we have to know which one *is* the latest.  That's where the branch names come in.

**Each branch name holds just one hash ID.**  The hash ID stored in the branch name is, by definition, the *last* commit that's *on* that branch.  So, suppose we have this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

This drawing indicates that the branch name `branch1` holds the hash ID of commit `J`, i.e., *points to* commit `J`.  Commit `J` is therefore the *last* commit on this branch.

Similarly, `branch2` holds the hash ID of commit `L`.  Commit `L` is therefore the *last* commit on this branch.

Which branch is commit `H` on?  This is a bit of a trick question, but the diagram itself is meant as a hint:

- Note that commit `I` is on `branch1`, so the fact that `J` points back to `I` means that commit `I` is on `branch1`.  `J` is the *last* commit on `branch1` so earlier commits are also on `branch1`.
- Commit `K` is on `branch2`, by virtue of commit `L` being on `branch2`.
- Commit `H` is thus on *both branches at the same time*.  At least, it is in Git.  (Other version control systems do this differently.)

In fact, if we add a new branch name, pointing to commit `H`, like this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

that just means that commit `H` is now on *all three branches* (and is the last, or *tip*, commit on `main`).  If we *remove the name `main`*, commit `H` is now only on the remaining two branches.

**This is why—and more importantly, *when*—branch names don't matter.**  Since we can find `H` in two other ways, we *can* remove the name `main` entirely.  We'll just find `H` by starting at one of the other two branch names and working backwards.  Note, though, that we will have "forgotten" that commit `H` was supposed to be the *last* commit on `main`, once we no longer have a `main`.

#### This brings us back to your original question and a key to understanding Git

When you *clone* an existing Git repository:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git
```

for instance, your computer makes a *new* Git repository.  It then *copies all the commits* from the other Git repository—which your Git reaches by calling up their Git at the URL you give—so that you have all of their *commits* ... but it *does not copy any of their branch names yet*.

Instead, your Git has their Git list out all their branch names, along with those commit hash IDs for the tip commits of their branches.  Your Git then takes their branch names and *changes them*.  Your Git turns their *branch* names into your *remote-tracking* names,<sup>2</sup> such as `origin/main` or `origin/develop`.  It does this by sticking the *remote name* `origin` (and the slash) in front of their branch names.<sup>3</sup>

The result is that if *they* have:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

then *you* get this instead:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/branch1
         /
...--G--H   <-- origin/main
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/branch2
```

Note that at this point, you have *no branch names at all*.

Usually, the last step of `git clone` is to run `git checkout` (or in Git 2.23 and later, `git switch`).  It's this step that *creates* your `main` branch, provided you have your Git check out that name—`main`—in the first place.

When you run `git checkout main`, your Git:

- checks to see if you have a branch named `main` (no, or at least, not yet);
- if that fails, checks to see if there's a *file* named `main` (this is a drawback / bad-feature / bug in `git checkout`, corrected in `git switch`, and is the reason that the Git folks added `git switch` in Git 2.23); and finally
- goes to look for an `origin/main` that your Git could use to *create* a branch named `main`.<sup>4</sup>

This last part works, so your Git *creates* `main`, and sets it up to "track" `origin/main`: your own Git's *remote-tracking name* for some other Git's *branch* name `main`.

This kind of thing happens both on an initial `git clone` *and* on a `git checkout` that you run yourself.  That gives you:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/branch1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/branch2
```

If you now ran `git checkout branch1`, your Git would notice that there's no actual branch named `branch1`, and would end up using the *aha, there is an `origin/branch1` that I can use to create a (local) branch name `branch1` that picks out commit `J`* trick that is built in to `git checkout` and `git switch`.

Git calls this particular trick *DWIM*, which stands for *Do What I Mean:* *create* the branch, as if I ran `git checkout -b branch1 --track origin/branch1`.  It also now calls it *guessing*, and `git checkout --no-guess` tells it *not* to try the DWIM code: if you don't have a `branch1`, don't search for a remote-tracking name that can be used to *create* one.

---

<sup>2</sup>Git documentation calls these *remote-tracking branch names*.  You can use that phrase if you prefer it, and you should expect Git documentation to use it—but many humans accidentally drop the wrong word here and start saying *remote-tracking branch*, instead of *remote-tracking name*.  If you drop the redundant word *branch*, you won't make this particular mistake.  The fact is that you can't get "on" a remote-tracking name the way you get "on" a branch, so it's important to know that these aren't really *branch* names.

<sup>3</sup>You can, if you like, pick a different name than `origin` for your remote name.  A remote name is mostly a way to store the URL that you had to type earlier, so that later, you can just say `origin` instead of `ssh://...` or `https://...`.  But note that the actual remote name you pick, whatever it is, is also the string that Git sticks in front of their *branch* names.  If you choose `xyzzy` instead of `origin`, you get `xyzzy/main` and the like, instead of `origin/main` and so on.

<sup>4</sup>This process is more complicated than I'm showing here.  The details depend on your particular Git version, too.  But with a fresh clone that made an `origin/main`, that's the end result.

---

#### Growing a branch by making commits

Note that right after using DWIM mode to *create* a (local) branch name, the branch name and the remote-tracking name *both select the same commit*, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
```

Git now, however, says that you are `on branch main`.  If you run `git status`, it prints out the literal text `on branch main`.  To symbolize that in this kind of drawing, I like to attach the special name `HEAD`, written in all uppercase, to the branch name:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

If you now make a *new* commit—we won't cover the mechanics of doing this, we'll just assume that you know how to do it—Git will make you supply a *log message* for the new commit, [to explain to yourself and others *why* you made the commit](https://xkcd.com/1296/).  That commit gets a new, totally-unique hash ID.  **This hash ID cannot in use in any other Git repository anywhere**, which explains why the hash IDs are so big and ugly, and once it is yours, it cannot ever be used again either.<sup>5</sup>  But we'll just call it `I` here:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

Note how new commit `I` points backwards to existing commit `H`.

It's at this point that Git does its really big magic trick: Git writes the new hash ID for the new commit into the *branch name*, using the `HEAD` attachment to know which branch-name gets updated.  So now we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- origin/main
         \
          I   <-- main (HEAD)
```

While `HEAD` is still attached to `main`, the name `main` itself is now pointing to *new* commit `I`.

---

<sup>5</sup>Re-using a commit hash ID for a different commit doesn't break anything *if* the two Git repositories never come in contact with each other.  But in practice we never have to worry about it; it's as secure as Git's cryptographic hash function.  Well, er, um: [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)

---

#### This is why every Git repository has its own private branch names

As long as your branch names point to the same commits as your remote-tracking names, you don't *need* a branch name, at least, not yet.  You could just `git checkout origin/main`.  But this results in what Git calls a *detached HEAD*, which I draw like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- HEAD, origin/main
```

If you make a new commit in this mode, you get:

```
...--G--H   <-- origin/main
         \
          I   <-- HEAD
```

There's no *branch name* by which to find commit `I`.  **This is OK temporarily** but if you now `git checkout` something *else*, we *lose the actual hash ID of commit `I`*.  So that's why you want to be "on" a branch before you make a new commit.

(There are ways to recover from mistakes, so it's not fatal to make a commit while in detached-HEAD mode.  It's just ... *annoying*.)