# Git: How to circumvent deletion of file in one branch when tracking it in another?

Tags: git

I just encountered the following situation: I have two python files, let's call them `A.py` and `B.py`.

I initialize git and create two branches `branch-x` and `branch-y`. They don't track any files yet.

I do`(branch-x) git add B.py` and `(branch-x) git commit B.py` , but at first I do not track `A.py` because it's identical in both branches. Later on, I do `(branch-y) git add A.py` and `(branch-y) git commit A.py`, because it turns out I also have to do changes in `A.py` after all. But when I now do `git checkout branch-x` `A.py` is gone in that branch!

What I'd actually like is for that file to be tracked in all branches in the state at the time I do `git add A.py`. How can I circumvent the above behavior? Am I violating some best practices?

Comment: There isn't any "deletion". You added the file on one branch, it never existed on the other branch. `git checkout` puts in the working tree the files that exist on one branch only. You can checkout `branch-x`, use [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) to get in the working tree the file `A.py` from the other branch and add it to this branch too. The two instances of `A.py` (on the two branches) have separate lives though. Changing and committing one of them doesn't reflect on the other branch until you merge the branches (but a merge affects all the files of both branches).

Comment: Thanks, for the comment! That's kind of what I assumed was happening, but it's still somehow inconvenient. If I had 15 branches instead of branch x and y, and I'd like to add ```A.py``` to all of them, I would have to ```git restore``` it in every single one, right? Is there a way to add a file in the current state to all branches at once?

Comment: The misunderstanding comes from this statement, "but at first I do not track `A.py` because it's identical in both branches". Actually, at that point it's not "in" any branches yet and it's just following you around until you commit it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple branches to obtain that situation: add and commit a new file, then checkout the previous commit and Git will remove that file from your worktree, even if it existed before as an untracked file.

That is because, well, it was untracked. A git commit represents the whole repository at that specific version: if you choose not to track a file, then it is not considered part of that version.

You cannot easily opt-in to retroactively track a file either, because that would imply rewriting the whole history and that's generally not a good idea. Still, this can be accomplished manually by committing the file addition on its own, then using `git rebase -i --rebase-merges` to move that commit to a point in the past and rewriting the rest of history on top of it.

The actual solution is simply to track all of your repository's required files from the beginning as Git is designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

*This is long, but it's probably a good idea for at least [the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6793721/jiggy) to read it carefully.*

Let me repeat TTT's comment, which is itself important so I'll highlight it again here (and add a bit of emphasis):

> > The misunderstanding comes from this statement, "but at first I do not track `A.py` because it's identical in both branches". **Actually, at that point it's not "in" any branches yet and it's just following you around until you commit it.**

Besides this, though, you have another misunderstanding about Git that shows here:

> I initialize git and create two branches branch-x and branch-y. They don't track any files yet.

This is literally impossible (but also nonsense, and I'm not sure which of these to give priority ).  To avoid these misunderstandings, we need to go back to some basics about Git.  Let's start with two definitions:

1. A *Git repository* consists mainly of a big database of *Git commit objects* plus other supporting objects.  There's also a second (normally much smaller) database of names that exist to help you (and Git) *find* the commits because of what's in definition 2.
2. The *commit* is the central idea of Git.  It's the be-all and end-all, the [*raison d'être*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raison%20d%27%C3%AAtre) for Git's existence in the first place.  So you need to know, at a sort of deep gut understanding level, what a commit *is*, and this comes in three parts:

   - Each commit is *numbered* with a unique value called a *hash ID* or *object ID* (OID).  This thing is normally expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal); you'll see the commit numbers spill out when you run `git log`, for instance.  These numbers are huge and ugly, out of necessity: Git requires that *every* commit get a *unique* number.  Once you make a commit, that number is used up forever, for everyone, in every Git repository everywhere!<sup>1</sup>  This trick enables two Git repositories to meet, at some unspecified point in the future, and learn which commits each other have by exchanging *just the hash IDs*.  (We won't get to this part here.)
   - Every commit stores two things: (a) a full snapshot of *every* file, and (b) some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself: who made it, when, and why (their log message), for instance.

   The files *in* each commit—the commit's snapshot—are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and *de-duplicated* form.  The de-duplication deals with the fact that many, or most, commits mostly re-use most of the files from some earlier commit.  If a new commit's snapshot is 100% identical to some older commit's snapshot, the new snapshot literally takes *no* space at all.  You can get this in several ways, including if you change one file and commit, then decide to change it *back* and commit again.  In this case the only space needed in the repository is for the commit's metadata; the two commits literally *share* all their files.

This file-sharing across and even within commits is possible only because *all parts of every commit*—every internal Git object, in fact—are *completely read-only*.  Neither you nor Git itself can *change* any commit, or any file within any commit.  Not only that, most of the programs on your computer cannot *read* any of the files stored inside a commit.

This gives us a dilemma: if you can't *use* the files *in* a commit, what good are they?

---

<sup>1</sup>Git actually relies on a sort of statistical probability of uniqueness, which runs afoul of a [couple of mathematical problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).  So Git's scheme is doomed to fail someday.  The huge size of the hash puts that day off as long as necessary, ideally billions of years or more.  [The "birthday paradox" or "birthday problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) is in some ways the worst one, and Git "handles" that one by the fact that we don't normally combine *unrelated* repositories.

See also [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)

---

#### You work with *copies*

Git's answer to this is actually pretty simple, and is the same as that found in many version control / source-code management systems (VCS or SCM).  Put simply, you don't *work on a commit* at all.  The commits are inviolate—pure— abstract and removed from the programmer.  They are *off limits*.  Only the VCS itself can do anything with the *commits*.  Instead, *you* work with *copies*.

When you first *check out* some commit, in Git, Git will read all the stored files that are *in* the commit.  It will expand them out of the Git-ified form they have there, and turn them back into ordinary read/write files and put those somewhere for you.  That makes a *copy* of all the files that *were* in the commit.

These copies—the files *extracted from* the commit—go into a work area: a *working tree* or *work-tree*, which is simply the place where you do your work.  You don't work *on the commit* directly, but rather *with* the files that *came out of the commit*.

When you're done doing work with these files and wish to make a *new* commit, you tell the VCS "make a new commit".  The VCS packages up the files to be committed, adds any necessary metadata such as your name and the current date and time, and uses all of that to make the commit.  Most version control systems use this general idea, but Git gives it a twist.

#### Your working tree, Git's *index*, and tracked vs untracked files

Let's pause here for a moment and review a few things:

- Git's *commits* are in Git's object database (in the hidden `.git` folder at the top of your working tree).  These have snapshots, but they're not directly usable.  The files in the commits aren't ordinary files, and they are not stored in folders.<sup>2</sup>
- The files you work on / with *are* ordinary files, in ordinary folders.  **Git has no control over these files and folders while you work on and with them.**  This last part has something to do with why you must run `git add` so often.

This dichotomy between the version-controlled files and the working tree files means that there are literally two copies of each "current version" file: the one in the commit, and the one you're working on / with.  Many other version control systems have this same issue.  When you invoke their "commit" action (however they may spell it), they use that particular command or point-in-time as a signal that they should now *scan your working tree* to figure out what you've done.  **Git does not work this way.**

Instead, Git keeps a *third* copy of each file!  Perhaps we should say third "copy", because this extra copy, that sits *between* the committed copy and the working copy, is stored in the *compressed and de-duplicated form*.  Since the initial third "copy" of each such file came *out* of the commit you chose to start with, it must match the committed copy.  Since it's always pre-de-duplicated, and it's a duplicate, it already doesn't exist: it just shares the committed copy, invisibly.

This third copy of each file is in a thing for which Git also has three *names*.  Git calls this the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  You mostly see that third name in the form of flags, like `git rm --cached`.  The first name, "index", is kind of meaningless (which in some ways makes it the *best* name), and its synonym "staging area" refers to how you *use* it:

```
git add path/to/file.ext
```

tells Git to read the copy of `file.ext` that lives in folder `to` of folder `path` of your working tree.  Git will scan the file, *compress and de-duplicate its contents*, and then add-or-replace the *index* copy of a file named `path/to/file.ext`.<sup>3</sup>

When you first check out some commit to begin working on or with it, Git will:

- remove, from its index and your working tree, any files that are there from the *previous* commit; then
- add, to its index and your working tree, any files that must be there for the commit you'll be working on / with.

In this way, the index and your working tree now match the commit you've selected.  As you work and run `git add` on files, Git updates its index copies, so that they're ready for the *next* commit.  Then, when you *do* run `git commit`, Git can simply *package up all the index files* to go into the new commit.  As they're already in the compressed and de-duplicated *format*, it's easy for Git to store them as a new commit.

What this means, in the end, is simple enough: **Whatever is in Git's index *right now* is what Git thinks you plan to put in your *next* commit.**  As you work on files in your working tree, you *must* run `git add` on them, so as to update the index copy for your *next* commit.  So the index can be described relatively simply as *what you plan to put into your next commit*.  That's why we call it the *staging area:* you "stage" a file to make it ready for the next snapshot.  However, the stage is *pre-set* based on the *last* snapshot.  (The index takes on an expanded role during `git merge`, so it's more than *just* the staging area, but that's its main use here.)

But there's a trick here.  Your working tree can contain files that *are not in the index*.  Why are they not in the index?  **There's one obvious possibility: perhaps you just created that file, just now.  In this case the file is *not in Git* and maybe has *never been in Git*.  It's just there in your working tree.**  This is the case, initially, for your `A.py` file.

There's a second possibility, which we should cover now, though you didn't use it.  You can tell Git *remove the file `path/to/file.ext` from your index*.  You normally do this with `git rm`, and normally, when you use `git rm`, you tell Git to remove *both* the index copy *and* your working-tree copy.  So now it's absent from both places.  But you can tell Git *not *to remove the working tree copy at all, using `git rm --cached path/to/file.ext`.  Now there's a working tree copy, but no index copy.

The important thing to note at this point is this: **Regardless of how we arrive at this condition, it is possible to have a file in your working tree that has no corresponding copy in Git's index.  When this is the case, Git calls that file an *untracked file.***  So an untracked file is, by definition, a file that *isn't* in Git's index, and a tracked file is, by definition, a file that *is* in Git's index.  This is all very simple, but there's one hitch: you can't *see* what's in Git's index directly.<sup>4</sup>  Instead, we use `git status` to see what's in Git's index *indirectly*.

Running `git status` produces output like this:

```
On branch main
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   scanner.go

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   reader.go

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        reader_test.go
```

This displays a lot of information in a fairly compact form.  We can get the same information even more compactly with `git status --short` (though this leaves out the `on branch main` part by default):

```
 M reader.go
M  scanner.go
?? reader_test.go
```

Note that the *position* of the `M` character is different for `reader.go` (unstaged) and `scanner.go` (staged) here.  They also have different colors (but this doesn't show up in plain StackOverflow text).

What Git is doing is *comparing things:*

- First, Git compares the *current commit's files* to the *staged files*.  Most of them are the same, so Git says nothing at all about these.  One of them is different: `scanner.go` is different, so Git says that this file is `staged for commit`.  In other words, I edited `scanner.go`, but then I *also* ran `git add scanner.go`, so now the index copy matches the working tree copy, and both differ from the committed copy.
- Then, Git compares what's in the index—the staged files—to your working tree.  Here, most of them are the same, including `scanner.go`, but `reader.go` is different in the index and in the working tree.  That's because I modified `reader.go` but have not yet run `git add reader.go`.  So the committed copy and the index copy match—it wasn't mentioned in the "to be committed" section, in the long output—but the index and working tree copies differ, so it's `not staged for commit`.
- Last, I *created* `reader_test.go` and have not run `git add` on it yet.  So it's not in Git's index at all, but it is there in my working tree.  The `status` command therefore *complains* about it.  This fact actually shows up in the second comparison, but Git holds off the complaints until after it finishes listing any "not staged for commit" files.

In the short status form, the staged-for-commit `M` status shows up in column 1, the not-staged-for-commit `M` status shows up in column 2, and the `untracked` status shows up as the two question marks in both columns.  You can get both columns 1 and 2 to show an `M` status: just check out some commit, modify some file, `git add` that file, and then *modify the file again*.  Now *all three copies* differ, so you'll get two `M` (modified) status fields.

If I were to `git add reader_test.go`, that would put a *new* file into the index.  Running `git status` will show this as a newly added file, `to be committed`, or a letter-`A` in column 1.  Again, this is all based on the *state* of things when I run `git status`: at this point, there would be *no* file named `reader_test.go` in the *commit*, but the two other copies, in Git's index and my working tree, would match.  So the difference between the *current commit* and the *proposed next commit* includes "add this file", and the difference between the proposed next commit and the working tree, for this particular file, is "no difference, so don't mention it".

---

<sup>2</sup>If you want to explore this idea further, look into *loose vs packed objects* and the difference between a *tree object* and a *blob object* in Git.  Loose objects are in individual files, but they don't have normal file names, and packed objects are crammed together into a single file with [delta compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) applied.  Your ordinary working tree files do have a correspondence to blob objects, which map 1-to-1 to *loose* files but many-to-one in *pack* files.  It's relatively easy to read a loose object file—once you know which object name you want—but much trickier to extract the desired object from a pack file.

<sup>3</sup>Note that files *in* the index are not in folders: they just have path names that include forward slashes.  This is true even on Windows: if your file is in `path\to\file.ext` in your working tree, it's still under the name `path/to/file.ext`—one file name, no folders, with forward rather than backward slashes—in Git's index.

<sup>4</sup>Actually, you *can* see what's in Git's index, using `git ls-files`, typically with `--stage`.  But for a big repository, this produces a huge and therefore largely useless list of files.

---

#### The trickiest part: a new repository is *empty*

When you run `git init` to create a new `.git` directory containing a new Git repository, you've told Git to create the two repository databases.  Remember those from our first definition:

- There's a commits-and-other-objects database.  It is *empty:* no commits exist, and there are no supporting objects for all zero of those (lack of) commits.
- There are no branch names, no tag names, no other names at all.  We didn't cover this earlier, but each name stores *exactly one hash ID*.  A *branch* name in particular stores the hash ID of the *latest* commit for that branch.

Since there are no commits, there cannot be any branch names.  You can't create *any* branch name—not `branch-x`, not `branch-y`, not `main` or `master`, nothing—until there is *at least one commit*.

Let's make a new empty Git repository and observe this effect:

```
$ mkdir tt && cd tt
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .../tt/.git/
$ git branch branch-x
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.
$ git branch
$
```

There are no branches!  That's why `git branch` printed nothing.  And yet:

```
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

I'm "on" branch `master`, even though branch `master` doesn't exist.  And if I use `git switch --orphan`, I can change which non-existent branch I'm on.  Note that I need the `--orphan` flag:

```
$ git switch main
fatal: invalid reference: main
$ git switch --orphan main
Switched to a new branch 'main'
$ git branch
$ git status
$ git status
On branch main

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
$
```

Is that weird, or is that weird?  But the fact is, you can't have a branch name until you have commits, and yet you can have a *current* branch name when you have no commits.  It's just that this current branch name doesn't exist!

The trick here is that Git will *create* that branch name *when you make the first commit*.  So let's make a commit:

```
$ git commit
On branch main

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
$
```

Whoops!  It turns out that we can't *make* an *empty* commit!<sup>5</sup>  So what we'll probably do—what I often do for instance—is create an initial file, maybe just a `README`, and commit *that:*

```
$ echo just for illustration > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
[main (root-commit) 96800d2] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$
```

Now that I have one commit, *now* I can create new branch names:

```
$ git branch branch-x
$ git branch branch-y
$ git branch
  branch-x
  branch-y
* main
```

Running `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`, we see that this one commit has all three branch names pointing to it:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 96800d2 (HEAD -> main, branch-y, branch-x) Initial commit
$
```

But this commit *does* have one tracked file, namely `README`.  So to create two new branch names, I had to create one file, make it tracked (`git add` it to copy it into Git's index), run `git commit` to create my first commit and hence my initial branch.  My initial branch name is now `main`, since I changed the name of the nonexistent branch before I made it exist; the `git commit` created the branch name and that very-first commit.

The very first commit in any Git repository is at least a little bit special, because of this bootstrapping issue.  So if you use GitHub or some other hosting site to create a repository, they will often *fill in* an initial commit *for you*, containing some initial file(s) such as a README, LICENSE, Copyright, etc., and maybe the misleadingly-named `.gitignore`.

Once you have the first commit, and its corresponding branch name, *then* you can make more branch names.  But they'll have tracked files—or rather, the *commit* they *select* will have some files, and when you *check out* that commit, with `git switch` or `git checkout`, those files will be tracked.

---

<sup>5</sup>You *can* make an empty commit, using `git commit --allow-empty`.  The `--allow-empty` flag really tells Git: *Let me make this commit now even though there's nothing new.*  When you do this from a commit that has files, you get another commit that just re-uses the existing snapshot.  When you do this in this special initial-no-files-no-commits setup here, you get a truly empty commit, one whose snapshot is the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452).  But people normally don't do that, and the phrase *empty commit* in Git normally means "a commit that matches the previous one". There is one valid reason for making this kind of "empty" (really, matching) commit, and that's to have a new unique hash ID for a new tag: see my answer to [Select Git tag from a "list"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72085518/1256452) once I create it.

---

#### Summary, or, what you've learned here

In bullet-point form:

- A *Git repository* consists mainly of commits and supporting objects, stored in Git's object database, plus some names—branch names, tag names, and the like.  The commits are numbered and hold snapshots and metadata, and the names help you find the commits.
- A *branch name* exists to help you (and Git) find the *latest* commit on the branch.  We have not gone into the mechanism here, but that's what it does.  What this means is that the branch name *selects* **one particular commit**.  For the name to exist, there must be a commit for it to select.
- *Checking out* a commit *fills in* Git's index / staging-area, and your working tree, from the files that are *in* that commit's snapshot.  It first *removes* from the index and your working tree any files that are there because of some previously-checked-out commit.  It *does not disturb* files that are sitting around in your working tree, but are not in either the commit you're moving off of, or the commit you're moving to.
- An *untracked file* is one that is not in Git's index *right now*.  The index contents can and do change: you can `git add`, you can `git rm`, and you can switch from commit to commit.  So the set of files that are tracked also can and does change.  But at any time, if some file exists in your working tree *right now*, and isn't in Git's index *right now*, that file is untracked.  If that file *is* in Git's index *right now*, that file is tracked.
- Files that are in your working tree—the copies that aren't in Git's index or the current commit—aren't *in Git* at all!  At most, they *came out of Git*, and if you `git add` and `git commit` they'll go *into* Git.  But the copies in your working tree are *yours* to futz with, up until you choose to switch commits, or decide to use a Git command that uses or changes your working tree contents, such as `git add` or `git rm` or `git restore`.
- The index or staging area holds your *proposed next commit*.  Use `git add` or `git rm` to update your proposal.

  If you want Git to *save* a file *into the next snapshot*, use `git add` on that file.  If the file came out of the current snapshot, Git will replace the tracked copy with an updated tracked copy.  If the file wasn't tracked before, Git will copy the file into Git's index, and now it's tracked.

  If you want Git to *omit* the file *from the next snapshot* even though it's tracked, use `git rm` to remove both the index and working tree copies of that file.  Note that when Git compares the previous snapshot (which has the file) to the new snapshot (once you make it), Git will say that this file has been "deleted", *even if you used `--cached`* when you ran `git rm`.  It's important to remember that the file in the *old* commit is stuck there forever: no commit can ever be changed!  If you ever check out the old commit, Git will copy the old version of the file out into your working tree.

There is a lot more to learn—in particular, the next thing to learn is that branch *names* don't really matter to Git; what matter are the *commits*—but this is a good starting point.