# Workflow when working on GitHub fork for PR requests

Tags: git, github

Know there is a lot of Q/A on this, but I'm still very uncertain on how to proceed.

---

*(Based on a real story!)*

Say there is a public project named `unicorns` by `danny`. To make pull requests one are to work from own fork of project.

### Basic setup

So one do a fork on GitHub's web-site to ones own profile.

Then locally get a clone of that one + set it up with the project to get updates:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/MyUser/unicorns.git
$ cd unicorns
$ git remote add danny git@github.com:danny/unicorns.git
```

To get an up to date local copy:

```
$ git checkout main
$ git pull danny main
```

### Creating pull requests

Then one gets to work. Starting with creating a branch:

```
$ git checkout -b my_work_1

# Do some changes and commit locally
$ git commit -am "I changed this"

# Push the changes to ones copy on GitHub
$ git push -u origin my_work_1
```

Then proceed with creating a PR from the GitHub website.

Then do a second PR they wanted right away:

```
# Check out main as not to include my_work_1 in this branch:
$ git checkout main

# Create new branch for second work
$ git checkout -b my_work_2

# Do some changes and commit locally
$ git commit -am "I changed this as well"

# Push the changes to ones copy on GitHub
$ git push -u origin my_work_2
```

Then proceed with creating a PR from the GitHub website.

---

### Trouble starts

So far so good. (I hope, lol)

The PR's are accepted and merged into `main` of the project.

**But then next day:**

```
$ git checkout main
$ git pull danny main
```

Now it say my main branch is ahead by 40 commits. In my local tree I see something like:

```
+ main-remotes/danny/unicorns Last thing done
+ Some commit
+ Some commit
: .. 35 more
+ My commit work 2  (No 39)
+ My commit work 1  (No 40)
|/ Branch my_work_2
|/ Branch my_work_1
+ remotes/origin/main Some commit
+ Some commit
:
```

---

There seems to be as many solutions as questions on this. I am wondering what is going on and how to proceed. Have read a lot of the Q/A's on the topic etc.

I have a myriad of questions but the gist of some:

1. Did I do something wrong above?
2. Is it my two local branches `my_work_1` and `my_work_2` that is the reason for the message? Hasn't those been merged (or smash merged as some said) into the `main` of the real repository?
3. Do I have to delete those branches before doing a `pull`?

   - `git branch -d my_work_1`
   - `git branch -d my_work_2`
4. What if I create a branch where I do some work that I want to push on a later date, but still wants to push other changes? Do I have to tell git to ignore these somehow?
5. Is it in general an OK workflow (once I understand how to handle the above)?

Suspect I have to update *my fork* on GitHub to the `main` of where it was forked from. Perhaps that is the issue. If so how? Simply `push main`?

Comment: `git rebase` is your friend: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

Comment: @Cyclonecode Thanks. That looks good for pt. 4. I.e. work on a branch over time. But still not sure how to solve the ones I have already pushed. I.e. `my_work_1` and `my_work_2`. Guess I need to get my remote ***fork*** (as it is that one I am working with) updated to main branch of *the source project* (`danny/unicorns`). But not sure what to do with my two branches, or what happens to them, in that scenario. If I do a `push -u origin main` that would result in the same issue on the *fork* as well I guess. (I.e. it will keep my forks and make the `unicorns` HEAD the HEAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Did I do something wrong above?

No.

> 2. Is it my two local branches `my_work_1` and `my_work_2` that is the reason for the message?

Which message?  Do you mean *Do these explain the `git log` output?*  The answer to that is both no and yes, or more precisely, yes-but-only-partly.  See (much) more below.

> Hasn't those been merged (or smash merged as some said) into the main of the real repository?

Merged, *squash*-merged, or rebase-and-merged, yes.  These three terms are the three ways GitHub offer the holder of the "upstream" repository of your fork, i.e., the original `unicorns`.  GitHub give `danny` these three options.  He has one big green button with a pulldown next to it; using the pulldown, he can select <kbd>MERGE</kbd>, <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd>, or <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd>.  Depending on *which option he uses*, you'll see different effects.

> 3. Do I have to delete [`my_work_1` and `my_work_2`] before doing a pull?

No.  You *can* delete them at any time.  Those two names simply give you an easy way to find your commits' hash IDs.  When you stop wanting to find those hash IDs, delete the names.

> 4. What if I create a branch where I do some work that I want to push on a later date, but still wants to push other changes? Do I have to tell git to ignore these somehow?

You can do whatever you like here.  The trick is just to know what you're seeing: see below.

> 5. Is it in general an OK workflow (once I understand how to handle the above)?

Yes.

#### What you're seeing is (a representation of) reality

A Git repository—*any* Git repository—mostly contains *commits*.  The commits are, by and large, the interesting thing.  Git stores these commits in a big database that Git calls its *object database* or *object store:* this thing is a simple [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), where the keys are raw hash IDs.  You'll see the commit hash IDs, or abbreviated versions of them, in `git log` output.

Besides commits, there are three other types of objects in the database, but we tend not to interact with them much, and hardly ever need *their* hash IDs.  We do occasionally need to use those raw hash IDs to have Git pull out some particular commit of interest, though.  That's because they are, in effect, the true names of the commits.  Every commit has a *unique* hash ID, and that hash ID means *that commit*, and only that commit.  The problem with these hash IDs is that they are big, ugly, and seemingly-random.

Besides the commits, then, the repository proper also contains a name-to-hash-ID lookup database: another simple key-value store, where the key is the name and the value is a hash ID.  The names are branch names like `main`, tag names like `v1.2`, and *remote-tracking names* like `origin/main` or `main-remotes/danny/unicorns`.  The values stored under these names are hash IDs, with each name storing exactly *one* hash ID: one is enough.

(I say "repository proper" here to distinguish these two databases plus the ancillary files that Git needs from your *working tree* files, which some people like to call "part of the repository", but which I like to say aren't *in* the repository, because, well, they aren't!  Also, the names *in* this database have full-name spellings: for instance, `main` is really `refs/heads/main`, it's just been abbreviated for display to drop the `refs/heads/` part, which is the part that makes it a *branch* name.  The remote-tracking names all start with `refs/remotes/`, which is what makes them remote-tracking names.  Tags, if you have any, start with `refs/tags/`, which ... well, you get the idea, I hope.)

Every commit has two parts: a *full snapshot of every source file*, and some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  The `git log` command normally uses only the metadata to show you what has happened, while a command like `git checkout` or `git switch` needs the saved snapshot to populate a working tree.

One of the keys to making Git work is that the metadata for any one commit contains a list of *previous commit hash IDs*.  This list is most often just one element long, giving us an *ordinary commit:* one that's neither a merge commit, nor the initial commit.  We call these the *parents* (or usually, parent, singular) of the commit.  This is how `git log` can show history.

**History, in a Git repository, is nothing more or less than the set of commits we find in the repository.**  Each commit "points backwards" to a previous commit—or, for *merge* commits, to two or more previous commits—and that's why a *name* can just store one commit hash ID!  We can draw this, using single uppercase letters to stand in for commit hash IDs, like this, with newer commits towards the right:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch
```

Here, `H` is the *latest* commit "on the branch".  The name *branch* "points to" (contains the hash ID of) the commit whose hash we're just calling `H`.  Commit `H` contains a snapshot and metadata, and its metadata points to (contains the hash ID of) earlier commit `G`.  Commit `G`, being a commit, points to earlier commit `F`, which continues pointing backwards.

Your `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` output (or similar transcription) does the same thing as I just did, but draws the commits vertically, with newer commits towards the top.  Here's another one—some snippets from an actual repository of mine:

```
* dcebed7 (HEAD -> main) reader, scanner: add whitespace as a token
* acf005a reader, scanner: handle more of the grammar
* 7409df3 file: provide Is() for file errors
```

The branch name finds the *latest* commit, and from there, Git works backwards.

**Every commit hash ID is unique.**  That is, every time you make a *new* commit, the *new* commit gets a new, unique, never-before-used-in-any-Git-repository, never-can-be-used-again hash ID.<sup>1</sup>

**No commit, once made, can ever be changed.**  In fact, that's true for all of Git's internal objects.  The hash ID is not at all random.  Instead, it is the output of some hashing function, preferably a cryptographically-strong one (currently mostly SHA-1, which [is no longer quite so strong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)).  If you copy a commit object out of the objects database, change even a single bit anywhere in that object, and put it back, you get a *new and different hash ID* for a *new and different commit*.  The old commit remains in the database and one can still have Git pull it up by its hash ID.  The new hash ID finds the new commit, the old one finds the old commit, and both commits now exist.

**We do this sort of thing—*copy* a commit while changing something—from time to time, and that's what you're running into here.**

---

<sup>1</sup>[This cannot work forever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) and *someday* Git will break, but the sheer size of the hash output (and its cryptographic strength) help to put that day off as long as possible—long enough, we hope, that nobody will care.

---

#### Clones, forks, and generally distributing repositories

When you *clone* a Git repository using `git clone` from the command line, you are:

1. creating a new, empty Git repository: one with no commits, no branches, nothing inside it;
2. having your Git software reach out to some other Git software: your Git software uses your Git repository and theirs uses theirs and I'll just call these "your Git" and "their Git";
3. have *their* Git list out all their branch names and hence their most-recent commits' hash IDs; and
4. have *your* Git use this information to get *all* their commits: the most recent, the parents, the grandparents, ad infinitum until they get all the way back to the very first commit ever.

You now have a repository with all their *commits*, but *no branches*.  That's okay!  Your Git is going to find (their, now yours as well) commits not by their *branch names*, but rather by your *remote-tracking names*.  Your Git now takes each of their *branch* names, such as `main`, and slaps the *remote name* `origin` in front.  (Technically your Git takes the full name, `refs/heads/main`, and changes it to the full name `refs/remotes/origin/main`, but with Git normally displaying this with `refs/heads/` and `refs/remotes/` stripped off, it looks like your Git is adding `origin/`.)

You now have a *remote-tracking name* for every one of their *branch* names, and because remote-tracking names work just as well as branch names, you have a way to find all the commits, just like they do.<sup>2</sup>

Last, your `git clone` creates one (1) *new* branch name—one `refs/heads/`-style name—in your repository, to remember a single latest commit.  Which name does your Git use?  The one you specified with your `-b` option—or, if you didn't specify a `-b` option, the name the *other* Git software recommends (which mostly winds up being `main` these days, though you'll see `master` in a lot of older repositories, and a few oddballs do something of their own).  The commit *your* name remembers will be the same commit *their* name remembers, so your `main` will identify the same commit as your `origin/main`, which is your Git's memory of their Git's `main`.

That's kind of a long way around, but that's how you get your first branch from `git clone`.  Having created that *branch name*, your Git software now does a `git switch` *to* that branch, to check out all the files from the snapshot in question.  This fills in your *working tree* and *staging area* (or *index* or *cache*), but we won't go into these details here.

**GitHub forks are clones, but with a few special features.**  When you use the GitHub <kbd>FORK</kbd> button, you're getting *GitHub* to make a clone *on* GitHub.  They (GitHub) *like it when you do this* because they "cheat", using an internal Git thing called "alternates", to avoid actually copying any objects in the big all-Git-objects database.  You do, however, get your own copy of the *names* database, and here we hit the first difference from a `git clone`-style clone:

- When GitHub do a "fork", they copy the branch names straight through.  So if `unicorns` has five branches when you mash the <kbd>FORK</kbd> button, *you* have five branches in your fork.  This is true even if they immediately add and/or delete some branches right after you mash the button: your branches are an at-the-time-snapshot of theirs.  From now on those names are in *your* repository on GitHub; it's up to you to update them.

  (This is also why there are no remote-tracking names on GitHub.)
- Besides the change to the way the branch names are handled, GitHub link your fork to the original repository, so that you can make pull requests and the like.

That's pretty much all you need to know and care about here.  When you `git clone` your GitHub fork to your laptop (or other computer, but I'll call it a "laptop" to distinguish it from a GitHub server computer), you'll generally want to `git remote add` the URL for the repository you forked.  You can then `git fetch` from *both* repositories, which as we'll see in a moment is how you synchronize.

---

<sup>2</sup>If they had some remote-tracking names, you've "lost" those, but it turns out GitHub never bother with remote-tracking names in the first place.

---

#### Fetch and push

Now that we have two, or three or maybe a thousand or whatever, Git repositories that are all related by cloning, we have the problem of synchronizing our repositories.  What if someone else has made new commits?  If we want to *get* their new commits, we use `git fetch`.  The `fetch` command takes a *remote*—those short names like `origin`, where we've stored a URL—and *calls up the Git that responds at that URL*.  We're back to "our Git" and "their Git", just like we were during cloning:

- our Git has them list out their branch (and other) names to get hash IDs;
- our Git checks to see if we have the same hash IDs: if so, we have the same commits, if not, we're missing some commits;
- our Git asks their Git for the hash IDs we *don't* have (and their Git is obligated to provide the parent hash IDs, which our Git can ask for, and this repeats);
- and now we have all the commits they have, plus any of our own.

In fact, this is the *same process that `git clone` used initially* and it ends the same way: now that we know the hash IDs of *their* branches, we can create or update each of our *remote-tracking names* using those hash IDs (provided we downloaded those commits: you can tell `git fetch` to skip some of them, and then our corresponding remote-tracking branches won't update either).

In summary (and with caveats), **`git fetch` gets any new commits *they* have that we don't, and updates our remote-tracking names**.  You give `git fetch` a *remote*, like `origin`, and it goes there and gets stuff from them.  If you have only one remote—as many people do—you can stop there; if you have more than one, I recommend using `git remote update` to update from each, but you can use `git fetch --all` to fetch from *all* remotes.  Just be careful with `--all`: see below.

Suppose we've made new commits and we would like to give those new commits *to* them?  Here, we use `git push`.  This is as close as Git gets to the opposite of `git fetch`, but there are several key differences:

- First, we tell our Git *what to push*, usually by branch name.  Our Git looks up the commit hash ID from the branch name: that's the commit we need to send them, if they don't have it.  We must also send them all the history *behind* that commit that they don't have.
- Second, whenever we're pushing, we don't get to use a "remote-tracking name".  Instead, *we ask their Git to set one of their branch names*.  Usually we want to use the same name on both "sides", and if we use a branch name in our `git push`, that's the name we want on both sides.

So we run `git push origin main` to send *new* commits we have from the most recent one on our `main`, and then we ask them, politely, to set *their* `main` to remember the latest such commit.

If we are the only one sending commits *to* them, we can be pretty sure about when we're adding commits, but sometimes this doesn't work so well.  This is an inherently sticky problem if we're *not* the only one sending them new commits!  Still, `fetch` and `push` are as close as Git gets to opposites, here.

#### General observations about diverging branches

It's time to step back a bit and consider what happens even if we, on our own, decide to use multiple branches.  Suppose we have a very simple repository with just one branch, whose last commit is `H`, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Because we're about to have more than one branch, we've added `HEAD` to our drawings to show *which name we're using to find a commit*.  We now create another branch name, `br1`.  As in all cases in Git, this name *must select some commit*.  Let's have it select the most recent `main` commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, main (HEAD)
```

Note that *all the commits*—everything up through `H`—*are on both branches*.  Let's create a third name, `br2`, too:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, br2, main (HEAD)
```

Now we'll run `git switch br1` so that any *new work* we do will be "on branch `br1`" once we commit it.  (*Note that work we haven't committed is not in Git,* because the working tree is not actually *in* Git.)  We get this:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), br2, main
```

We're still *using commit H`;* we're just doing so *via the name` br1`.  So nothing else changes, and in fact Git doesn't even touch any of our working tree files.

We do some work and commit it, which makes a *new commit*, which gets a new, unique hash ID.  We'll call this commit `I` and draw it in:

```
          I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

The sneaky thing that Git has done here is that it has *stored the new commit's hash ID in the name `br1`* (to which `HEAD` is attached).  That is, the name `br1` now finds commit `I`, instead of commit `H`!  But commit `I` points backwards *to* commit `H`, because when we made `I`, `H` *was* the current commit.  Now `I` is the current commit.

If we make a second commit, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

and all is fine.  We can now `git switch br2`: Git will rip out all the commit-`J` files from our working tree and replace them with commit-`H` files; the committed files are safely saved forever in commit `I`, and we now have:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2 (HEAD), main
```

We now make a new commit, as usual.  The new commit gets a new, unique hash ID, but we'll just call it `K`; and `K` points back to `H`, because we're on commit `H` when we run `git commit`, so now we have:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

If we repeat for a new commit `L`, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

An interesting thing about Git is that it will claim that commits up through `H` are on *all three branches*.  In a way, it's better to think of commits as being "contained in" some set of branches.  The set of branches that *contain* any given commit are those branches where, by starting from the commit selected by the branch name, we can *find* that commit as we work backwards.

Because *branch names* simply find the *last commit in the branch*, we can now, if we like, tell Git to move the name `main` forward to point to, say, commit `J`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1, main
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

(We don't have to be "on" the branch to move it, and in some ways it's easier to move a name around when we're *not* "on" it, so I left `HEAD` attached to `br2` in the drawing.  The set of commands we can use to move a branch name depends on whether we're "on" the branch, which is ... kind of an annoying thing about Git, really, but it is what it is.)

Once we've done this, though, note that moving the name `main` to point to commit `L` causes commits `I-J` to *stop being on `main`:*

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD), main
```

We can *either* have commits `I-J` be on `main`, *or* have commits `K-L` be on main, at this point.  We can't get *both sets of commits* onto `main` **at this time**.

It's easy enough to get both sets of commits onto `main` by making a new commit `M` of type *merge commit*.  A merge commit is a commit with two or more parents—usually exactly two—and if we do make such a commit, we can set things up like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- main (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

*If and when we do create commit `M`*, and make `main` point to it, we won't need the *names* `br1` and/or `br2` any more to find commits `J` and `L`.  Git will be able to find them on its own, by stepping back one hop from `M`.

To create merge commit `M`, though, we must run `git merge`.  The `git push` command can't create `M` for us.  Why does this matter?  Well, if we are the only person who ever creates commits, we can arrange things so that it *doesn't* matter.  But what happens if we're pushing to some *shared* repository, where we don't control who pushes, and when?

#### `git push` and "non-fast-forward"

Suppose that both Alice and Bob have clones of some centralized repository.  Alice creates a new commit or two on her `main` and uses `git push origin main`; meanwhile Bob is creating a new commit or two on his `main`, and doesn't have Alice's commits.

At this point, the *centralized* repository has:

```
          I--J   <-- main
         /
...--G--H
```

where there's no obvious reason for the kink in the graph—but I've put it in because *Bob* is, or was, still back at `H`, where both Alice *and* Bob were just a short while ago.  Bob makes his new commits and gets:

```
...--G--H   <-- origin/main
         \
          K--L   <-- main
```

in *his* repository.  When he runs `git push origin main`, his Git calls up `origin`'s and sends over commits `J-K`, which now look like this:

```
          I--J   <-- main
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- [bob asks, politely, to set "main" here]
```

What happens now is simple enough: they just refuse, telling Bob's Git that if they did that, they'd "lose" commits `I-J`.  This shows up at Bob's end as a "non-fast-forward" error.

If Bob could push to a new branch (`bob`), that would be fine.  Then it might be possible to do the merge *on GitHub*.  I say *might* because some merges are easy—they have no conflicts—and some aren't.  GitHub originally wouldn't do any conflicted merges at all, though they are gradually making GitHub more feature-<s>ridden</s> er rich here.<sup>3</sup>

Some people, however, don't like merges.  This is one place that `git rebase` comes in.  Git's "squash merge", represented by the GitHub <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd> button, also comes into play here.  GitHub's <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> button is strongly related, but it's ... well, let's just get on with rebase now.

---

<sup>3</sup>Seriously, there's nothing wrong with fancier tools.  Just remember Scotty's Dictum, "The more they fancy up the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain."

---

#### Rebasing

As I mentioned above, we will sometimes copy a commit in order to improve it.  The *simplest* Git command for copying a commit is `git cherry-pick`, which is often used like this:

```
git switch somebranch       # switch to some branch
git cherry-pick a123456     # commit hash ID from `git log`
```

The `cherry-pick` operation *copies the effect of the given commit*.  That is, commit `a123456`, in this case, has a snapshot, and has a (single) parent—we normally only copy ordinary single-parent commits—and if we have Git compare the parent's snapshot with `a123456`'s snapshot, there's some set of changes that we (or whoever) made.

To achieve the cherry-pick operation, Git uses its internal *merge machinery* to make the *same set of changes* to our current commit, which in this case would be the most recent commit on `somebranch`.  Hence, if we had a graph like this:

```
          o--P--C--o--o   <-- branch-xyz
         /
...--o--o
         \
          o--o--H   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

and commit `C` is the `a123456` one whose hash ID we gave to `git cherry-pick`, Git will compare the snapshot in `P` (`C`'s parent) to the snapshot in `C`, to see what changed in that commit.

In order to *apply the same change*, Git needs to compare the snapshot in `P` to that in `H`.  That way, if commit `H` has the same code in it that `P` does, but it's been moved around within a file, or maybe even moved to a *different file*, Git can (usually) figure out where the code went.  Then Git can apply the change to the correct snapshot-`H` file, at the correct line(s).  This operation is, technically speaking, exactly the same thing Git does for a full-blown `git merge`: that happens to do exactly the right thing here.  (Of course, because it *is* a merge, it can have *merge conflicts*, but as long as the code in snapshot `H` is sufficiently similar to that in snapshots `P` and `C`, that's not too likely.  And if it *does* occur, we probably have to think about what might need to be altered in the `P`-vs-`C` change anyway.)

Having made the same *change*, `git cherry-pick` goes on to copy most of the metadata from the original commit: it saves the original commit's log message, and even keeps the original commit's author.  It makes us the *committer* though, and then makes a new commit that's "just as good as" the original, but which adds on to our current branch:

```
          o--P--C--o--o   <-- branch-xyz
         /
...--o--o
         \
          o--o--H--C'  <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

Looking at commits `C` and `C'`, we'll mostly "see" the same thing, even if we include displaying a patch for the two commits.  The *hash IDs* will differ, though, and of course commit `C'` is on *our* branch.

Now suppose we take the Alice-and-Bob situation and look at this as a case of just needing to copy the commits:

```
          I--J   <-- alice-main
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- bob
```

Suppose we *copy* `K` to a new-and-improved `K'` whose biggest change—maybe even only change, in some ways—is that it comes *after `J`*, and then copy `L` to a new-and-improved `L'` in the same way:

```
          I--J   <-- alice-main
         /    \
...--G--H      K'-L'  <-- bob-version-2 (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- bob
```

We can now *abandon* the original `K-L` commits in favor of the new and improved `K'-L'` pair.  To do that, we have Git forcibly yank the name `bob` over to point to `L'`, and delete the temporary `bob-version-2` name:

```
          I--J   <-- alice-main
         /    \
...--G--H      K'-L'  <-- bob (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   ???
```

We no longer have any *name* by which to find commit `L`.  It will *seem to be gone* from our repository!  It's still there, it's just that `git log --all` or `git log --branches` uses the *branch names* to get started, and there is no branch name that starts us looking at `L` any more.

If we're not paying attention, it even looks like commits `K-L` have somehow changed.  They haven't: there are instead *new* commits.  But we can now `git push origin bob:main` (to throw some never-before-shown syntax at you ), meaning *send our commit `L'`, and therefore `K'` too, and then ask `origin` to set *their* `main` to point to `L'`*.

**People use `git rebase` all the time to avoid using `git merge`.**  Whether that's a *good idea* is a matter of opinion, but people do it and you should know how to do it.  The `git rebase` command lets you do this without using multiple `git cherry-pick` and `git reset` commands.  (I won't go into further details here as this answer is already very long.)

#### GitHub's <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> does a rebase

The GitHub <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> button always does this kind of rebase.  The end result is that someone else (probably `danny`) is listed as the *committer* of the new (copied) commits; you're listed as the *author* of those new copied commits.  The new commits are different commits, so they have different hash IDs.

It's possible for someone doing this to *break something*.  It's pretty rare (especially when using the button, which won't work in the case of merge conflicts during the cherry-picking) but not everything Git does fully-automated is correct.  So you *might* want to hang on to your original commits.  It's up to you to decide when *you* want to abandon your original commits.

#### We can now get back to your item 4

> 4. What if I create a branch where I do some work that I want to push on a later date, but still wants to push other changes? Do I have to tell git to ignore these somehow?

The `git push` command *sends commits* (only).  It does not copy them to different commits; it does not do merges or rebases.  It sends the commits, by their hash ID, to some other Git repository.  Assuming the other Git accepts the "update some name" request, those commits will be bit-for-bit identical to your original commits, and therefore they *are* the same commits, located in the same position in the same commit graph.

Note that the parent commit of the first commit in that chain of commits that you've just sent *must* be present.  So, for instance, if someone else used <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> to *copy* your commits to new-and-(supposedly-)improved commits, and you `git push` commits that add on to your original chain, you're preserving your original commits along with this chain.

In general, this means that if you want to *cooperate with* someone who has rebased your commits, you must rebase any *additional* commits that were based on those commits.  Doing this can be easy—Git has a mechanism for dropping "matching" commits automatically—or hard, depending on whether they made any changes to your commits.

(Because this is extra work for them, and also extra work for you, most GitHub users will request that you first do your own rebase.  That will *mostly* solve some of the harder cases.  It would be rather pleasing to me if GitHub would take such rebased commits as-is, instead of rebasing your rebased commits unnecessarily a second time, but GitHub's button always does an extra rebase step.  This leaves a few—very few, very rare—cases where things don't work so nicely and automatically.)

The bottom line, which I hope I can squeeze in here, is this: **Rebasing engenders more rebasing.**  You will find yourself doing `git rebase` a lot.

Comment: Could you elaborate? (Just kidding :P) – Thanks a lot. I have to use some time reading over this. To make it easier I made it into a LaTeX (for PDF / print): https://www.overleaf.com/read/cyqrfxhcmdpt