# Git commiting to different remote repos

Tags: git, github

I unfortunately have little to no experience with Git as for years I have used alternative offline source control products.

I have inherited a project which is managed through Github and I am just trying to work out the best practice for managing two separate repos (staging and production).

I have setup two different remotes, lets call them "origin" and "prod". Origin is pointing to the staging repo and "prod" pointing to the production repo.

I understand that I can select the remote I wish to "push" to:

```
git push origin main
```

But taking a step back from the push, when I add and commit, these aren't tied back to a repo. So is there a way I can group commit changes for specific repos?

For example,

```
git add README.md
git commit -am "FIRST COMMIT"

git add test1234.html
git add test5678.html
git commit -am "SECOND COMMIT"
```

Can I push both of these commits to the "origin" repo and just the first commit to the "prod" repo?

Comment: You are not _visualizing_ what goes on in git correctly. What you push into remotes are _branches_.... and branches are made up of commits one after the other (what you commit locally).... so, what you want to get is _the right sequence of commits_ in (two? I would assume) branches so that you can push each one to a separate repo.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I push both of these commits to the "origin" repo and just the first commit to the "prod" repo?

Yes, but not sustainably long-term.

Here's the first set of things you need to know when using Git:

- A Git repository is, at its heart, two databases:

  - One database contains commits and other internal Git objects.  Each commit stores, indirectly, *all* the files that go with that particular commit; we'll talk about this more in a moment; but this means that the objects database holds the files, in a commit-oriented fashion.  The objects in this objects database are *read-only:* nothing can change *any* object once it's stored, and the database itself is essentially append-only.  Retrieving an object from the database requires knowing its "object number" (a big ugly random-looking hash ID).

    This first database is the one that's copied (without any changes: nothing in here *can* be changed) by cloning.  The object numbers (especially those for commits) are *universally unique:* every Git repository everywhere *must* use the *same number* for the same commit, and *must* allocate a new, never-before-used number for any *new* commit.<sup>1</sup>
  - The other database is simpler: it contains *names*—human readable ones—grouped into things like branch and tag names.  Each name stores one and only one object number, which turns out to be all we need.  This database is entirely read/write; anyone can change anything in it.  (Hosting sites like GitHub *always* add restrictions so that some random person off the internet can't go into your GitHub account and change or remove all your names.  You wouldn't use a hosting site if it didn't do this!)

    This second database is *not* copied by cloning, but is *readable* by someone making a clone.  A `git clone` command will select some stuff out of it and make changes to that during cloning, so that they can remember your branch names.
- Cloning a Git repository means copying these databases.  As noted above, one of them is (necessarily) copied as-is; the other typically gets modified.  What were *branch* names become what I call *remote-tracking names*.<sup>2</sup>  For instance, their `main` becomes your `origin/main`.<sup>3</sup>
- That's all that's *required* of a repository, and some (e.g., server hosted) repositories may have just that (though all hosting servers add a bunch of non-Git features too).  But you can't do any new work in such a repository, so when you clone one, you get a bit more than just the two databases.

This means that every clone *initially* has *every commit*,<sup>4</sup> but *no branches* (or at least no branch *names*—the word *branch* in Git is so overused as to be practically meaningless without context).  Doing work in a repository with no branch names at all, however, is no fun at all.  So your clone normally *creates* **one** branch name immediately after doing the database setup, before returning control to you.  (You can turn this off with `--no-checkout` but there's rarely any reason to do that.)

The branch name you get in your clone selects the *same commit* as the remote-tracking name in your clone, and the remote-tracking name in your clone is built from *their* **branch** name, so your `main` and your `origin/main` name the *same commit* as their `main` and hence your `main` and their `main` are in sync.  This assumes you're having your Git create your `main`: you get to choose which of their branch names your Git creates, using the `-b` option at `git clone` time, but if you don't use `-b`, your Git software asks their Git software what name they recommend.  (On GitHub, you can set this with the web interface; GitHub call this the "default branch", which is what Git calls it for `git clone` as well.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Furthermore, Git has to do this without consulting all the other Git repositories in the universe.  This is [mathematically impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) and the technique that Git uses to approximate it [will someday break](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452), but the size of the hash space is big enough that it's not a problem in practice.  (We get a huge break as well by not smushing together *unrelated* repositories, so that we never notice accidental hash collisions in those unrelated repositories: the uniqueness constraint gets relaxed to apply only to *related* repositories.)

<sup>2</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*.  Old Git documentation rather sloppily called them "remote branches" or other silly phrases.  They're not actually *branch* names at all—they're just your Git repository's *memory* of some other repository's branch names, transformed—and the word *branch* is so badly overused in Git that it's better, in my opinion, to just drop the word *branch* here entirely.

<sup>3</sup>The pattern here is mostly clear: a *branch* name doesn't have a remote name like `origin` in front, and a *remote-tracking* name like `origin/main` does.  But then you get weirdness like `git pull origin main` and you might start to wonder why this isn't `origin/main` here too.  There are historical reasons for that, i.e., no good reason *now* except that Git has to be compatible with Git-the-way-it-was-used-in-2005, before "remotes" were invented.

<sup>4</sup>Technically, you get only the *reachable* commits, and you can snip off many of those with a "shallow" clone as well, but we won't get into these details.

---

#### The next things to know about Git

I've already mentioned that the true identity of a commit is its hash ID name.  For instance, [`d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376) is a particular commit in the Git repository for Git (the link goes to it).  It has the same hash ID in *every clone* of the Git repository for Git, so if you have a clone of the Git repository for Git, you will have this commit in your clone, or else your clone is out of date and you need to run `git fetch` to bring it more-up-to-date from a more-up-to-date copy.

The `fetch` and `push` commands are how we transfer commits.  These commits, like all Git objects, are strictly read-only: once created, they can never be changed, and once they've been distributed Out There to other Git repositories it's generally difficult or even impossible to recall them (there are specific cases where you know how far they've spread and can stamp them out like some evil COVID strain, but given how frequently Git repositories have Git-sex with other related Git repositories, it's usually too late).

The fetch command generally means *call up some other Git software and repository and get everything that they have, that I don't*.  You *can* limit the fetch somewhat, but that's not the norm.  By contrast, the push command generally means *call up some other Git software and repository and give them *specific* commits that I have that they don't*.  If we push the sex analogy a little too far, this means it's up to the "male" ("push") operations to be responsible.

Now, the thing about commits is that they don't *just* have a full snapshot of all the files, like a tar or zip or WinRAR archive or whatever.  They *also* carry some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit, for instance.  But it also includes stuff that *Git* relies on internally: specifically, every commit has a *list of raw hash IDs* for earlier commits.

This list of earlier (or *parent*) commit hash IDs, stored in each commit, is how commits form history.  Most commits contain exactly one hash ID: one parent commit.  This forms a simple, backwards-looking, linear chain, and this explains how Git works and why the answer above is "yes but not sustainably".

Let's draw a picture of a tiny, three-commit repository, using uppercase letters to stand in for the commit's hash IDs (which in reality are big and ugly and impossible for humans to work with).  We'll call the first commit `A`, the second one `B`, and the third one `C`, and draw them like this:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Commit `C` stores commit `B`'s raw hash ID.  We say that `C` *points to* `B`, and draw that as an arrow sticking out of `C`, pointing to `B`.  What this *means* is that if we can somehow memorize the hash ID *of* commit `C`, and give that to Git, Git can retrieve commit `C` from its all-objects database, and that gives Git the hash ID of commit `B`, so that Git can retrieve commit `B` too.

Having retrieved *both* commits—and the two snapshots—Git can go on to *compare* the two snapshots, to see what changed between them.  Git essentially plays [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference) here.

Equally important, now that Git has commit `B` in hand, it can use the metadata in `B` to get `A`'s hash ID, from which Git can get commit `A`.  (Commit `A` is special: its list of parents is empty.  Git can now stop going backwards.)  So by memorizing *one* hash ID—that for commit `C`—we had Git find *all* the commits.

The *second* database, holding branch names and other names, is how we have Git do the memorizing for us:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
```

The *name* `main` holds `C`'s hash ID, so that it is easy to find commit `C`.

If we like, we can now create a second name, such as `develop`.  We must pick any one of the existing commits so that the name `develop` selects that commit.  The most obvious candidate is the *newest* (presumably latest = greatest, right?) commit, `C`, so that's the one will probably pick:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, main
```

Now we need a way, in our drawing, to know *which name we're going to use*.  This will be our *current branch name*.  To draw which one is current, we'll attach the special all-caps name `HEAD` to just one branch name, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

This means we are using `main` and therefore using commit `C`.

#### The current branch and commit, and your working tree

Git shares a problem that all version control systems have: if previous versions are frozen for all time (and they are), how do we get any *new work* done?  Git's answer is the usual one: there's an additional area, which Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*, that holds copies of all the files from the commit you've selected.

So: we use `git switch` or the older `git checkout` command to pick some particular *branch name*, and thereby some particular *commit*, and Git extracts all the files from that commit and puts them into our working tree.  We now have all the files from commit `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

as we're "on" branch `main` and the name `main` selects commit `C`.

If we run `git switch develop`, we get:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

Git needs to attach the name `HEAD` to develop, remove all the commit-`C` files, and plug in, instead, all the commit-`C` files.  Wait, those are the same files.  Git doesn't need to bother to do *anything* to the *files*.  So it doesn't, and this is (later) an important thing to know: if we switch *branch names* without switching *commits*, *nothing at all happens in the working tree*.

Most version control systems stop here, with the two copies of each file: the frozen one in the current commit, and the usable one in your working tree.  Git goes on to add a *third* copy, in an area that Git gives three names, perhaps because it's so important, or perhaps because the original first name for it was so awful: this is the *index* or *cache* or *staging area*.  All three names mean the same thing here; *staging area* refers to how you *use* it and is arguably the best name, but I tend to use *index* because it does extra stuff at various times.  We won't get into any of the details here, but I always try to mention it since the index / staging-area is the key to making *new* commits.

Anyway, let's just assume for now that you know how to make a new commit, and let's go about making a new commit now, which we'll call `D`, since that's the next letter.  In reality it will get a new, unique hash ID—it will depend on, among all the other details, the *exact second* at which you make the new commit, so I'd have to know that to predict it—so, well, `D`.  New commit `D` will point backwards to existing commit `C` because `C` is the commit we're using *when* we make `D`.  So let's draw commit `D`:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D
```

Oh dear, I left out the branch names.  What happened to those?  Well, we're not "on" branch `main` now, so *nothing* happens to that name.  We *are* "on" branch `develop` now, so *Git shoves the new commit's hash ID into that name*.  The result looks like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Our new commit `D` links back to existing commit `C`, and our branch name `develop` locates commit `D`.  If we make another new commit `E` we get:

```
        D--E   <-- develop (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C   <-- main
```

where I have for some reason drawn `develop` up top this time.

Now let's run `git switch main`:

```
        D--E   <-- develop
       /
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD)
```

This time, we are *changing commits*, so Git removes all the commit-`E` files and swaps in all the commit-`C` files.<sup>5</sup>  If we look at what we have in our working tree, it's gone back in time to commit `C`.  (That's also the *last* commit in the repository we cloned, assuming we cloned a repository to get `A-B-C` originally.)

Let's make another new branch name, `feature`, now, and switch to that name.  We can do this in two steps:

```
git branch feature
git switch feature
```

or one:

```
git switch -c feature
```

In either case we get:

```
        D--E   <-- develop
       /
A--B--C   <-- feature (HEAD), main
```

If we now make *another* two new commits, we get:

```
        D--E   <-- develop
       /
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        F--G   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

**This is really what commits and branches are about in Git.**  We make new commits, and Git makes the new commits link backwards to the old ones; as we make each commit, Git stuffs its new, unique hash ID into the *current branch name*, which is how we remember which commit is the *latest*.

---

<sup>5</sup>Git actually "cheats" here.  Git *de-duplicates* files within and across commits, and because of the way it does that internally, Git knows, instantly, which files are identical in the two commits, when switching.  So Git doesn't bother to swap out the files that *haven't* changed.  This is a more general form of the "if we aren't changing commits, don't touch anything" case.  It's also quite useful, for when we start making changes but forget to switch branch names first.

---

#### This in fact is how branch names are defined

The hash ID stored *in* a branch name *is* the *last* commit on that branch:

```
        D--E   <-- develop
       /
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        F--G   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Here, `G` is the *last* commit on `feature`.  If we force Git to store `D` into `develop` and `F` into `feature`—there are various ways to do that—we get:

```
          E   ???
         /
        D   <-- develop
       /
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        F   <-- feature (HEAD)
         \
          G   ???
```

It's as if commits `E` and `G` no longer exist.  We can't *find* them, because we *find* commits using branch names and the names no longer point to them.  (If we've memorized their hash IDs, we can use those to find them, for a while at least.<sup>6</sup>)  The branch `develop` ends at `D` now, not at `E`.  Note that commits `A-B-C` are on *all three* branches.

Since we've never *sent* commits `E` and `G` to any *other* Git repository, we can be sure that they won't *be* in any other Git repository.  Neither are `D` and `F` yet, but we can now use `git push` to send either or both of `D` and/or `F` to some other Git:

```
git push origin develop
```

sends commit `D` to the Git repository over at `origin`, whatever URL that might be.  Then it asks that Git software to create or update *its* branch name `develop` to point to commit `D`.  Or, if we decide `develop` is the wrong name, we can run:

```
git push origin develop:feature-1
```

to send `D` to them, but ask them to create or update their branch name `feature-1`.  There's no need to use the same name on both sides—well, except, perhaps, to retain your own sanity.  (If you're going to rename this `feature-1`, it might be better to do that locally first, *then* use `git push origin feature-1`.)

(Note that we don't have to be "on" any particular branch to `git push` it either, and—for reasons we won't get into here—the *first time* we `git push` a branch name we probably want to add the `-u` option.)

If we like, we can actually send *both* `D` and `F` in one `git push`:

```
git push origin develop feature
```

which sends the commits we have that that they don't, that they'll need—i.e., `D` and `F` since they gave us `A-B-C` in the first place—and asks them to create or update their `develop` and `feature` names to remember `D` and `F` specifically.

---

<sup>6</sup>If you can't find a commit in your repository, and you leave things that way long enough, Git may decide that you don't really want it back after all, and can delete it.  Any other repository that *has* it can send it back to you later, after all, and you've indicated your lack of interest *now* by making it invisible.  This is technically a *garbage collection* operation, done by `git gc`.  When and whether any particular Git software does this GC is up to that particular Git software.

---

#### Multiple remotes

You can have more than one remote.  All a remote is, is a short name for a URL, by which your Git:

- remembers that URL for you, and
- when you use `git fetch remote`, calls up that other Git software, gets all the commits they have that you don't, and updates your `remote/*` names.

So you can:

```
git remote add prod <url>
```

and then `git fetch prod` to get from that other Git any commits they have that you don't, and to create or update your `prod/*` remote-tracking names.

But: if the repository at *that* URL is *related to* the repository at your existing `origin` URL, and in fact got all its commits *from* the repository at your `origin` URL, you will already have all those commits.  You got them when you got all the commits from `origin`.  So the set of commits you need is empty.  Your Git will still create or update all your `prod/*` names, and since this is the first time you've done this with the remote name `prod`, that means your Git will create them all.

The thing is, all those commits will literally *be* the *same commits* that were on `origin`.

This sort of thing means that there's no point in having a separate *repository* for the production system.  Just have one repository, and use different *names* to select the "most recent" development / test commit, and the "most recent" production commit.

It's certainly possible to do what you're describing.  There's just no real reason to bother.

Comment: wow firstly thank you for putting so much effort into this response. I have read it once and got a little bit lost so I will give this another read shortly. Just to clarify your last statement, there is no point having two repositories - the current environment has two separate servers each pulling their code-base from separate GitHub repositories. One server points to the 'production' repo and the other points to the 'staging' repo. I'm not sure changing this to look at different (branches ??) will be easy to manipulate. With this in mind... help??

Comment: Actually I think "GitHub Environments" might be the path the previous developers went down...

Comment: Let me put it this way: either the commits in the two server-side repositories *are* partly the same and thus have strong family relationships, in which case there's no point in having separate repositories ... or, the commits are *completely unrelated*, in which case you don't want to use a single repository on your (client) side in the first place. (And: I'm not sure what you mean by "GitHub Environments". GitHub provide environment variables holding secrets, so that you don't have to put secrets such as passwords into a repository. Putting secrets into a repository is generally a bad idea.)

Comment: I'm referring to this: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment When I look in the previous developers repositories, the repo counter says "1" but when I click into it there are 2. When I click into the production one, there is an "Environment" section. If I go into the staging actions, there is a "deployment" section. It *appears* as though I can manually deploy specific commits to the production. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Aha: those are features of "GitHub Actions". These Actions are not part of Git, they're a GitHub add-on. You simply store a file with a magic name (`.github-whatever`) and GitHub notice that such a file exists in some particular commit in some particular repository. They have their software read this file and do operations based on the file's content. There's nothing "Git-ty" going on here, except that each commit that has one of these files is obviously a candidate for action. I'm not a GitHub actions expert and don't know precisely how GitHub choose which commits' file(s) are used.