# Beginner: How to merge 2 README.md files (branch merge)

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I have a problem where I need to merge 2 branches, both containing a README.md file.[image: problem] If I try to merge the 2 branches with the readme to a 3rd branch, ofc the first one gets through without a problem. If I try the 2nd branch ofc it gives me a content conflict, because the 2nd readme would delete the email out of the 1st one. Now we were given a website which should have helped fix that with a mergetool, but if we try to change something via the mergetool the 2 lines seem to be "stuck" together, meaning if I change a line with local it changes both, same with remote. I'm pretty new to git etc. (like a few hours max) and I have no idea how to find a solution, so any help would be great^^

Trying to merge 2 README files, content conflict. Mergetool didn't work like i thought it would.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve merge conflicts in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 2):

Note: this answer got too long so I've split it into two parts.

## Part 1 ([part 2 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74218390/1256452))

You have encountered a basic stumbling block for those who try to use Git without a tutorial, or with a *bad* tutorial (of which there are, unfortunately, many).  Your mistake here is thinking that "merge", in Git, involves *two* versions of some file.  This is not the case!  Merging in Git is on a *commit* basis and involves *three* versions of each file.

Before we can get into merging, we have to start with *commits*.  Without the proper base,<sup>1</sup> merging won't make any sense.  So let's jump into that first.  Note that you may want to read this twice before you tackle your merge.

---

<sup>1</sup>There's a pun here that will fly right over your head if you're not already familiar with the ideas behind merging.

---

#### Commit = snapshot + metadata

Git is, at its heart, all about *commits*.  Git is not really about files or branches.  It's true that each commit *stores* files, and we (or Git at least) organize commits *into* branches, using branch names to help us *find* individual commits.  But it's the commit itself—or the collection of commits—that's the heart of the repository.

Git stores these commits in an *object database*.  We won't go into most of the details here, though we will skim a few necessary parts, but if you are curious, you can peek inside the hidden `.git` folder, where you will find a sub-folder named `objects`.  Inside this are potentially many more folders, which store the objects in various forms ("loose" and "packed" but you don't need to care about this here).  Each object, including each commit, is *numbered*, with a unique ID that is expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), such as [`d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376).  (This particular one is a commit in the Git repository for Git.)

This hash ID is the "true name" of the internal object, and Git literally requires it to *find* the object in the objects database.  These names are not friendly to humans, though, so Git provides a separate secondary database—one that's not nearly as well organized, nor as well implemented, really—that stores *names:* branch names, tag names, and all other kinds of names.  Each of these names simply stores one hash ID, which is in fact all that's necessary.

So, when you use a branch name like `main` or `feature` or whatever, you're really providing Git with a raw hash ID, that's been hidden behind this name.  It's worth running `git rev-parse` a few times to get a feel for this mechanism:

```
git rev-parse main
```

might produce:

```
d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376
```

for instance, if you have a clone of the Git repository for Git (though by now its main/master has moved on; I haven't updated my clone in more than a week now for home-life reasons).

When you clone a Git repository, it's the underlying objects that you are copying.  The *names* in your names database are yours, not the original clone's, but the *objects*, which are all strictly read-only once they're created, get shared.  You get a copy but you (and your Git software) are forbidden from changing any of these.  Not even Git can change a Git commit.  You just *add new commits* to the repository.  That's how history exists: the existing commits continue to exist.  They're just now in *two* repositories: the original, and your clone.  Make more clones, and you make yet more copies of the objects.

With that said, let's look at the anatomy of one particular commit, in this case `d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376`:

```
$ git cat-file -p d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376 | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 13b45e4ccc34572dce66dc79468b66c0b383a560
parent c68bd3ec22a1afc85b0b897834b2524aedbd0553
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1665507772 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1665509772 -0700

The second batch

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

That, right there, is the entire commit object, as seen in every Git clone of the Git repository for Git.  You can see that commits are pretty small!  But each one has a `tree` object: that first line, `tree` followed by an internal object ID, is *required* in *every* commit.

The tree object in the commit represents a permanent archive of *every file*.  This is another object (and you can `git cat-file -p` it, if you like, to see how it works in great detail), but what we see in the output above is the *metadata* for the commit:

- the commit has a *parent*, with a raw hash ID: this is another commit object;
- the commit has an *author* and a *committer:* these are text strings giving the name and email address of the person who made the commit, along with some date-and-time stamps; and
- the commit has a log message, which is what you see when you run `git log`.

The `git log` command uses the stored hash ID here to find the *previous* commit.  *Most* commits have exactly one `parent` line, but a few have mroe than one parent, making them *merge* commits, and at least one commit in any non-empty repository has *no* `parent` because it was the *first* commit.

We say that the commit *points to* its parent or parents, and if we use single uppercase letters to stand in for real hash IDs—which are big, ugly, and random-looking<sup>2</sup>—we get drawings that look like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- main
```

Here, the *name* `main`, a branch name, *points to* (contains the hash ID of) commit `H`.  Commit `H` itself contains, indirectly, a full snapshot of every file—that's the `tree <hash>` line—and directly contains metadata, including a `parent` line.  So commit `H` *points to* earlier commit `G`.

Commit `G`, being a commit, contains a snapshot and metadata, so `G` points to earlier commit `F`.  Commit `F` is a commit, so it points to a still-earlier commit, which points back to an even-earlier commit, and so on, backwards, down the line to the very first commit ever (presumably commit `A` in our drawing).

---

<sup>2</sup>They're actually not random at all, and concretely, the hash ID `d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376` is simply the SHA-1 checksum of the content of the above commit, except that this content is prefixed by `commit 284` and an ASCII NUL byte, with `284` being the decimalized size of the rest of the object.  The fact that the previous hash IDs on the `parent` lines and the date-and-time-stamps are themselves unique means that the new hash ID is unique.<sup>3</sup>

<sup>3</sup>Anyone familiar with the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) should immediately object here.  That objection is correct and means that Git will eventually fail.  You can calculate the probability of failure with a fancy formula, and it turns out to be vanishingly small until the objects database holds more than about 1.7×10<sup>15</sup> objects, at which point it starts to creep up towards the probability of undetected disk-drive errors.  We live with those; [we can live with SHA-1 collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452).  Even so, Git is slowly moving towards SHA-256.

---

#### A special feature of a branch name

We're going to skip a lot here and just look at one special feature of branch names.  We already know that the name *points to* a commit.  We can also draw this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, feature
```

where we have a single commit, `H`, that is pointed-to by *more than one branch name*.  When this is the case, all the commits up to and including `H` are on *both branches*.  Checking out either branch, with `git switch main` or `git switch feature`, gets us the files from commit `H`.  But, as a special feature, *checking out* that name "attaches" the special name `HEAD` *to* that name:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), feature
```

Here, we're on commit `H` and branch `main`.  The files we have available to us are those from commit `H`.  If we now run:

```
git switch feature
```

the picture changes slightly:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, feature (HEAD)
```

We're still on commit `H`, but we're "on" it through the *name* `feature`.  We have the same files, but something wacky is about to happen.

Let's make a new commit now, in the usual way Git has for making commits (we modify some files and `git add` and `git commit`).  We get a new commit, which gets a new, unique ID; we'll just call this `I` and draw it in:

```
          I
         /
...--G--H
```

What happens to the branch *names?*  The answer is: nothing happens to any of the ones that we are *not* "on", but the one that we *are* "on", **that** name gets forcibly updated so that it points to the new commit we just made:

```
          I   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

If we make another new commit, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

Commits `I-J` are clearly "on" the `feature` branch.  Commits up through `H` are clearly "on" the `main` branch.  Surprisingly—or not, depending on your point of view and whether you've used *other* version control systems—Git declares that commits up through `H` are on *both* branches at this time.

#### Forming more branches, and a side note on the word *branch*

Let's now switch back to `main`, with `git switch main`:

```
          I--J   <-- feature
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Git will rip away our commit-`J` files and put back the commit-`H` files.  The "true" files are safely saved away in the `tree` objects for each commit.  The files we see and work with are in fact *not in the repository at all*, they're just *copied out* of the repository.

We can now create and switch to another name, perhaps `dev` or `re-feature`.  Or if we like, we can commit on `main`.  It doesn't really matter to *Git*, as the branch name is merely a sort of label, pointing to the commit.  Later, if we decide we want to have `main` *stay* with commit `H`, we can make a new name that points to the new commits we're about to make, and then force the name `main` back to commit `H`.

**This is a key weirdness in Git:** *branch names* aren't really very important at all, except in that they help us by finding the *last* commit.  Whatever commit the name points to *is* the last commit in the branch.  If we move the name, we've changed which commit is the last commit in the branch.  This is also why we say that some commit is "on" a branch if we can get there by starting at the last commit (found by the name) and working backwards.  In effect, commits are "contained in" their branches more than they are "on" any one (single) branch.

Rather than mucking about with moving `main` forward and backwards, let's do:

```
git switch -c feat2
```

now, to get:

```
          I--J   <-- feature
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, feat2 (HEAD)
```

and make two more commits:

```
          I--J   <-- feature
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- feat2 (HEAD)
```

Now, just for the heck of it, let's *delete* the *name* `main`.  (It's kind of in the way of what we're about to do.)  This gives us:

```
          I--J   <-- feature
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- feat2 (HEAD)
```

Commit `H`, which *was* on *three* branches, is now only on *two* branches.  The branch `main` has ceased to exist.  Or has it?  If we create a new name, `old-main`, pointing to `H`:

```
          I--J   <-- feature
         /
...--G--H   <-- old-main
         \
          K--L   <-- feat2 (HEAD)
```

commit `H` is now on three branches again.

**The number of branches that some commit is "on" is not important.**  The word *branch* in Git is rather badly overloaded (see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)) and when you see it without context, you should be careful: it may not mean *anything*, and the person who used it might not be aware of what they're saying.  Or it may mean any of the various things that it can mean, such as "branch name", "remote-tracking name", "tip commit", and "set of commits ending at a particular commit".

#### Onward: `git merge`

With all that out of the way, let's change our two `feature` names to `br1` and `br2` so that they're easier to type in, and switch to `br1` and run `git merge br2` now:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

We seem to have asked Git to merge "branch `br2`" into "branch `br1`".  And that's *sort of* true.  But in fact, what we're really asking Git to merge are *commits*, namely `J` and `L`.  As always, each of these two commits represent a snapshot-plus-metadata.

Because we are "on" `br1`, the files we have available to us, before we run `git merge br2`, are those from commit `J`.  The files we're asking Git to merge exist in `br2`, i.e., in the tip commit *of* `br2`, i.e., in commit `L`.  But in order to *perform* the merge, Git cannot simply compare the files in `J` to the files in `L`.  You might wonder why not, and we'll provide a simple example, but before we get there, let's consider the *goal* of a merge in the first place.

**The goal of a standard `git merge` operation is to *combine work*.**  If we are going to *combine* work, we first have to *define* work.  What *is* the work in a commit?

#### The work in an individual commit

Let's take a really concrete example: commit [`d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376).  If you click on this link, or clone the Git repository for Git and run `git show d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376`, you get a bunch of text shown that includes this:

```
diff --git a/Documentation/RelNotes/2.39.0.txt b/Documentation/RelNotes/2.39.0.txt
index a26c82444b..a6ee7c8996 100644
--- a/Documentation/RelNotes/2.39.0.txt
+++ b/Documentation/RelNotes/2.39.0.txt
@@ -66,9 +66,25 @@ Fixes since v2.38
    led to a segfault (which is bad), which has been corrected.
    (merge 92481d1b26 js/merge-ort-in-read-only-repo later to maint).
 
+ * Force C locale while running tests around httpd to make sure we can
+   find expected error messages in the log.
+   (merge 7a2d8ea47e rs/test-httpd-in-C-locale later to maint).
[snip]
```

This is obviously some `git diff` output.  It shows us a *change* to one file, `Documentation/RelNotes/2.39.0.txt`.  But if a commit is a snapshot (plus metadata)—and it is—how can there be a *change* to a file?  The snapshot is just an archive, like a zip file or tarball or whatever.  The answer is that this particular commit has a (single) *parent* commit, whose hash ID we see above.  If we have Git extract *both* of these commits and *compare* them, we'll find that this file, `Documentation/RelNotes/2.39.0.txt`, is *different* in the two commits—and the `git diff` output from comparing these two commits is just what we see with `git show`, or on the GitHub page.

#### Work done over multiple commits

So the *difference between* some commit and its parent represents the work done in that particular commit, and that's the definition we will start with.  Let's go back to our simple stylized graph:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

and look at the *work done* in, say, commit `I`.  We'll find this "work" by comparing the snapshot in `H` to the snapshot in `I`.  Maybe we added one new file, `new.txt`, and did nothing else.  We can look at the work done in commit `J` too: maybe we edited `old.txt` and `README.md`.  The changes to those two files is the work done in `J`.

Now, what about commits `K` and `L`?  Maybe in commit `K` we modified `foo.py`, and in commit `L` we made another change to `foo.py` *and* also modified `README.md`.

If we compare commit `J` with commit `L`, then, we'll see the following:

- delete `new.txt` (it's in `J`, where we added it because of `I`, but it is not in `L`);
- undo the change we made to `old.txt` (we did that in `J`);
- modify `foo.py` (we made two changes to that in `K` and `L`), and modify `README.md` to add whatever we did in `L`, **and** to **undo** whatever we did in `J`.

This is clearly no good!  We don't want to *remove* `new.txt` at all.  Maybe we can compare in the other direction, so that we add `new.txt`.  But we already have a `new.txt`, and this comparison will tell us to *undo* whatever changes we made in `foo.py`.  That, too, is no good.

No: **What we need is to identify the work done on `br1` first, separately.**  We can do that pretty easily by comparing the snapshot that's in `H` to the one that's in `J`.  That will show us:

- the new file added; and
- the change we made to `README.md`.

That's the "work done in `br1`", or more precisely, the work done in commits `I-J`.

Once we have that, we can try to identify the work done on `br2`.  We can do that pretty easily too, by comparing the snapshot that's in `H` to the one that's in `L`.  That will show us:

- the two changes made to `foo.py`; and
- the change we made to `README.md`.

That's exactly what we want!  But hang on a moment:

- **Why** did we go back to commit `H`?  Why not back to commit `G`?
- **How** did we pick commit `H` in the first place?
- **How** do we *combine* these changes?

The answer to the first two questions is `git merge-base`.

#### The merge base

If we just *look at* the picture we drew:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

it's stunningly obvious *why* we picked commit `H`.  Commit `H` is on *both branches*.  So is commit `G`, of course, and so are all the commits before `G`, but commit `H` is the *last* of these shared commits.  Going further back in time, to an even-earlier shared commit, nets more overall changes, where "both sides" will make the same changes, and there's no profit in doing that.  So commit `H`, the *last* shared commit, is also the *best* shared commit.

There are cases where the best shared commit is not obvious at all, and there are ways to draw the graph that make it less obvious that `H` is the best shared commit.  Git has, built into it, an implementation of the [Lowest Common Ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs) algorithm (as extended to DAGs like Git's commit graph), so that `git merge-base` can find the shared commit, and `git merge` uses that by default.<sup>4</sup>  We thus usually don't have to think about this: we just run `git merge br2` and *Git* finds the best shared commit, in this case `H`, and does its thing.

Not having to think and worry about it, though, does not mean we can *ignore* it.  **We must realize and remember that when we run `git merge`, Git is going to *find* a merge base commit.**<sup>5</sup>  This merge base supplies the *third* version of each file.

---

<sup>4</sup>I've mentioned this "by default" a few times, and that is because `git merge` allows you to specify a *merge strategy*.  There's a merge strategy, `-s ours`, that means *ignore everything they did*.  This strategy doesn't bother finding a merge base at all.  There are some other fancier strategies that do complicated stuff, but we won't cover those here.

Git's "merge strategy" `-s` argument should not be confused with Git's *strategy-option*, or `-X`, arguments to `git merge`.  I like to call these *eXtended options* to keep them apart in my head.  The `-X` options are passed *to* the strategy, which then does whatever it does with them.  Since we almost always use the default strategy in the first place, most people seem to think of the `-X` extended options as options to `git merge`, but they're actually specific to the strategy.  (This is all very confusing, and perhaps was a bad idea, rather like Douglas Adams' famous quote: ["In the beginning the Universe was created.  This has made a lot of people very angry and been widely regarded as a bad move."](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/1-the-story-so-far-in-the-beginning-the-universe-was))

<sup>5</sup>There are particularly nasty cases where there is more than one "best" merge base commit, and for these cases, Git defaults to *merging the merge bases* to come up with a "virtual merge base".  With any luck, you will never experience <s>the wonders, er, horrors, er, terror ...</s> this particular case yourself.  Seriously, it's not usually terrible, but occasionally, it is really awful and ugly.  You can check to see if this will happen or has happened using `git merge-base --all`: if that spits out more than one hash ID, you've hit the multiple-merge-bases case, and it's time to find a helpful StackOverflow article.

---

#### How Git handles three versions of each file

Now that we know that `git merge br2` really uses *three* versions of each file:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

with the *merge base* version of each file coming from commit `H`, we can see how Git uses these.

Let's start with the easy cases, with our hypothetical example.  Here, we modified `foo.py` in `br2`—once in each new commit—but we *didn't touch `foo.py` at all* in our `br1` commits.  So the diff from `H` to `J` shows *nothing* for this file, while the diff from `H` to `L` shows the two changes.

To combine nothing with something, Git takes the something.  That was easy!  Git then applies the "something" to the copy *from commit `H`*, which is also the copy from commit `J`, which is also the copy we have sitting in our working tree.  So the result is that the changes we made in `K` and `L` show up in our working tree.

Let's take another easy case: the file `NOTES.md` in all three commits match.  To do nothing at all on the left (in our changes on `I-J`), and nothing at all on the right (in their changes on `K-L`), Git does nothing: it takes any of the three copies of `NOTES.md`, from any of the commits, such as the one we already have in our working tree, and just leaves it alone.

Let's take a third easy case: the file `new.txt` *does not exist* in the merge base commit `H`, and *does not exist* in commit `L`, but is there in commit `J` and in our working tree.  Git combines the "create" with the "do nothing" to create the file, i.e., leave it in our working tree (and in Git's *index*, about which we'll say more in a moment).

Had we created a new file in "their" commits (`K-L`), or deleted a file on either side, or whatever, Git would take that change—create new file, or delete file—and copy that across.  Any time one side does something and the other side doesn't do something, we take the "something".

This leaves us with the hard case, or at least, the *potentially* hard case: we did something, and they did something, to the *same file*.

#### Combining changes to one file, and how Git expands its index

There's an important thing we have not mentioned at all here yet, and it's a big topic that I won't really cover properly, which is this: **Git does not make commits from what's in your working tree.  Git makes commits from what is in Git's index.**  This thing, this "index", is crucial in Git *because* Git uses it to make new commits.  It's so important, and perhaps so poorly named (what the heck does *index* mean anyway?), that it actually has three names:

- when called "the index", as I do here, we can refer to everything it does;
- when called "the cache", as Git mostly only does in flags now (`git rm --cached`), it refers to how Git uses it to speed stuff up; and
- when called the *staging area*, which is perhaps the best name for how you *use* it, Git is describing how you use it: to "stage" the next commit.

What's *in* the index or staging area is, to put it briefly and gloss over some details, a sort of a *copy* of each file that is *going to be committed* if you run `git commit` *right now*.  That is, when you first switch to some commit, Git not only extracts that commit's files to your work area, so that you can see them and work on them.  Git *also* extracts the same files to Git's index aka staging area, so that they're all staged to go into the *next* commit in exactly the same form they have in *this* commit.

The existence of this index / staging-area is *why* you have to run `git add` every time you change a file.  The `git add` command tells Git:

- open and read the working-tree copy of the file;
- compress the data down to the internal form for a loose object;
- check to see if we already have the file data (i.e., is this a duplicate?);
- make either the original object (if duplicate), or this now-prepared object, ready for committing.

So we will re-use the original if this is a duplicate.  Otherwise, the next commit will use this data, which has never been committed before.  Either way, at the end of `git add`, the working tree version of the file is now in Git's index, ready to be committed.

The de-duplication that happens in this step is a big part of how Git keeps the commits from bloating up the repository, even though every commit stores every file every time.  Most commits are mostly duplicates, and these duplicate copies take no space because they're de-duplicated.  It's during `git add`, not `git commit`, when Git actually does the duplication checking and de-duplicating.  So if you don't *force* Git to re-add every file every time,<sup>6</sup> `git add` and `git commit` go very fast.

Now, this is the *normal* condition of the index, when we're not in the middle of a merge.  But when you run `git merge`, Git *expands* the index, creating three extra "slots" for each file:

- slot zero, if it's used, is the normal ready-to-commit copy: if this index entry is occupied, the other three slots are erased and the file is *not* conflicted;
- slots 1, 2, and 3 hold the *merge base*, "ours", and "theirs" copy of the file: if any of these slots are occupied, slot zero is erased and the file *is* conflicted.

Hence the way `git merge` works—at least from a high level viewpoint<sup>7</sup>—is this:

- the "ours" copy of each file moves from slot zero to slot 2;
- the *merge base* copy of each file goes into slot 1; and
- the "theirs" copy of each file goes into slot 3.

At this point, we have all three slots filled for any file that appears in all three commits.  Now we just take care of each possible case:

- All three slots hold the same copy of the file: nobody touched it at all, just use any copy, collapse it all down to slot zero.
- Slots 1 and 2 match and slot 3 is different, or slots 1 and 3 match and slot 2 is different: we or they touched the file, and they or we didn't, so take the *modified* file, whichever slot that's in, and move that to slot zero and erase the other two.
- Slot 1 is empty, slot 2 is occupied, slot 3 is empty; or slot 1 is empty, slot 2 is empty, and slot 3 is occupied: we or they added the file.  Put the non-empty entry into slot 0 and erase all the others.
- Slot 1 is not empty, and matches what's in 2 or 3, but the other of 2 or 3 is empty: one of us removed the file and the other of us didn't, so remove the file, by removing all the entries (no slots left at all).

Some of the remaining cases are messy and I leave it as an exercise to work them out (consider, e.g., "slot 1 empty, slots 2 and 3 both have files in them", which may be an add/add conflict).  The *usual* hard case is the one where slots 1, 2, and 3 are all occupied with *different* copies of the file: that's your standard "merge conflict".

---

<sup>6</sup>Note that running `git add .` makes Git check for *changes* via various magic OS-dependent file-system tricks, which is normally much faster than re-compressing every file.  This is where that "cache" aspect of the index comes in.  You have to defeat this cache trick to really see the timing difference, and these details are beyond the scope of this answer, though I'll note that the `--renormalize` option is the mostly-portable way to mostly do most of this.

<sup>7</sup>The `git merge` code takes care not to bother expanding the index for unconflicted files, as most files are mostly unconflicted and this makes everything go a lot faster.  But that complicates the *code* a lot; the simplified view where we do the expand-then-combine-then-shrink is a whole lot easier to think about, and gives the same result, just a bit slower.

This also skips over the whole "renamed file" identification process, which is kind of tricky.

[on to part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74218390/1256452)

Comment: I am very curious about how long time you wrote this answer.

Comment: This is a great answer for somewhat mediocre question.

Comment: @GenoChen: It's a few hours of work at least.

Answer (score 2):

## Part 2 ([part 1 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74218374/1256452))

#### Auto-merging

If we have a standard, boring conflict—that is, if we have all three slots occupied with three *different* versions of some file, as would be the case with our `README.md` changes—Git really does have to use `git diff` now on the two pairs.  By comparing the *base* version to each *tip commit* version, one at a time, Git can see which line(s) of the file *we* changed, and which line(s) of the file *they* changed.

If the lines we changed are sufficiently far away from the lines they changed, `git merge` can simply *combine* the two changes.  We touched line 42 (replacing it with two lines 42+43) and they touched line 123 (now line 124), so Git makes our change to the base version at line 42 (now 42+43) and makes their change to the base version at line 123 (now line 124)—and as far as *Git* is concerned, *Git* has *successfully auto-merged our work*.

If Git thinks it successfully did this auto-merging, Git writes the resulting file back into the working tree *and* does a `git add` to put this file into its index.  The `git add` step *erases* slots 1 through 3 and writes the working tree copy into slot zero.  The merge conflict has been resolved and the file is ready to commit.

On the other hand, perhaps we changed line 42 (making it two lines, 42+43) *and* **they** also changed line 42 (perhaps leaving it one line).  In this case, Git *can't* combine our changes with their changes.  What Git does for this case is write, to the *working tree*, a "merge conflict" version of the file.  Git then *leaves all three input files* in its index, so that slots 1, 2, and 3 are occupied with the three input copies of `README.md`.  Slot zero is empty.

In general, Git considers a change to be conflicted if:

- the two sides modify the same line(s) but in different ways; *or*
- the two sides modify lines that "touch" each other ([abut](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abut)).

When this happens Git will leave you with a merge conflict, which you must fix up yourself.  **All Git needs is the final version of the file.**

#### Manual merge

You can provide the merge result any way you like.  One way is to open the conflicted file, as it appears in your working tree, in any editor and edit it into shape.  Write the result back into the working tree and run `git add`:

```
git add README.md
```

Git will read and compress the working tree copy and prepare it for committing as usual, and will write this to the slot-zero entry for the file.  This erases the conflicted-file inputs in slots 1, 2, and 3, and the file is now resolved.

#### `git mergetool`

Another way to merge conflicted files is to use `git mergetool`.  This command will in fact run any arbitrary editor of your choice, but to make that work, things get a little complicated.

What this program does is, from a high level viewpoint anyway:

1. extract *all three* input files from the index (using `git checkout-index --stage=all`, more or less);
2. run some command on the three files, perhaps with a fourth name supplied;
3. run `git add` on the result.

It repeats this for each conflicted file.  The tricky parts include, but are not limited to, these:

- How does Git decide whether you actually merged the file?
- Where are the three (or four) files?

The answer to the first question depends on the editor or other program that `git mergetool` runs: some programs have a "trusted exit code" that tells Git whether they succeeded at merging.  If so, `git mergetool` does the `git add` for you.  Others don't: for this case, `git mergetool` make a backup of the unmerged mashed-together file that `git merge` left in your working tree, and compares the supposedly-merged final version of the file against this backup.  If the backup matches the supposedly-merged version, `git mergetool` assumes that the merge *didn't* work.

The actual temporary copies of each file are *currently* handled by renaming the internal names that `git checkout-index` spews out to `path.LOCAL`, `path.REMOTE`, and so on.  This isn't really promised anywhere.

If you're using a pre-packaged merge tool, someone has (at least supposedly) set up all of this stuff so that `git mergetool` runs your preferred editor, whatever that is, in such a way that it presents you with a sensible way to merge the three input files.  If you're setting this up on your own, poke around inside the internals of `git mergetool` as it's horrendously complicated.

#### The final result

No matter how you go about finishing a conflicted merge, in the end, what you have in your working tree and in Git's index is a set of files.  These are—or at least, Git will *believe* these are—the *correct* merge result, by definition.  All the files *in* Git's index are now in staging-slot-zero, so that `git status` says that all conflicts are fixed and it's now OK to commit the merge.

You now run either:

```
git merge --continue
```

or:

```
git commit
```

(both wind up doing exactly the same thing) and Git makes a new *merge commit*.  If the input graph looks like this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

and you ran `git merge br2`, the end result looks like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \₁
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /²
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Note that new commit `M` *is* a commit, so like every commit, it holds a snapshot and metadata.  The *snapshot* in `M` is whatever you had in Git's index (in staging slot zero) when you finished the merge, or, if Git was able to auto-merge everything, everything Git put in staging-slot-zero: a full snapshot of every file, as of the form it has for that commit.

The *metadata* in commit `M` is where things are very slightly special.  Unlike an ordinary commit, merge commit `M` has *two* parents instead of just one.  The *first* parent is the same as normal: it's commit `J`, where branch name `br1` pointed before the merge operation finished.  The *second* parent is the one you said to merge: `br2` selected commit `L` at the time, so that's the second parent of commit `M`.

It's now safe to delete the *name* `br2` if you like, as Git can find commit `L` by working backwards from `M`.  As always, we only need to have a branch name pointing to some commit if we want to be able to *find* that commit quickly and easily, using that name.  If we have some other way to find the commit, we don't *need* the branch name.  We may or may not *want* it; that's up to us; the names are there for us to use for our purposes, after all.

## Reminders: what you should know now

- A Git repository is mostly a big collection of commits and other objects.
- These objects are strictly read-only.  They are numbered, with hash IDs, which are their "true names".  The hash IDs depend on the content, which is why the content can't be changed.  If you need to improve a commit, you can make a new improved one.  You literally can't fix the existing one though.
- We normally *find* commits using names—branch and tag names for instance—and then maybe working backwards, one hop at a time, as `git log` does.
- We like to *see* commits with `git diff` or `git show`, which compares two snapshots.
- Making *new* commits makes the *current branch name* advance.
- The word "branch" is ambigous; be careful with it.
- *Checking out* a commit extracts its files.  Checking out a *branch name* (with `git switch` or `git checkout`) selects the *tip* commit, as pointed-to by the branch name, and extracts its files.
- Besides the frozen (and de-duplicated and Git-ified) copies of files in the commit, there are useful copies of the files in your working tree, *and* Git-ified (but not quite frozen) copies in Git's *index* or *staging area*.
- `git commit` uses the *index* / *staging-area* copies to make the new commit; `git add` updates the index copy of each added file.
- `git merge` works by finding a *merge base* and, in effect, running *two* `git diff` operations to see what "work" happened since that shared common merge-base commit.
- Git resolves merge conflicts on a line-by-line basis, whether that makes any sense or not.  This works great for many computer programming languages, and can work well for documentation.  It actually *doesn't* work very well for things like XML though.